# Sort the distinct elements of a list in descending order by frequency

Tags: code-golf

Write a function which takes a list or array, and returns a list of the distinct elements, sorted in descending order by frequency.

Example:

Given:

```
["John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John"]
```

Expected return value:

```
["Doe","Harry","John","Dick"]
```

Comment: Code-golf or code-challenge?

Comment: Code-golf. That was mistake. Just correct it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### APL (14)

```
{∪⍵[⍒+⌿∘.≡⍨⍵]}
```

This is a function that takes a list, e.g.:

```
      names
 John  Doe  Dick  Harry  Harry  Doe  Doe  Harry  Doe  John 
      {∪⍵[⍒+⌿∘.≡⍨⍵]} names
 Doe  Harry  John  Dick
```

Explanation:

- `∘.≡⍨⍵`: compare each element in the array to each other element in the array, giving a matrix
- `+⌿`: sum the columns of the matrix, giving how many times each element occurs
- `⍒`: give indices of downward sort
- `⍵[`...`]`: reorder `⍵` by the given indices
- `∪`: get the unique elements

Comment: And yet somehow they call going from this concise witty language to Java "progress"? (-:

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3 - <strike>47</strike> 43; Python 2 - <strike>40</strike> 39

For Python 3:

```
f=lambda n:sorted(set(n),key=n.count)[::-1]
```

For Python 2:

```
f=lambda n:sorted(set(n),cmp,n.count,1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> names = ["John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John"]
>>> f(names)
['Doe', 'Harry', 'John', 'Dick']
```

Comment: I was trying to post the same, but here is a modification. `f=lambda n:sorted(set(n),cmp,n.count,1)` 39 characters

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize you could pass both a non-None `cmp` function and a `key` function. Cool.

Comment: A bit shorter: `f=lambda n:sorted(set(n),key=n.count)[::-1]`

Comment: Thanks @grc, the alien smiley does save some characters in the Python 3 case.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 31

```
Sort[GatherBy@n][[-1;;1;;-1,1]]
```

> `{"Doe", "Harry", "John", "Dick"}`

(With `n = {"John", "Doe", "Dick", "Harry", "Harry", "Doe", "Doe", "Harry", "Doe", "John"}`)

Comment: Darn, you got me there :D

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks. I'm thinking of getting rid of `Reverse`, but `Sort[GatherBy@n][[-1;;1, 1]]` does not work:). Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh, got it http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22320/745

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica (26 <del>37</del>)

With `n = {"John", "Doe", "Dick", "Harry", "Harry", "Doe", "Doe", "Harry", 
  "Doe", "John"}`:

```
Last/@Gather@n~SortBy~Length//Reverse
```

> {"Doe", "Harry", "John", "Dick"}

---

**Mathematica V10+ (26)**:

```
Keys@Sort[Counts[n],#>#2&]
```

Comment: @garej older version in use. Post as another answer?

Comment: I've added to yours if you do not mind...

Comment: @garej. Thanks, excellent solution!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6 (36 bytes, 35 characters)

`»` can be replaced with `>>`, if you cannot handle UTF-8. I'm almost sure this could be shorter, but the `Bag` class is relatively strange in its behavior (sadly), and isn't really complete, as it's relatively new (but it can count arguments). `{}` declares an anonymous function.

```
{(sort -*.value,pairs bag @_)».key}
```

Sample output (from Perl 6 REPL):

```
> my @names = ("John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John")
John Doe Dick Harry Harry Doe Doe Harry Doe John
> {(sort -*.value,pairs bag @_)».key}(@names)
Doe Harry John Dick
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby: 34 <del>37</del> characters

```
f=->a{a.sort_by{|z|-a.count(z)}&a}
```

(edited: previous 30-char solution was the body of the function)

Comment: You can trim a few characters with `f=->a{a.sort_by{|z|-a.count(z)}&a}` . The `&` does a uniq.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, 14 chars (19 as named function, also 14 as full program)

```
:a.|{[.]a\-,}$
```

This code takes an array on the stack and sorts its unique elements in descending order by number of occurrences.  For example, if the input array is:

```
["John" "Doe" "Dick" "Harry" "Harry" "Doe" "Doe" "Harry" "Doe" "John"]
```

then the output array will be

```
["Doe" "Harry" "John" "Dick"]
```

**Note:** The code above is a bare sequence of statements.  To turn it into a named function, wrap it in braces and assign it to a name, as in:

```
{:a.|{[.]a\-,}$}:f;
```

Alternatively, to turn the code into a full program that reads a list from standard input (using the list notation shown above) and prints it to standard output, prepend `~` and append `` ` `` to the code.  The `[.` [can be omitted in this case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/tips-for-golfing-in-golfscript/8758#8758) (since we know there will be nothing else on the stack), so that the resulting 14-character program will be:

```
~:a.|{]a\-,}$`
```

---

#### How does it work?

- `:a` saves a copy of the original array in the variable `a` for later use.
- `.|` computes the set union of the array with itself, eliminating duplicates as a side effect.
- `{ }$` sorts the de-duplicated array using the custom sort keys computed by the code inside the braces.  This code takes each array element, uses array subtraction to remove it from the original input array saved in `a`, and counts the number of remaining elements.  Thus, the elements get sorted in decreasing order of frequency.

**Ps.** [See here](/revisions/17383/3) for the original 30-character version.

Comment: I think that `[a\])^` should be equivalent to `[.;]a\-`. Sorting by number of non-matching elements is a nice idea.

Comment: Alas, no: `^` collapses duplicates, `-` doesn't. (And ITYM `(`, not `)`.) `[a\](\-` would work, but wouldn't save any characters.

Answer (score 2):

### R: 23 characters

```
n <- c("John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John")

names(sort(table(n),T))
## [1] "Doe"   "Harry" "John"  "Dick"
```

But it uses the not so nice shortcut of `T` to `TRUE`...

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
>#'=:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nyk5Z3dbqf5qGkld@Rp6StZJLfiqIzEzOBlIeiUVFlUg0VBJMooqBdWv@BwA)

- `=:` group the input, building a dictionary mapping unique values to the indices in which they appear
- `#'` take the count of each set of indices
- `>` sort the keys of the dictionary by their values, descending

Answer (score 1):

if this could fit here : `In sql-server`

```
create table #t1 (name varchar(10))
insert into #t1 values ('John'),('Doe'),('Dick'),('Harry'),('Harry'),('Doe'),('Doe'),('Harry'),('Doe'),('John')


select name from #t1 group by name order by count(*) desc
```

OR

```
with cte as
(

select name,count(name) as x from #t1 group by name
)

select name from cte order by x desc
```

## [see it in action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0032/3)

Comment: Why the CTE? `select name from #t1 group by name order by count(*) desc`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>63 62</strike> 61 chars

```
function R($a){foreach($a as$v)$b[$v]++;arsort($b);return$b;}
```

Demo:

```
$c = array("John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John");
$d = print_r(R($c));

Array ( [Doe] => 4 [Harry] => 3 [John] => 2 [Dick] => 1 )
```

Comment: have a look at `array_count_values()`… That's all you have to use (including `arsort()`)

Comment: `array_count_values()` does not delete duplicated values, nor orders them, as I can see.

Comment: It deletes the duplicates … It just doesn't order them… => arsort

Comment: @bwoebi You are right. Unfortunately writing it that way is 1 character longer than this answer.

Comment: Why is the way with `array_count_values` longer? `<?$u=array_count_values($_GET);arsort($u);print_r($u);` are 54 Bytes in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: 59 characters

```ruby
f=->n{n.group_by{|i|i}.sort_by{|i|-i[1].size}.map{|i|i[0]}}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> f=->n{n.group_by{|i|i}.sort_by{|i|-i[1].size}.map{|i|i[0]}}
=> #<Proc:0x93b2e10@(irb):2 (lambda)>

irb(main):004:0> f[["John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John"]]
=> ["Doe", "Harry", "John", "Dick"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 39 characters

```
f = Reverse[First /@ SortBy[Tally@#, Last]] &

names = {"John", "Doe", "Dick", "Harry", "Harry",
         "Doe", "Doe", "Harry", "Doe", "John"};

f@names
```

> {Doe, Harry, John, Dick}

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript5): <s>118</s> 113 characters

```
function f(n){m={}
for(i in n){m[n[i]]=m[n[i]]+1||1}
return Object.keys(m).sort(function(a,b){return m[b]-m[a]})}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/crg5B/

Comment: With Harmony's [fat arrow functions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax): `f=n=>{m={};n.forEach(e=>m[e]=m[e]+1||1);return Object.keys(m).sort((a,b)=>m[b]-m[a])}`. (Currently only in Firefox.)

Comment: You can use `m[n[i]]=-~m[n[i]]` to increment, and you don't need {}s around the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

## C#: 111 characters

```
List<string>M(List<string>l){return l.GroupBy(q=>q).OrderByDescending(g=>g.Count()).Select(g=>g.Key).ToList();}
```

(inside a class)

```
var names = new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Dick", "Harry", "Harry", "Doe", "Doe", "Harry", "Doe", "John"};
foreach(var s in M(names))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

> Doe
>
> Harry
>
> John
>
> Dick

A simple solution using LINQ.

Comment: You could also remove the **.ToList()**, since the sequence get enumerated via the **foreach**

Comment: That's true, but then I'd have to change the return type into **IEnumerable<string>**.

Answer (score 1):

**Haskell - 53 Characters**

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

f :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
f=map head.(sortBy$flip$comparing length).group.sort
```

Explanation: the first two lines are necessary imports, the next line of code is the type signature (generally not necessary), the actual function is the last line.
The function sorts the list by its natural ordering, groups equal elements into lists, sorts the list of lists by descending size, and takes the first element in each list.

total length including imports: 120

w/o imports but with type signature: 86

function itself: 53

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure: 43 characters

Function:

```
#(keys(sort-by(comp - val)(frequencies %)))
```

Demo (in repl):

```
user=> (def names ["John","Doe","Dick","Harry","Harry","Doe","Doe","Harry","Doe","John"])
#'user/names
user=> (#(keys(sort-by(comp - val)(frequencies %))) names)
("Doe" "Harry" "John" "Dick")
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 8 bytes

```
~.\:#/.~
```

### Usage

The names are stored as an array of boxed strings.

```
   'John';'Doe';'Dick';'Harry';'Harry';'Doe';'Doe';'Harry';'Doe';'John'
┌────┬───┬────┬─────┬─────┬───┬───┬─────┬───┬────┐
│John│Doe│Dick│Harry│Harry│Doe│Doe│Harry│Doe│John│
└────┴───┴────┴─────┴─────┴───┴───┴─────┴───┴────┘
   f =: ~.\:#/.~
   f 'John';'Doe';'Dick';'Harry';'Harry';'Doe';'Doe';'Harry';'Doe';'John'
┌───┬─────┬────┬────┐
│Doe│Harry│John│Dick│
└───┴─────┴────┴────┘
```

### Explanation

```
~.\:#/.~   Input: A
    #/.~   Finds the size of each set of identical items (Frequencies)
~.         List the distinct values in A
           Note: the distinct values and frequencies will be in the same order
  \:       Sort the distinct values in decreasing order according to the frequencies
           Return the sorted list implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 15 bytes

```
q~$e`{0=W*}$1f=
```

This may use CJam features from after this challenge was posted. I'm too lazy to check.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÙΣ¢}R
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Mxziw8tqg36/z9aySs/I09JR8klPxVEZiZnAymPxKKiSiQaKgkmUcXAumMB)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù    # Uniquify the (implicit) input-list
 Σ   # Sort this uniquified list by:
  ¢  #  Get its count in the (implicit) input-list
 }R  # After the ascending sort: reverse the list, so it'll become descending
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
èó±☻₧╛╗
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8aa2f1029ebebb&i=%5B%22John%22,%22Doe%22,%22Dick%22,%22Harry%22,%22Harry%22,%22Doe%22,%22Doe%22,%22Harry%22,%22Doe%22,%22John%22%5D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Qċ@ÞṚ⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/wSLfD4XkPd8561Ljr/@F2b5VHTWsi//@PVvLKz8hT0lFyyU8FkZnJ2UDKI7GoqBKJhkqCSVQxsO5YHQA)

There are quite a few ways to formulate this, but I find this to be the most amusing of several 6-byte alternatives. `ċ@Þ@QṚ` comes rather close.

```
Q         Unique items of the input.
   Þ      Sort them by
 ċ@       how many times they appear in the input
    Ṛ     reversed.
     ⁺    Duplicate the last link: reverse the sorted result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
u↔Ö#¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v/RR25TD05QP7fz//3@0kld@Rp6SjpJLfiqIzEzOBlIeiUVFlUg0VBJMooqBdccCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```
[ sorted-histogram keys reverse ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY29CsJAEIT7PMW8gHkAbQP@FDZiJRbLuZojyV2yuxoO8dnPIwgWM8MMA9@dnEXJ59P@uF1jIGtrNTKv5p2CVGMJ5enJwbGiYwncYxQ2S6P4YJhmbKpqmt84xDagiYzGuw47Ekk/X8aif1u@n3yBRjG@rdpCjA@hoSCSQvjFooxrdtT3qPMX)

### Explanation

```
                 ! { "John" "Doe" "Dick" "Harry" "Harry" "Doe" "Doe" "Harry" "Doe" "John" }
sorted-histogram ! { { "Dick" 1 } { "John" 2 } { "Harry" 3 } { "Doe" 4 } }
keys             ! { "Dick" "John" "Harry" "Doe" }
reverse          ! { "Doe" "Harry" "John" "Dick" }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl

to meet given i/o spec I need 120 chars

```
s!"([^"]+)"[],]!$a{$1}++!e while(<>);print 'MostOccuring = [',join(',',map{qq("$_")}sort{$a{$a}<=>$a{$b}}keys %a),"]\n"
```

pure shortest code by taking one item per line and printing one item per line I only need 55 chars

```
$a{$_}++ while(<>);print sort{$a{$a}<=>$a{$b}}keys %a)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala (71)

```
(x.groupBy(a=>a)map(t=>(t._1,t._2.length))toList)sortBy(-_._2)map(_._1)
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(x:Array[String]) =
  (x.groupBy(a => a) map (t => (t._1, t._2.length)) toList) 
    sortBy(-_._2) map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
sub f{my%k;$k{$_}++for@_;sort{$k{$b}-$k{$a}}keys%k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrTq3UjXbWiW7WiW@Vls7Lb/IId66OL@opBoklFSrC6ISa2uzUyuLVbNr/zsk2qZpKHnlZ@Qp6Si55KeCyMzkbCDlkVhUVIlEQyXBJKoYWLemdXFipZJDotL/f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)