# Group a List by Frequency

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a list of integers, group the elements which occur most first, then group the next most and so on until each unique element in the list has been grouped once.

---

## Examples:

**Input:** `[1,2,3]`

**Output:** `[[1,2,3]]`

---

**Input:** `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]`

**Output:** `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]`

---

**Input:** `[1,1,1,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,-56]`

**Output:** `[[6, 8],[5],[1],[7],[9,4,-56]]`

---

**Input:** `[]`

**Output:** `[]`

---

**Input:** `(empty input)`

**Output:** `ERROR/Undefined/Doesn't matter`

---

## Rules

- Groupings must go from maximal frequency to minimal frequency.
- Internal order of the groupings are arbitrary (E.G. example 3 could have `[8,6]` instead).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

## Related

- [Sort the distinct elements of a list in descending order by frequency](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17287/sort-the-distinct-elements-of-a-list-in-descending-order-by-frequency)

Comment: Can the output be in string format? Ie. A list of lists, but each number represented by a character instead of an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
_{M.g/Q
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_%7BM.g%2FQ&input=%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C7%2C7%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C9%2C5%2C6%2C5%2C6%2C5%2C6%2C5%2C6%2C-56%5D&debug=0)

1 byte thanks to FryAmTheEggman.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma you can't; it's in a lambda; the implicit variable there is `k`, which I have already omitted.

Comment: got it - thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Congratulations.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn thank you.

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
Union/@SortBy[l=#,f=-l~Count~#&]~SplitBy~f&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fbvs/NC8zP0/fITi/qMSpMjrHVlknzVY3p845vzSvpE5ZLbYuuCAnEyhVl6b2P6AoM69EwUEhHYirDXUUIMhER8FUR8EMhszByAIbsoSpxCR1Tc1q/wMA) (Using Mathics.)

Alternatively:

```
SortBy[Union[l=#],f=-l~Count~#&]~SplitBy~f&
```

Comment: There's no built-in?

Comment: Is `GatherBy` an option, not sure because I don't know the language.

Comment: @carusocomputing It sorts the groups by the first occurrence of the elements in the original list, so I'd still have to sort the groups afterwards. By sorting the list first, I can save a byte with `SplitBy` (also the `SortBy` would actually be more complicated if I did `GatherBy` first).

Comment: Interesting, so the "must be in order from maximal to minimal" messes that up?

Comment: @carusocomputing Exactly.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>95</s> 101 bytes

```js
a=>a.map(x=>(o[a.map(y=>n+=x!=y,n=0)|n]=o[n]||[])[x*x+(x>0)]=x,o=[])&&(F=o=>o.filter(a=>a))(o).map(F)
```

#### How?

For each element ***x*** of the input array ***a***, we compute the number ***n*** of elements of ***a*** that are different from ***x***:

```js
a.map(y => n += x != y, n = 0) | n
```

We use the indices ***n*** and ***x*** to fill the array ***o***:

```js
(o[n] = o[n] || [])[x * x + (x > 0)] = x
```

***Edit***: Because JS doesn't support negative array indices, we need the formula `x * x + (x > 0)` to force positive indices.

This gives us an array of arrays containing the unique elements of the original list, grouped by frequency and ordered from most frequent to least frequent.

However, both the outer array and the inner arrays potentially have many empty slots that we want to filter out. We do this with the function ***F***, applied to ***o*** and each of its elements:

```js
F = o => o.filter(a => a)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(x=>(o[a.map(y=>n+=x!=y,n=0)|n]=o[n]||[])[x*x+(x>0)]=x,o=[])&&(F=o=>o.filter(a=>a))(o).map(F)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,3]))) // [[1,2,3]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]))) // [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,1,1,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,-56]))) // [[6, 8],[5],[1],[7],[9,4,-56]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([]))) // []
```

Comment: I think a `Set` saves you a byte: `a=>a.map(e=>(r[n=0,a.map(f=>n+=e!=f),n]||(r[n]=new Set)).add(e),r=[])&&r.filter(s=>s).map(s=>[...s])`.

Comment: @Neil This is quite different from my current approach. Maybe you should post it as a new answer?

Comment: I didn't think changing `o[n]` from an array to a set was that different, but I already golfed @RickHitchcock's answer anyway so there's not that much point.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>145</s> 141 bytes

```
import collections as c,itertools as i;o=lambda n:lambda l:l[n]
print[map(o(0),g)for _,g in i.groupby(c.Counter(input()).most_common(),o(1))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBCsIwEAXQvafIMoFYrNhqK648RikljbUOJDMhnS56@liLC@XxYT4fJiz8IjymBD5QZGHJucEyEE7CTMJq4CEykdsqXOnmjO8fRmD9PVztGmx3IQJy402QJA9Kj@pJUXR6FIACsjHSHPpF2uxOM64vJWCYWSqVeZq4s@Q9oVSaZK5Um1KT64@TLnS5Oa8uf6pt@82@KNs3)

This is my first submission after years of reading.

> It basically it puts all the elements into a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (dictionary of how many of each element in the list) and [.most_common()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) puts the items in decending frequency order. After that, it's just a matter of formatting the items into the right list.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126159/group-a-list-by-frequency/126200?noredirect=1#comment310701_126200).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :). Don't get as addicted as I did.

Comment: Creating your own itemgetter function is 4 bytes shorter than importing it: `o=lambda n:lambda l:l[n]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
QɓċÐ€ĠṚị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/w5OQj3YcnPGpac2TBw52zHu7u/n@4Hcg7OunhzhlAOvL//2guhWhDHSMd41gdMAsEjUB8IDTRMdUxQxIH88HQHAgtUKAlWA4Z65pC9MZyxQIA)

Comment: Did... Pyth... beat... Jelly?

Comment: Jelly doesn't have group-by, so that shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 85 bytes

```php
<?$r=[];foreach(array_count_values($_GET)as$k=>$v)$r[$v][]=$k;krsort($r);print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4/C8IwFMT3fo43JNAOgq1KjA5SxEWXbiGEUFJbKk14/QMufmvnGDMpPw4OjnvvXOv8/uhalxhEiwqNszh1w528SnW9VZdTSVkC6lxWXKzSL@s0T4vIJrD9YxezX2V5IZkH5EKyxqLRdUs0on6q2s7DpBb9mM1I4geqR@j5ARYKKGCRQnLoWY9jmEQAKXPYhQpG7/17sFkd7pkP)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 74 bytes

```
#(for[[_ g](sort-by(comp - key)(group-by val(frequencies %)))](map key g))
```

Looks quite verbose :/

Comment: Beat me to it (and beat me by a few bytes, clever use of `comp -` to reverse!). Not as short as other languages, but I thought it was amusing since Clojure has "group-by" and "frequencies" built in.

Comment: When I read the task description I was hoping for 50 or 60 bytes, but the actual implementation turned out to be a bit trickier.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 43 bytes

```perl6
*.Bag.classify(-*.value).sort».value».key
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##hVDLasMwELzrK/ZggpzKgqaN8zAJTSGnvi6lUIwJqqMUU8UWlh1qQr6st/6Yu5KT0J7KsGh3NTO7kpalCtvaSNiFPI3ItoFeWqwlzNo@vxXvPFXCmGzT0KDPd0LV0uemKKvvr67C80M2rRPeVNJUMAOV5dJQn2@Fnu4JgHV/eHq8W75GWC1fFvfgrciB2P4zSiKilcjhwukjsinKo1UwBwpT9Kdeluu68hlM3VTqyU8t00quffDBzshMsJZSqwbs9ic@76UiL/IsFYrBWfNvl2v8FVzQ1G9wbgL1Vt0s@zC6j90/JAefL8pSNOTQxpdswK4SmM0hPuYsIZhZDGyNuGZDFp44CYsdK@66Z7IrHUaI8R9M3N3vCIYnw5DBGN2GGNZ7hDFBM0tA746U/AA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
*                   # WhateverCode lambda (this is the input)
                    # [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]

.Bag                # turn into a Bag
                    # (1=>3,5=>1,4=>1,3=>2,6=>1,2=>2).Bag

.classify(-*.value) # classify by how many times each was seen
                    # {-2=>[3=>2,2=>2],-3=>[1=>3],-1=>[5=>1,4=>1,6=>1]}

.sort\              # sort (this is why the above is negative)
                    # {-3=>[1=>3],-2=>[3=>2,2=>2],-1=>[5=>1,4=>1,6=>1]}

».value\            # throw out the classification
                    # ([1=>3],[3=>2,2=>2],[5=>1,4=>1,6=>1])

».key               # throw out the counts
                    # ([1],[3,2],[5,4,6])
```

Comment: Wow, I always forget about `Bag`, nice one!

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, <strike>71</strike> 61

```bash
sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|awk '{printf$1-a?"\n%d":",%d",$2;a=$1}'
```

Input as a newline-delimited list.  Output as a newline-delimited list of comma-separated values.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi/qKSmNC@zUEE3uQbEUdDNK6pJLM9WUK8uKMrMK0lTMbS1TbRX0lFNUbJSiskDUjoqRtaJtiqGter//xtygaAJlymXGRiaA6EFCrQEyyFjXVMzAA).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 79 bytes

```
Table[#&@@@f[[i]],{i,Length[f=GatherBy[Sort[Tally@#,#1[[2]]>#2[[2]]&],Last]]}]&
```

**input**

> [{1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5,
>      6, 5, 6, -56}]

**output**

> {{8, 6}, {5}, {1}, {7}, {-56, 9, 4}}

Comment: The GatherBy I mentioned to Martin! I wondered how this would be done :).

Comment: `Sort[...,...&]` is just `SortBy[...,-Last@#&]`.

Comment: `Length[f=...]`. And `First/@` is `#&@@@`.

Comment: fixed, fixed and fixed

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
9B#uw3XQP
```

Input is a column vector, using `;` as separator.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39JJubTcOCIw4P//aENrEDSxNrU2A0NzILRAgZZgOWSsa2oWCwA)**

#### Explanation

```
9B#u   % Call 'unique' function with first and fourth outputs: unique entries and
       % number of occurrences
w      % Swap
3XQ    % Call 'accumarray' with anonymous function @(x){sort(x).'}. The output is
       % a cell array with the elements of the input grouped by their frequency.
       % Cells are sorted by increasing frequency. Some cells may be empty, but
       % those won't be displayed
P      % Flip cell array, so that groups with higher frequency appear first.
       % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> 77 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to mb7744*

```r
unique(lapply(x<-sort(table(scan()),T),function(y)as.double(names(x[x==y]))))
```

Reads from stdin; returns a list with subvectors of integers in increasing order. If we could return strings instead of ints, then I could drop 11 bytes (removing the call to `as.double`), but that's about it. R's `table` function does the heavy lifting here, counting the occurrences of each member of its input; then it aggregates them by count (`names`). Of course, that's a string, so we have to coerce it to an integer/double.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzQvs7A0VSMnsaAgp1Kjwka3OL@oRKMkMSknVaM4OTFPQ1NTJ0RTJ600L7kkMz9Po1IzsVgvJb8UJJ@XmJtarFERXWFrWxmrCQT/DRVA0ETBVMEMDM2B0AIFWoLlkLGuqdl/AA)

Comment: You can lose 7 bytes by eliminating the "which", and using logical indexing

Comment: @mb7744 oh duh.

Comment: I took another stab at it with R. It's unfortunate how long the lambda syntax is, so I set out trying to avoid it. In exchange I had to use nested `lapply`'s, but at least in that case I can assign a short variable to `lapply`. I can't seem to assign a variable to the the function `function`...

Answer (score 2):

## k, 22 bytes

```
{x@!x}{(>x)@=x@>x}#:'=
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%7Bx%40%21x%7D%7B%28%3Ex%29%40%3Dx%40%3Ex%7D%23%3A%27%3D1%201%201%204%205%206%206%206%207%207%208%208%208%208%208%208%208%209%205%206%205%206%205%206%205%206%20-56)

<sup>([AW's k](https://kparc.com) seems to require an extra `@` before the `#`, but oK does not.)</sup>

Explanation:

```
                     = /group identical numbers in a map/dict
                  #:'  /get number of times each number is repeated
                       /this is almost the answer, but without the inner lists
      {      x@>x}     /order "number of times" greatest to least
            =          /group them (to make the smaller groups)
       (>x)@           /get the actual numbers into place
{x@!x}                 /get values of the map/dict it's in
```

Comment: https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok for anyone else wondering what `k` is, it's actually `ok`. Ba-dum-tssss...

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
ọtᵒ¹tᵍhᵐ²|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@Hu3pKHWycd2gkkezMebp1waFPN///RhjogaKJjqmMGhuZAaIECLcFyyDje1Cz2fxQA)

#### Explanation

```
Example input: [2,1,1,3]

ọ            Occurences:            [[2,1],[1,2],[3,1]]
 tᵒ¹         Order desc. by tail:   [[1,2],[3,1],[2,1]]
    tᵍ       Group by tail:         [[[1,2]],[[3,1],[2,1]]]
      hᵐ²    Map twice head:        [[1],[3,2]]

         |   Else (Input = [])      Input = Output
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>100</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 93 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil (plus he fixed an edge-case bug in my code).  Saved 3 more bytes thanks to @TomasLangkaas.*

```
a=>a.sort().map((_,n)=>a.filter((v,i)=>i-a.indexOf(v)==n&v!=a[i+1])).filter(a=>a+a).reverse()
```

**Test cases**

```js
f=
a=>a.sort().map((_,n)=>a.filter((v,i)=>i-a.indexOf(v)==n&v!=a[i+1])).filter(a=>a+a).reverse()

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,3])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,1,1,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,-56])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([])))
```

Comment: Your test is flawed (doesn't work for zero) but I think you can still save bytes by filtering and reversing instead of unshifting: `a=>a.sort().map((_,n)=>a.filter((v,i)=>i-a.indexOf(v)==n&v!=a[i+1])).filter(a=>1/a[0]).reverse()`.

Comment: Ahh, I should have known to test for 0!  Your code fixes it, plus it's shorter, so thank you for that : )

Comment: Save 3 more bytes by changing `.filter(a=>1/a[0])` to `.filter(a=>''+a)`.

Comment: Nice one, @TomasLangkaas, thanks.  (Saves 2 bytes.)

Comment: My bad (have trouble  with counting), but `.filter(a=>a+a)` would provide the extra byte.

Comment: Yes, that does it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>6</s></sup> 5 bytes

```
↔k#¹u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5flZpbfGhnbn7xo6bG/4/apmQrH9pZ@v///@hoQx0jHeNYHSANgkYgHhCa6JjqmMFFwTwwNAdCCxRoCZZDxrqmIJ2xsQA)

-1 byte from Leo.

### Explanation

```
↔k#¹u 
    u uniquify the input 
 k#¹  key on frequency in input
↔     reverse
```

Comment: You could save 1 byte by uniquifying the original list instead of the final groups https://tio.run/##yygtzv5flZpbfGhnbn7xo6bG/4/apmQrH9pZ@v///@hoQx0jHeNYHSANgkYgHhCa6JjqmMFFwTwwNAdCCxRoCZZDxrqmIJ2xsQA

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÙΣ¢}R.γ¢
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Mxziw8tqg3SO7f50KL//6MNdUDQRMdUxwwMzYHQAgVaguWQsa6pWSwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf8Pzzy3@NC64kOLaoP0zm0Gs/7X6vyPjjbUMdIxjtUB0iBoBOIBoYmOqY4ZXBTMA0NzILRAgZZgOWSsawrSGaujpBQLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù       # Uniquify the (implicit) input-list
 Σ      # Sort this uniquified list by:
  ¢     #  Get its count in the (implicit) input-list
 }R     # After the ascending sort: reverse it to make it descending
   .γ   # Then adjacently group each value by:
     ¢  #  Its count in the (implicit) input-list
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The `.γ` could have been `.¡` for the same result. `.¡` is the group-by builtin, and `.γ` is the adjacently group-by builtin. But since we use a sort first, the result ends up buying the same.
Unfortunately, 05AB1E lacks a sort & group-by as single builtin, so we'll have to do it in two steps instead (like most existing answers tbh).

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 63 bytes

```
[ histogram unzip swap zip expand-keys-push-at values reverse ]
```

[image: Running the above code in Factor's REPL with some test cases]

### Explanation

```
                     ! { 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 }
histogram            ! H{ { 1 3 } { 2 2 } { 3 2 } { 4 1 } { 5 1 } { 6 1 } }
unzip                ! { 1 2 3 4 5 6 } { 3 2 2 1 1 1 }
swap                 ! { 3 2 2 1 1 1 } { 1 2 3 4 5 6 }
zip                  ! { { 3 1 } { 2 2 } { 2 3 } { 1 4 } { 1 5 } { 1 6 }
expand-keys-push-at  ! H{ { 1 V{ 4 5 6 } } { 2 V{ 2 3 } } { 3 V{ 1 } } }
values               ! { V{ 4 5 6 } V{ 2 3 } V{ 1 } }
reverse              ! { V{ 1 } V{ 2 3 } V{ 4 5 6 } }
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
def f(l):
 r=[[]for _ in l]
 for x in{*l}:r[-l.count(x)]+=x,
 return[*filter(bool,r)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvBCsIwEETv/Yo9JnVbEG2thX5JCIKaYGBJypJCpPjtMe1JeczhMTPzO76CP@X8NBasIDlWwJNS2gaGGzgPpCvYJBVZa/qMrBpqH2HxUSSpD1PCcjFxYa9q6ygaFvcQCFnqPLMrMyvUETfO2GG/cykMf1z37jdN12sp8xc)

-12 thanks to tips from @ovs!

Comment: This will currently fail if all elements are the same, because `r` is too short. `r=[[]for _ in s*2]` would be a simple fix, but replacing `r[l.count(x)]` with `r[-l.count(x)]` fixes this as well, while removing the `[::-1]`

Comment: And a few golfing hints: The assignment to `s` is not worth it, the last line can be shorter with a `filter` and using tuples instead of lists for the inner containers can save a few bytes

Comment: @ovs thanks! your tips helped a lot. I used `l` instead of `s*2` and removed `s` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>60</s>, 54 bytes

```
ÚòÍ¨¼¾©î±/± ±òHòø 
pkJjòú!
Ç¨^ƒ ©î±/o
Îf ld|;D
òV{Jk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Csw5sO9x5acWjPocZD@w6tPLzu0Eb9QxsVDm08vMkDKLVDgasg2ysLyNqlyHW4/dCKuEPNCodWHmoEK8znOtyXppCTUmPtwnV4U1i1V/b//4ZcIGjCZcplBobmQGiBAi3BcshY19QMAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: daf2 cda8 bc81 bea9 eeb1 2fb1 20b1 f248  ........../. ..H
00000010: f2f8 200a 706b 4a6a f2fa 210a c7a8 5e83  .. .pkJj..!...^.
00000020: 20a9 81ee b12f 6f0a ce66 206c 647c 3b44   ..../o..f ld|;D
00000030: 0af2 567b 4a6b                           ..V{Jk
```

As much as I love V, I'm pretty sure this is the worst possible language for the task. Especially considering it has no support for lists, and basically no support for numbers. Just string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell, <strike>77,</strike> 70 bytes**

```
($a=$args)|group{($a-eq$_).count}|sort n* -Des|%{,($_.group|sort -u)}
```

NB: To see that these results are correctly grouped (since visually there's no deliniation between the contents of each array), you may wish to append `| write-host` to the end of the above line.

**Acknowledgements**

Thanks to:

- [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler) for saving 7 bytes by massively refactoring / rewriting to a way more golfed approach.

---

**Previous**

*77 bytes*

```
param($x)$x|group|sort count -desc|group count|%{,($_.group|%{$_.group[0]})}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I had to inlclude the `,()` for grouping (since output was just showing as one continuous array).  This is way more golfy than my original attempt; awesome work!

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 119 bytes

Just a quick stab at it:

```
using System.Linq;
a=>a.GroupBy(x=>x)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Count(),x=>x.Key)
    .OrderBy(x=>-x.Key)
    .Select(x=>x.ToArray())
    .ToArray()
```

Comment: +1 You can remove the `System.Func<int[],int[][]>F=` and trailing `;` though. That isn't part of the byte-count for these kind of lambdas.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, I had no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.group_by{|e|a.count(e)}.sort_by{|x,_|-x}.map{|_,i|i|[]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCoMwEETv/Yo9trAGqkbtwf5ICCEWLR5aJVVQknx7uqalWB6zh53ZHTM3a@jqkFy11exuhnlUzWpd6zS7DfNzOrYnz16DmeJ6QeWSxbOHHq1T2LveCel9GKET4owbKZFhjhwLKaGugQyJINJtZAg5Akcg77A7ivFISVR/XKK3V8J/rwuESqLgJGoRJSmni5j4FHyTMrwB)

There has got to be a shorter way to do this.

Comment: save one byte by removing the parentheses from `a.count e`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 66 bytes

```r
(l=lapply)(l(split(x<-table(scan()),factor(-x)),names),as.integer)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VclLCoAwDEXRrXSYgBUEv6CLiVKlEGtpO9DVx@pIOVx48III8MTkPV8IDNGzTXCOOtHMBuJCDhCLlZZ0BNBn3o52E7GgWFqXzGYCSqUetWpU@@qy/md4v2@6aUVu)

If in the output the integers may be in string format, can drop to **48 bytes** (as mentioned in @Giuseppe's answer).

---

Ungolfed:

```r
input <- scan(); # read input
x <- table(input); # count how many times each integer appears, in a named vector
y <- split(x, factor(-x)) # split the count into lists in increasing order
z <- lapply(y, names) # access the the original values which are still
                      # attached via the names
lapply(z, as.integer) # convert the names back to integers
```

Comment: `as.double` is shorter by one byte, and it should work the same as `as.integer`

Comment: Well, it depends whether you want to return an integer or a double. If double is okay, maybe character would be as well, and we could both save some bytes.

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyexoCCnUqO4ICezRKPCRrc4OTFPQ1MnsSxVo0KnQsct1M@2JDEpJ1VTU6c0L7OwNFXzv6ECCJoomCqYgaE5EFqgQEuwHDLWNTX7/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 89 bytes

```perl
map$k{$_}++,@F;$_="@{[sort{$k{$b}-$k{$a}}keys%k]}";s/\S+ /$&.'| 'x($k{1*$&}!=$k{1*$'})/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlu1olvlZbW8fBzVol3lbJoTq6OL@opBoknlSrC6ISa2uzUyuLVbNja5Wsi/VjgrUV9FXU9NRrFNQrNIAKDLVU1GoVbSEs9VpN/fTU///NFEwVTBSMgdAICA1B8F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ugWJAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 71 bytes

```
{a->a.groupBy{a.count(it)}.sort{-it.key}.values().collect{it.unique()}}
```

I actually just learned about groupBy after creating this. I didn't know collect wasn't my only choice.

---

```
{
    a->                 // [1,2,1,2,3,3,3,6,5,4]
    a.groupBy{      
        a.count(it)     // [2:[1,2,1,2],3:[3,3,3],1:[6,5,4]]
    }.sort{             
        -it.key         // [3:[3,3,3],2:[1,2,1,2],1:[6,5,4]]
    }.values().collect{ // [[3,3,3],[1,2,1,2],[6,5,4]]
        it.unique()
    }                   // [[3],[1,2],[6,5,4]]
}
```