# Random ticket code generator

Tags: code-golf, number, random, generation

A lottery company wants to generate a random lottery ticket number of length 10 characters.

Write a code in any language to create such a number in which every digit comes only once for example `9354716208` in this number all integers from 0 to 9 comes only once. This number should be a random number.

- The generated number should be shown on screen.
- It must be able to generate all permutations of all allowable characters.
- The code is required to be as small as possible (in bytes).

Comment: Why should it be in Java or PhP?

Comment: @Fabinout Sorry, you can write it in any language.

Comment: Generally, it's good idea to allow any language, according to [tag:code-golf] description.

Comment: I take it that all passwords beginning with zero should be possible.

Comment: Can the password be output as an array of characters?

Comment: @DavidCarraher I see nowhere in this question that the output is expected to be a "password". The challenge is asking to generate a "number". Thus, I think it's appropriate to assume that an array of characters is not acceptable. A string, in a language where strings are also treated as arrays of characters, may be - but something which is an array only probably is not. The following may be acceptable: `1234567890` or `"1234567890"`. However, this probably would not: `"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"` nor the same with newlines instead of commas - with or without quotes in the output.

Comment: Yes. I meant to say "number". Btw, I agree that instructions appear to request a number (an integer or string integer). I was hoping that Ankush would explain his position.

Comment: How is it that one of the longest and least golfed answers (the SQL answer), without even a char count, stand as the accepted answer in [tag:code-golf] when folks like @Howard have 5 or 8 character answers?

Comment: Yes, @marinus has a 4 byte solution (mine is 6 bytes)

Comment: -1 The selection of the winner is improper, given that this was a code-golf challenge.

Comment: I am equally confused, the accept answer (which is massive by code-golf standards) was submitted ***after*** a GolfScript answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### J (4 bytes)

Couldn't resist.

```
?~10
```

In J, if `F` is dyadic , `F~ x` is the same as `x F x`.

Comment: +1 I think I may have to try something slightly more terse than Python to beat this.

Comment: Does this allow for a password that begins with zero?  According to the rules, the program "must be able to generate all permutations of all allowable characters"

Comment: @DavidCarraher: yes. It selects 10 non-repeating random numbers from the interval `[0..10)`, so that basically means a random permutation of '0123456789'.

Comment: I see. I raised this because in most languages, the "number", 0123456789, will automatically be edited to the form 123456789. The string, "0123456789", remains untouched. So my question is really this: is your output a number or a string?

Comment: @DavidCarraher It's an array.

Comment: +1, if I wouldn't run out of votes. Seriously, I knew that J programs can be short, but like this?

Comment: marinus I have doubts about whether an array of characters can be considered a number. It would need to have its elements concatenated in some way. I'll ask the OP to get his view

Answer (score 12):

#### J, 5 characters and APL, 8 characters

**J**

```
10?10
```

J has the built-in deal operator (`?`). Thus, we can take 10 out of 10 (`10?10`).

**APL**

```
1-⍨10?10
```

APL has the same operator which unfortunately starts with one instead of zero. We are therefore subtracting one from each number (`1-⍨X` means `X-1` due to the commute operator).

Comment: Oh, wow, that's nice.

Comment: If OP would have asked specifically for the number not an array, you should convert it to base10 number also, with `10#.`

Comment: You may assume that `⎕IO←0` so you don't have to subtract one. Also, for both J and APL, you can use commute to save a byte with `?~10` and `?⍨10` since monadic application of the derived function uses its right argument also as left argument. NOte however that this makes the J code identical to [that of Marinus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17748/43319).

Answer (score 9):

**Python 2.7 (<s>64</s> <s>63</s> 57)**

Not a chance here compared to the operator heavy languages and due to the lack of default loaded random :) This is the shortest I could come up with;

```
from random import*
print''.join(sample("0123456789",10))
```

It creates a range and samples 10 numbers from it without replacement.

(Thanks to @xfix for the shorter import format fix and @blkknght for pointing out my somewhat über complicated sampling range)

**Python 2.7 (40)**

If you run it from the interactive prompt and can read comma separated, you can shave it to 40, but it feels a bit like breaking the spirit of the rules;

```
from random import*
sample(range(10),10)
```

Comment: You can use `from random import*` to save one character. This looks like my Perl 6 solution, but more verbose, but it's great to see that something like this can work in Python, even if more verbose.

Comment: @xfix Yes, sadly the modules in Python are a bit verbose to get to in comparison :) Updated with your import fix, quite new to the golfing thing so not up to "par" on my idioms.

Comment: You can save a few more characters by sampling from the string `"0123456789"` rather than using `range` and them mapping `str`.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks, updated with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 8):

## Perl 6 (<del>18</del> 16 characters)

```
print pick *,^10
```

This generates array containing all random elements (`pick *`) from `0` to `9` and outputs the result (`print`).

Sample output:

```
$ perl6 -e 'print pick *,^10'
4801537269
$ perl6 -e 'print pick *,^10'
1970384265
$ perl6 -e 'print pick *,^10'
3571684902
```

Comment: +1 I think you don't need the whitespace before `pick`.

Comment: @Howard: I actually need it. `[~]` (which is parsed as a listop, according to Perl 6 grammar) requires a whitespace (or paren) after it if it contains any arguments. Otherwise, Perl 6 compiler complains about "two terms in row". It wasn't needed in older versions of Perl 6, but this is the past. The Perl 6 is still being worked on.

Comment: @xfix: use `print` instead of `say [~]` and save 2 characters :)

Comment: @Ayiko: Thanks for an improvement :).

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby, 18

Run this in `irb`:

```
[*0..9].shuffle*''
```

If you want this to be a stand-alone program, with output to `stdout` (the rules don't seem to *require* this), then add these 4 chars at the start:

```
$><<
```

Comment: You may shorten `(0..9).to_a` to `[*0..9]`.

Comment: You're welcome. But why do you not use `[*0..9].shuffle` in the first place?

Comment: @Howard, because it's late and I'm dumb.  :)  Thanks!

Comment: this return array with number not number

Comment: @Monk_Code, could you prove it? On my machine it returns and `IO` object, but return value was not a requirement anyway. Otherwise it outputs a `String`. (Which in most languages is the only way to represent numbers beginning with `0`.)

Comment: @Monk_Code, no, the program outputs a 10-digit *string*. This is what the question asks for.

Comment: Why the `$><<`? `[*0..9].shuffle*''` on its own works just fine.

Comment: @AlexQueue, I wanted output. I used that because 1) it's 1 char shorter than `puts `, 2) it's 2 chars shorter than `print `, and I felt using `p ` was cheating because it includes double-quotes in the output.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP - 37 Characters

```
<?=join('',array_rand(range(0,9),10))
```

I had an 18-character solution that should theoretically work but PHP is weird.

Or, if you want an xkcd answer:

```
<?="5398421706" // Chosen by program above; guaranteed to be random ?>
```

EDIT: Thanks xfix, it's now 5 characters shorter and complete.
EDIT AGAIN: [Live example](http://codepad.org/gA8lIBWT).

Comment: Write a complete program, instead of just complete parts. Also, `echo` doesn't need parens, and if `echo` is the first statement in the program, you can replace `<?php echo` with `<?=`. Also, `join` is an alias for `implode`.

Comment: You don't even need the `<?=` and `?>`. It's valid PHP code without those.

Comment: @Jeremy The golf requires that the number be displayed; besides, `echo ` is the same length as `<?=` and `?>` combined, and without those, it doesn't work in Codepad. Thanks though. :P

Comment: I guess you're right. I was, however, thinking PHP in the terminal, where I guess you'd need an echo anyways.

Comment: @Jeremy Ah, PHP, where non-embedded implementations besides a terminal are scarce. :P

Comment: I get `0123456789` every time. Think it only works pre-5.2.10 since after that it has the result in order..

Comment: @Sylwester That's a very strange output. Array_rand must  be malfunctioning in the newer versions. :/

Comment: Am I doing something wrong, your live example gives the same number over and over again?

Comment: @TobyAllen Codepad only executes code once. Click "Create a new paste based on this one" and then click Submit.

Answer (score 8):

**PHP, 29 chars**

`<?=str_shuffle('0123456789');`

With PHP, the closing tag isn't required. But if that's against the rules, then you can replace ; with ?> for 1 net increase.

Comment: You beat me to this solution.

Answer (score 7):

#### GolfScript, 12 characters

```
10,{;9rand}$
```

Simply generates the list of digits (`10,`) and sorts it `{...}$` according to some random keys - which yields a random order of the digits.

Examples (try [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAsezs5cmFuZH0k&run=true)):

```
4860972315

0137462985
```

Comment: I was about to post this :P

Comment: That's kind of a crap shuffle, though: for example, the first digit is about three times as likely to be 0 than 1. Replacing `9rand` with `99rand` would (mostly) fix that; `9.?rand` would be [practically perfect](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5265).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I know, but the question didn't say anything about uniform distribution.

Answer (score 6):

### R (23 characters)

```
cat(sample(0:9),sep="")
```

Sample output:

```
> cat(sample(0:9),sep="")
3570984216
> cat(sample(0:9),sep="")
3820791654
> cat(sample(0:9),sep="")
0548697132
```

Answer (score 6):

### TI-BASIC, 5 bytes

```
randIntNoRep(1,10
```

Comment: Displays a list rather than a number. You're looking for `randIntNoRep(0,9:.1sum(Ans10^(cumSum(1 or Ans`.

Comment: I don't think this challenge requires an integer type, only that "The generated number should be shown on screen" which it is.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the question was asking for a number (as did [others](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/random-ticket-code-generator/17775?noredirect=1#comment34042_17723) but it seems the intent of the challenge author was never clarified. Some other solutions output as a list (J and APL) in any case.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't assume that unless I was sure, because this method is shorter.

Answer (score 5):

**Octave (14)**

```
randperm(10)-1
```

`randperm` unfortunately creates a selection from 1..n, so have to subtract 1 at the end to get 0-9.

Answer (score 5):

## In sql server

```
DECLARE @RandomNo varchar(10)
SET @RandomNo = ''

;WITH num as (
SELECT 0 AS [number]
Union 
select 1
Union 
select 2
Union 
select 3
Union 
select 4
Union 
select 5
Union 
select 6
Union 
select 7
Union 
select 8
Union 
select 9
)
SELECT Top 9 @RandomNo = COALESCE(@RandomNo + '', '') + cast(n.number AS varchar(1))
FROM numbers n
ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT cast(@RandomNo AS numeric(10,0))
```

## [See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13548)

OR something similar (courtesy of @manatwork) using recursion and xml.

```
with c as(select 0i union all select i+1from c where i<9)select i+0from c order by newid()for xml path('')
```

Comment: Man, you love CTEs… But as this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, better shorten it as much as possible. My best is 186 characters: `select i+0from(select 0i union
select 1union
select 2union
select 3union
select 4union
select 5union
select 6union
select 7union
select 8union
select 9)f order by newid()for xml path('')`. (BTW, great trick that `newid()`.)

Comment: Ok, you'r right. Is shorter with CTE. 106 characters: `with c as(select 0i union all select i+1from c where i<9)select i+0from c order by newid()for xml path('')`.

Comment: You can simplify the cte with `(VALUES (1),(2),...)`

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (<s>79</s> <s>78</s> 68 characters)

Rather than creating an array with the numbers 0-9 and sorting it, I decided to generate random numbers. When it came up with a number that was not already in the array then added it. This repeats ten times and then alerts the output.

`for(a="";!a[9];){~a.indexOf(b=~~(Math.random()*10))||(a+=b)}alert(a)`

Comment: You can save 1 byte using `||` short-circuit evaluation instead of `if` like:

`for(a="";!a[9];){b=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);~a.indexOf(b)||(a+=b)}alert(a)`

Comment: @StevenPalinkas Thanks, great idea! I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: We could also save 2 bytes with a bit of rearrangement in the code: `for(a="";!a[9];){~a.indexOf(b=Math.floor(Math.random()*10))||(a+=b)}alert(a)`

Comment: We can save an additional 8 bytes using the ["shorthand"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript) for Math.floor like: `for(a="";!a[9];){~a.indexOf(b=~~(Math.random()*10))||(a+=b)}alert(a)`

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 40

The number is created as a string so as to allow zero to be displayed as the first character, when needed.

```
""<>RandomSample["0"~CharacterRange~"9"]
```

**Output examples**

> "0568497231"
> "6813029574"

**Explanation**

`"0"~CharacterRange~"9"` is infix notation for `CharacterRange["0","9"]`.
Either of these returns the list, `{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}`.

`RandomSample[list]` by default returns a permutation of the list. (It can also be used for other kinds of sampling, when parameters are included.  E.g. `RandomSample[list, 4]` will return a Random sample of 4 characters, with no repeats.

Comment: But why to display 0 as the first character?

Comment: According to the OP, the program "must be able to generate all permutations of all allowable characters".

Comment: @Ankush That's infix notation, so "0" is not always the first char.

Comment: Ajasja is correct. The program  can generate any permutation. I added some remarks above to clarify this.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 145 bytes

### Ungolfed

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Enumerable.Range(0,10).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList().ForEach(Console.Write);
    }
}
```

### Golfed

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){Enumerable.Range(0,10).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList().ForEach(Console.Write);}}
```

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.Range(0,10)`, and you don't need the curly brackets in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, 82 characters

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Rob W](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13882/rob-w), code length is reduced to 90 characters.

**EDIT:** Thanks to [George Reith](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11182/george-reith), code length is reduced to 82 characters (using for loop).

Pretty straightforward way: pick random element of `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` array and append it to the output, then reduce array and replay.

*Old version (106 characters):*

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],l=11,t="";while(--l){r=Math.floor(Math.random()*l);t+=a[r];a.splice(r,1);}alert(t)
```

Readable version:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], l = 10,t = "";
while(l--) {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
  t += a[r];
  a.splice(r, 1);
}
alert(t);
```

*Better version (90 characters):*

```
a="0123456789".split(t=""),l=11;while(--l)t+=a[r=0|Math.random()*l],a.splice(r,1);alert(t)
```

*Last version (82 characters):*

```
a="0123456789".split(t='');for(l=11;--l;t+=a.splice(0|Math.random()*l,1));alert(t)
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gthacoder/qH3t9/.

Comment: I golfed down your method to 90 characters: `a='0123456789'.split(t=''),l=10;while(l--)t+=a[r=0|Math.random()*l],a.splice(r,1);alert(t)`. Big savers: `Math.random(x)` === `0|x`. Replace curly braces and semicolons with commas. Directly use the result of an assignment as a value, instead of using an intermediate variable. Finally, initialize the initial array using `.split(r='')`. This is shorter than creating an array using array literals and assigning the string value in a separate expression.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the tips. I updated my answer. P.S. I guess you meant `Math.floor(x) === 0|x`.

Comment: This always has 9 at the end. To fix, initialize `l=11` and switch your while loop condition to `while(--l)`

Comment: @Greg Good point. Thank you. I updated the answer.

Comment: I like how you took an in-place (fisher-yates) shuffle algorithm and made it shorter by creating a new string to hold the shuffled data.

Comment: 88 Characters: `a="0123456789".split(t="");for(l=11;--l;a.splice(r,1))t+=a[r=0|Math.random()*l];alert(t)`

Comment: 82 Characters: `a="0123456789".split(t='');for(l=11;--l;t+=a.splice(0|Math.random()*l,1));alert(t)` - Your code fits perfectly into a for loops initialisation, condition and expression arguments. The `r` variable is redundant.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Nice idea about for loop. Thank you. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 27

```
Row@RandomSample@Range[0,9]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice way to avoid strings!

Answer (score 4):

### Shell/Coreutils, 23

```
shuf -i0-9|paste -sd ''
```

Comment: If we don't need a trailing newline, you can shave this to 20 with `shuf -i0-9|tr -d \\n`

Comment: what about `shuf -zi0-9`

Comment: @marcosm: That gives you lines terminated with zeroes, which is slightly strange.

Answer (score 3):

### K/Kona (6)

```
-10?10
```

As with J, `?` is the deal operator; the `-` forces the values to not repeat.

Answer (score 3):

### Scala, 37

```
util.Random.shuffle(0 to 9).mkString
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (80 characters)

```
alert("0123456789".split("").sort(function(){return .5-Math.random()}).join(""))
```

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/3rmza/

Comment: Note this can be golfed further by using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) (which currently only works in FF, but is coming soon to interpreters everywhere): `alert("0123456789".split("").sort(n=>.5-Math.random()).join(""))`

Comment: `"0123456789".split("")` vs `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` saves one characters.

Comment: This doesn't really guarantee a random distribution. See http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/. Nevertheless, that was not stipulated in the rules so good abuse.

Comment: You don't need the space between `return` and `.5`

Comment: @Greg _Shhhh!_ Do you have any idea how many characters a **real** shuffling function takes? ;)

Comment: @Greg It is a random distribution (assuming Math.random is sufficiently random), it just isn't a uniform one.

Comment: The original blog post is gone, adding the internet archive for posterity: https://web.archive.org/web/20150212083701/http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 2):

### Forth, 72

```
needs random.fs : r ': '0 do i loop 9 for i 1+ random roll emit next ; r
```

Room still to golf, maybe, but Forth made this one hard.  I think.

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog,  177/302 characters

I'm a beginner on Prolog, so probably this is not the most condensed code.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
sort(N) :-
    N = [N0,N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9],
    domain([N0],1,9),
    domain([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9],0,9),
    all_different(N),
    labeling([],N).
```

Returns:

```
| ?- sort2(N).                                         
N = [1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] ? ;
N = [1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8] ? ;
N = [1,0,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9] ? ;
N = [1,0,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,7] ? ;
N = [1,0,2,3,4,5,6,9,7,8] ? 
yes
```

If you want it to return an integer:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
sort(M) :-
    N = [N0,N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9],
    domain([N0],1,9),
    domain([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9],0,9),
    all_different(N),
    labeling([],N),
    M is (N0*1000000000)+(N1*100000000)+(N2*10000000)+(N3*1000000)+
         (N4*100000)+(N5*10000)+(N6*1000)+(N7*100)+(N8*10)+N9.
```

Returns:

```
| ?- sort(N).
N = 1023456789 ? ;
N = 1023456798 ? ;
N = 1023456879 ? ;
N = 1023456897 ? ;
N = 1023456978 ? 
yes
```

Using instead:

```
labeling([down],N)
```

Gives the numbers in the opposite order:

```
| ?- sort(N).                                        
N = 9876543210 ? n
N = 9876543201 ? n
N = 9876543120 ? n
N = 9876543102 ? n
N = 9876543021 ? 
yes
```

Unlike some other codes posted, this returns all possibilities (with no repetitions).

Answer (score 2):

**Clojure, 42**

```
(println (apply str (shuffle (range 10))))
```

> 6209847315

Comment: The generated number should be shown on screen, not it's parts.

Answer (score 2):

## [q/kdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28programming_language_from_Kx_Systems%29) [6 chars]

```
-10?10
```

will generate 10 unique random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## [√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Valyrio) , 4 bytes

```
XrśO

X    › Push 10 to the stack
 r   › Push the range from [1...10]
  ś  › Shuffle the stack
   O › Output the whole stack separated by spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 83 characters

```
a=[];while(!a[9]){b=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);!a.includes(b)&&a.push(b)}alert(a)
```

While running until array has 10 elements.

Generating random number from 0 - 9 then check if array !includes this number and add it to the array.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 4 bytes

```
kdÞ℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwia2TDnuKEhSIsIiIsIiJd)

Explanation:

```
kd   # Digits `0123456789`
  Þ℅ # Random permutation
     # 's' flag - Print the sum of the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## F#,  <strike>71</strike> 63 characters

I'm new to F#, but here's what I've come up with:

```
{ 0..9 } 
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun _ -> System.Guid.NewGuid())
    |> Seq.iter (printf "%d")
```

compacted:

```
{0..9}|>Seq.sortBy(fun _->Guid.NewGuid())|>Seq.iter(printf"%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not much smaller than JMK's answer, but here's a slightly smaller C# solution (135):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P { 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        Console.Write(string.Join("", "0123456789".OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()))); 
    } 
}
```

Compacted (134):

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write(string.Join("", "0123456789".OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid())));}}
```

Alternate version (135):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P { 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        "0123456789".OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList().ForEach(Console.Write); 
    } 
}
```

Compacted:

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){"0123456789".OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList().ForEach(Console.Write);}}
```

They're equal in length, but it really just depends on whether you want to use Linq's ForEach function or String's Join function. I was able to remove 10 characters in length by spelling out the range "0123456789" in a string instead of using Enumerable.Range(0, 10).

Answer (score 1):

**LOGO**, 64 characters

```
make "d 1234567890
repeat 10 [
    make "n pick d
    show n
    make "d butmember n d
]
```

**pick** returns random item of the supplied list.
**butmember** returns list with all occurrences of the specified item removed.
*Note: Not all Logo implementations support `butmember` command.*

Answer (score 1):

## Racket <s>45</s> 43

```
(map print(shuffle'(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript (96)**

```
function x(){return s.search(r=0|Math.random()*10)<0?r:x()}for(i=0,s='';++i<=10;s+=x());alert(s)
```

*First attempt (109)*

```
s='';for(i=0;++i<=10;s+=(x=function(){return s.indexOf(r=(m=Math).floor(m.random()*10))<0?r:x()})())alert(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>153</s> <s>150</s> <s>143</s> <s>139</s> 130 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;v->{List l=new Stack();for(int i=0;i<=9;l.add(i+++""));Collections.shuffle(l);System.out.print("".join("",l));}
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@KritixiLithos*

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##XZDBTsMwDIbvewqrp5SybDtCKBeuMCENcUEcsjRl7tKkapyiaeqzF6/sAlYSK05@6/vd6EEvQ2d9Ux0nbLvQEzRck4nQyRsFHKsVvGquhxroYGF/Irs0IXlaGKdjhBeN/rwAQE@2r7WxsL1cAYaAFRjxfklDrrg28uYVSRMa2IKHEqZh@Xh@xkjgSm@/YUfaHEWu6tALbglYrhU@lHfKSV1VAouiyLI8V0/BOWsIg48yHlJdOytcrnanSLaVIZHsetaLLJNNQM/51rFsnBiEGbq0d8xwRZlRWzYidsSqr49Pnf@aYPdvluFMqCxQAG7cJYLNGghbG@/nT39ZN3wUxVUP4KURPjk3T@AS/xGdF9e3cZ7ROP0A)

```java
import java.util.*;                // Required import for List, Stack, Collections
v->{                               // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  List l=new Stack();              //  List
  for(int i=0;i<=9;                //  Loop from 0 to 9 (inclusive)
    l.add(i+++""));                //   Add these numbers to the List (as String)
  Collections.shuffle(l);          //  Randomly shuffle the List
  System.out.print("".join("",l));}//  Print the List content without delimiter
```

Comment: `String.join("",l)` is shorter than replacement. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LY4/T8MwEMX3fIpTJptQq8ymQ9SObBkRw2En9KqLHdmXVlWVj80cHGB5f6T3pB@NU0wCF7yimYXYPNnKMeYMbXdqT48KIAsKufUayYNT@vFGWYAPob9BmxLet660HWJSFATosLf0@rK3bNB7RU3T1LXW9hiZeycUQzb5PA8D94q17e5Z@tHEWcyUyl91UuzLXCIFVdfPXK7LCjDNn0zuHwZ@YUYsk7/5@wdmj76Iho0ZNlJbwlIt63eIO4fu3P8A "Java (OpenJDK 8) – TIO Nexus")

Comment: But in order for ^ to work, you need only int elements, so you can do `l.add(i+++"")` in the for-loop

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 50 bytes

```
S$="0123456789
@L
SWAP S$[RND(10)],S$[0]?S$GOSUB@L
```

Explained:

```
S$="0123456789" 'create string with digits 0-9
@LOOP 'label
SWAP S$[RND(10)],S$[0] 'swap a random character with the first character
PRINT S$ 'print the string
GOSUB @LOOP 'Loop. Using GOSUB without RETURN will eventually cause a stack overflow, ending the program.
```

Comment: what stops this having duplicate numbers?

Comment: Wow it seems like a lot of people made the same mistake. It should work correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, <strike>133 bytes</strike> <strike>144 bytes</strike> 97 bytes (listing)

I started this by trying to imagine how PHP's `str_shuffle()` would work in Sinclair [ZX81] BASIC, and ended here (new and improved version):

```
1 LET A$="0987654321"
2 LET R=INT (RND* LEN A$)+1
3 PRINT A$(R);
4 LET A$=A$( TO R-1)+A$(R+1 TO )
5 GOTO 2+((A$="")*4)
```

This solution is based on a post by XavSnap on the [Sinclair ZX World](http://sinclairzxworld.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2236) forums after I posted my solution below.

#### Initial entry (slower and bloated):

```
1 LET A$="0123456789"
2 LET B$=""
3 FOR I=0 TO 9
4 GOSUB 8
5 NEXT I
6 PRINT B$
7 STOP
8 LET A=1+INT (RND*10)
9 IF A$(A)=" " THEN GOTO 8
10 LET B$=B$+A$(A)
11 LET A$(A)=" "
12 RETURN
```

Some things to note

1. Sinclair ZX80 and ZX81 BASIC does not accept multi-statemented lines, like `10 PRINT "HELLO":GOTO 10`
2. The interpreter adds in white spaces before and after most commands, so this version of BASIC is one of the most difficult to golf
3. You can manipulate strings by position like a `char[]` in C, although strings are indexed from 1 and not 0
4. This new version will work on an unexpanded (1K/2K) machine for real
5. When I've worked it out, the byte count is the listing only, it's using more system RAM. As this is 8 bit tech, I'll also work out the actual byte count (listing + variable stack)

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 4 bytes

The language probably changed in between the exercise and my solution, so this is not really competing.

`žh.r`

[Try online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X4Ze0f//X/PydZMTkzNSAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
Aö¬q
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QfascQ==&input=)

---

### Explanation

`ö¬` generates a random permutation of the range `[0-10)` (with `A` being the Japt constant for `10`) and `q` joins it to string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 84 bytes

```
proc f a\ b {expr rand()>.5}
puts [join [lsort -command f {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0}] ""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFNITFGIUmhOrWioEihKDEvRUPTTs@0lqugtKRYITorPzNPITqnOL@oREE3OT83F6gAqKXaUMFIwVjBRMFUwUzBXMFCwVLBoDZWQUkp9v9/AA)

Comment: `[split 1234567890 ""]` renders the same byte extent as `{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0}`

Comment: Failed outgolf: [`puts [join [lsort -command {apply {a\ b {expr rand()>.5}}} {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0}] ""]`](https://tio.run/##DcgxDsIgAEDRq/ww2UGj1tq6eBFkwOrQBgoBmmgIZ6edXvLSaGr1a4rI2U0L0kQXEsfRWauXD1l7b/47L97k788Hwv6H5nnqSinkC1dabnTc6Rl4cC4KIVStGw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
@k{0..9}++;say keys%k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hu9pAT8@yVlvbujixUiE7tbJYNfv//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Perl's hash algorithm puts the hash keys into a a random order, so this should satisfy the requirements.

If it doesn't, here's the old method:

#### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
@a=0..9;print splice@a,rand@a,1while@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98h0dZAT8/SuqAoM69EobggJzM51SFRpygxLwVIGZZnZOYA@f///8svKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), 96 bytes

**Code:**

```
x=list(range 10)
c=1
z='' while c>0[ r=int(ps any) if r<c[ z+=str(x.pop(r)) ] c=count x ]print z
```

**Explanation:**

```
x = list(range 10)                 ; x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
c = 1
z = ''
while c > 0 [                      ; While !empty( x )
    r = int(ps any)                ;     r = random 10
    if r < c [                     ;     If Random # < count( x )
        z += str(x.pop(r))         ;         z.append( x[random] ), x.remove( x[random] )
    ]
    c = count x                    ; Keep track of leftover elements
]
print z                            ; Print Result
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ɳᒆʀ
```

Explanation:

```
ɳ           Push the string "0123456789" onto the stack
 ᒆ         Push an array containing all possible permutations (of "0123456789") onto the stack
  ʀ         Pick an element from the array uniformly at random
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5OaHk9pONfz/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>17 11</s> 12 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @Teal pelican suggesting a better way to generate the numbers 0-9. Thanks to @Not a Tree for pointing out the previous version only starts with a 9 or a 0.

```
<v?=9:l
{xn!
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36bM3tbSKoeruiJP8f9/AA)

Adds all the numbers to the stack and then randomly chooses between cycling the stack or outputting the number until the stack is the empty. Biased towards larger numbers first, but the random wasn't specified to be uniform.

An 11 byte version that doesn't work on TIO due to `{` erroring on an empty stack, but works on other platforms such as [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground).

```
{l:b=?.!
xn
```

Comment: If you change the 0-9 code you can reduce it a bit; [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36bM3tbSKoeruiLv/38A)

Comment: @Tealpelican Thanks!

Comment: I think for the 10 byte version you meant } not { as { will remove 5 from the output but } will remove 0 from the output so none would work. A note :- TIO errors on trying to move right or left on an empty stack because it tries to pop then push from an empty stack. The ><> esolang page doesn't express what should or should not happen in this instance but as the "official" interpreter was written in python with the pop instruction used in both move right and left then TIO is acting correctly.

Comment: This kind of question is why I wish we had single way angled mirrors in ><> something like this; ◣ where going up or right reverse the direction but down and right change it axis

Comment: Are you sure this can produce every permutation? It always seems to return a number starting with 0 or 9. I think you can fix it by adding `!` to the end of the second line, though.

Comment: Good point @Notatree! Fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 75 + 17 = 92 bytes

`+17` bytes for args `-g0i -w -mq -c20`

```
 8 ?]v~S
?/--^]~9
A\0)0/a
B\1)1/b
C\2)2/c
D\3)3/d
,L-v-^e
)\sf
`zzzzzzzzzz*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/X8FCwT62rC6Yy15fVzcuts6SyzHGQNNAP5HLKcZQ01A/ics5xkjTSD@ZyyXGWNNYP4VLx0e3TDculUszpjiNK6EKDrT@//@vW/5fN90g879uspHBf93cQgA) Try adding `-vv` to the args list to see the values on the queue as it runs, in the debug output.

Not the most straightforward solution... The strategy here is like this:

1. fill a queue with the numbers `0` through `9`
2. pop the head of the queue, call this `x`
3. generate a random number `0` to `3`

   - if `3`, print `x`
   - if not `3`, append `x` back onto the queue
4. jump to step 2 until all ten numbers have been printed

This strategy ensures that all permutations are possible, however the permutations are not evenly distributed. Also, it is theoretically possible to never finish printing.

This could potentially be slightly smaller if I generate a single random bit (`0` or `1`) instead of two (`0` to `3`), but it would have a more extreme effect on the distribution. My initial attempt, however, didn't actually save many bytes.

If there is interest, I will endeavor to explain further the actual implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 81 bytes

```cs
()=>string.Join("",Enumerable.Range(0,10).OrderBy(x=>new System.Random().Next()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09D4IwFEV3fsULU5tggzPCoNHB@BUdnGt5kCa0jW1RiOG3Y9GYON57T@4RbiaMxbF1Utdw6Z1HlUX/ie2kvmeRaLhzcLKmtly9IgDnuZcCHkaWsOdSEzq1AJtWi4XzNjwUUEE@EpoX38y2JnBxnKx1q9DyW4PszHWNJE3mKWVHW6Jd9qTLC43Pnz8QpVGEsgN2nlBKx0mTfWQro50JL1crPZIqrFM/RMP4Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org.), 20 bytes

```
shuf -i0-9|tr -d \\n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZbijNK0xR0Mw10LWtKihR0UxRiYvIgUlAVMJUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kDµr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS7NdDm0tWlKclFwMFYHJAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
kDµr  # Implicit input
kD    # Push the string "0123456789"
  µr  # Take a random permutation
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### SPSS (174 bytes)

Most of the commands in SPSS can be shortened to the first three letter. It is convenient for code golfing.

```
new fil.
inp pro.
loo i=0 to 9.
comp R=uni(1).
end cas.
end loo.
end fil.
end inp pro.
sor cas R.
fli i.
for var001 to var010 (f1).
wri /var001 to var010.
exe.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash (79 characters)

```
seq 0 9|awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print rand()"\t"$0}'|sort -nk1|cut -f2-|tr -d '\n'
```

Note that the lottery company should not run this more than once per second!

Edit: Oh rats, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/random-ticket-code-generator#17784) blows mine away.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 97 characters

C is unrepresented...time to fix that!

```
d[10],i;main(j){srand(&j);while(i++<10){doj=rand()%10;while(d[j]);d[j]=putchar(j+'0');}puts("");}
```

Slightly more legible:

```
d[10],i;
main(j){
  srand(&j);
  while(i++<10){
    do
      j=rand()%10;
    while(d[j]);
    d[j]=putchar(j+'0');
  }
  puts("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 5 bytes

```
10,mr
10,    e#Range 0..9 inclusive
   mr  e#Shuffle
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 24 Bytes

```
-join(0..9|sort{random})
```

Explanation:

```
-join( #Join an array of
0..9 #The numbers 0-9
|sort{random} #Sorted into a random order
)
```

running it 10 times results in:

```
9184702653
7813529406
0458237691
2158604793
5391782046
4673980251
4870532196
9412576380
4816275309
1098624537
4257910683
```

Answer (score 0):

### C 144 bytes

```
f(){srand(time(0));j,i,a[10];for(i=0;i<=9;i++){a[i]=i;}for(i=0;i<4;i++){j=rand()%9;a[j]=9-j;a[9-j]=9-a[j];}for(i=0;i<=9;i++)printf("%d",a[i]);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int j, i, a[10];

   for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
      a[i] = i;


   //jumble the array elements
   for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
   {
       j = rand() % 9;
       a[j] = 9 - j;
       a[9 - j] = 9 - a[j];
   }

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
       printf("%d ", a[i]);


}
```

### Usage

Every time this binary is executed, a new random array of numbers from 0 to 9 is printed.

### Explanation

- `srand` is used so that a new seed is produced everytime for `rand` function.
- Store the elements from 0 to 9 in an array.
- Jumble the array elements by generating four random values between 0-9. (I'm not sure if that step was so wise, can be done in a better way i guess.)
- Print the array elements

Answer (score 0):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 66 bytes

```
(print(join(list-rand(permutations(list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))""))
```

[Try it online!](http://webide.sharafi.me/?code=KAogICAgJSBHb2xmZWQ6CiAgICAocHJpbnQoam9pbihsaXN0LXJhbmQocGVybXV0YXRpb25zKGxpc3QgMCAxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDggOSkpKSIiKSkKCiAgICAlIEEgbmljZXIgZXhhbXBsZToKICAgIChpbXBvcnQgbGlzdHMpCgkodmFyIFNhbXBsZXMgKHBlcm11dGF0aW9ucyAoc2VxIDAgOSkpKQoJKGVhY2ggKHNlcSAwIDEwKSAjIDo6ICgocHJpbnQgKGpvaW4gKGxpc3QtcmFuZCBTYW1wbGVzKSAiIikpKSkKKQ==)

`permutations/1` generates all permutations of the given list. There will be no duplicates. We pick a random item from the generated permutations and print it.

The try it online link has a better example for printing out a number of unique entries.

This could be a little shorter if the `lists` module is imported, but importing it takes up more space than is saved by a `(seq 0 9)` call.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 77 bytes

```python
from random import*;x=range(10);shuffle(x);print ''.join([str(i) for i in x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcgxCoAwDADAr2QzFRSdiy8Rh6KtRjSRtEI/7lw7HVwJKjeo461C9yOaWpunGrvHcTA2Hm8Il8ds7KPECZqmP4UY55gUyUAQBQJiyIsp5WPpVrce/gc)

This creates the desired list using Python's `range`, then shuffles it using `random.shuffle`. `random.shuffle` just randomizes the list. Then it prints out each item in the list joined by `''`.

Comment: (space)`''.join([str(i) for i in x])` -> `\`x\`[1::3]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```
10 iota 10 sample [ pprint ] each
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqsUJSYl5Kfq1BQlFpSUllQlJlXomD939BAITO/JFEBSBcn5hbkpCpEKxRAJGMVUhOTM/7/BwA)

| Snippet | Comment | Data stack (top on right) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `10 iota` | A range of numbers from 0 inclusive to 10 exclusive | `{ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }` |
| `10 sample` | Take 10 random samples from a sequence without replacement | `{ 7 3 8 4 2 5 1 9 6 0 }` |
| `[ pprint ] each` | Prettyprint each element without a newline |  |

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 24 bytes

```
9[:,]y[0f?[fsprlr,]puy]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/98y2kontjLaIM0@Oq24oCinSCe2oLQytuD/fwA)

This adds the digits 0-9 onto the stack, then as long as the stack isn't empty, it picks a random number, rotates the stack entries that many times, then prints the top of the stack.

```
9[:,]                     - pushes 9, 8, 7, ... 0 onto the stack
     y[              y]p  - loops as long as the stack size>0
       0f?                - generate random number in 0-(stack-size) range
          [      ,]p      - loops for as many rotations as we want to do
           fsp            - flip the random digit to the top, save and delete
              rlr         - reverse the stack, load saved digit, reverse again
                    u     - print the random digit we picked
```

The number of rotations used really should be in the range `0-(stack-size-1)` but the possible extra rotation doesn't hurt anything and it saves a character to use the larger range.