# Remove repeated words from a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Remove all repeating words from an inputted sentence.

Input will be something like `cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake` and the output should be `cat dog bird Snake snake`. There will always be a single space separating words.

Output order must be the same as input. (Refer to the example)

You don't need to handle punctuation but capital letter handling is required.

Comment: I recommend waiting to accept an answer for at least a few days. A shorter solution may still come.

Comment: I expect similar solutions to [uniqchars](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59625/20260), except that this doesn't ban built-ins that remove duplicates.

Comment: Seeing the example, there is not special capital letter handling: `Snake` and `snake` are treated simply as different

Comment: @AlexA.: In fact, there already is one. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/remove-repeated-words-from-a-string/62108#62108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/blob/master/gs2.py), 3 bytes

```
,É-
```

Encoded in [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

STDIN is pushed at the start of the program. `,` splits it over spaces. `É` is `uniq`, which filters duplicates. `-` joins by spaces.

Answer (score 9):

### CJam, 7 chars

```
qS/_&S*
```

Can probably be much shorter... but whatever I've almost never used CJam. ^.^

`q` reads input, `S/` splits on spaces, `_&` duplicates and applies a setwise AND (therefore getting rid of duplicates), and `S*` re-joins on space.

[Online interpreter link](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qS%2F_%26S*&input=cat%20dog%20cat%20dog%20bird%20dog%20Snake%20snake%20Snake)

Comment: How can you even get much shorter than 7? lol

Comment: Some one just did.

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 34 bytes

```
import Data.List
unwords.nub.words
```

Usage example: `(unwords.nub.words) "cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake"` -> `"cat dog bird Snake snake"`.

Answer (score 8):

## APL, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
{1↓∊∪(∊∘' '⊂⊢)' ',⍵}
```

This creates an unnamed monadic function that accepts a string on the right and returns a string.

Explanation:

```
               ' ',⍵}    ⍝ Prepend a space to the input string
     (∊∘' '⊂⊢)          ⍝ Split the string on spaces using a fork
    ∪                    ⍝ Select the unique elements
{1↓∊                     ⍝ Join into a string and drop the leading space
```

[Try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B1%u2193%u220A%u222A%28%u220A%u2218%27%20%27%u2282%u22A2%29%27%20%27%2C%u2375%7D%27cat%20dog%20cat%20dog%20bird%20dog%20Snake%20snake%20Snake%27&run)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Comment: I love any answer that uses a non-esoteric, non-golf language.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, 21 chars

```
->s{s.split.uniq*' '}
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6) 33

(see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59716/21348))

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser (implementing Set, spread operator, template strings and arrow functions - I use Firefox).

Note: the conversion to Set drop all the duplicates *and* Set mantains the original ordering.

```js
f=s=>[...Set(s.split` `)].join` `

function test() { O.innerHTML=f(I.value) }

test()
```

```css
#I { width: 70% }
```

```html
<input id=I value="cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake"/><button onclick="test()">-></button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Wow wow wow... I am continually amazed by your ability to cut any solution I think up by 25% or more. +1

Comment: Looked at the problem and immediately thought of Sets... only to realize that you'd already done it =P very nice!

Comment: how can set maintain the original ordering?

Comment: @njzk2 ask the developers of the language. It *could* be: a set is internally an Array, and at each insertion there is a check to reject duplicates. It's an implementation detail anyway

Comment: @njzk2 while I don't know *how*, I know that this fact is specified by the language: *Set objects are collections of values, **you can iterate its elements in insertion order**. A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.* (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 6):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 12 bytes

TeaScript is JavaScript for golfing.

```
xs` `u()j` `
```

This is pretty short. It splits on each space, filters out duplicates, then rejoins.

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/?code=xs%60%20%60u()j%60%20%60&input=Cat%20cat%20cat)

Comment: Is it `tee-a script` or `tee script`?

Comment: @MathiasFoster it would be "tee-script"

Comment: Does TeaScript have letters reserved for variable names? Most of them appear to be shorthands for built-in properties.

Comment: @intrepidcoder yes all of these: `cdfghijklmnopstuvw` are reserved for variables, they are all pre-initialized to 0. `b` is also reserved for a variable name, it is pre-initialized to an empty string

Answer (score 5):

## PowerShell, 15 Bytes

```
$args|select -u
```

Whoa, an actual entry where PowerShell is somewhat competitive? That's unpossible!

Takes the string as input arguments, pipes to `Select-Object` with the `-Unique` flag. Spits out an array of strings, preserving order and capitalization as requested.

#### Usage:

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\remove-repeated-words-from-string.ps1 cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake
cat
dog
bird
Snake
snake
```

---

If this is too "cheaty" in assuming the input can be as command-line arguments, then go for the following, at **<s>24</s> 21 Bytes** <sub>(saved some bytes thanks to [blabb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41749/blabb))</sub>. Interestingly, using the unary operator in *this* direction happens to also work if the input string is demarcated with quotes *or* as individual arguments, since the default `-split` is by spaces. Bonus.

```
-split$args|select -u
```

Comment: Relying on the environment's behavior of spoon-feeding the code with readily split up input…?

Comment: @manatwork I've added a clarification if the first usage is considered too "cheaty" -- since it's not clear exactly how the input is specified, we'll leave it up to the OP.

Comment: And _now_ is clear how efficients are PowerShell's own features. That 24 really deserves an upvote.

Comment: @timmyD you can chop off 3 bytes to the uncheaty ?? version by using the unary split and no need for "" '' in the commandline args too 
:\>ls -l split.ps1 & type split.ps1 & echo.&powershell -nologo -f split.ps1 cat
dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0 21 2015-11-02 19:06 split.ps1
-split$args|select -u
cat
dog
bird
Snake
snake

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 29 bytes

```julia
s->join(unique(split(s))," ")
```

This creates an unnamed function that splits the string into a vector on spaces, keeps only the unique elements (preserving order), and joins the array back into a string with spaces.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 22 bytes

```r
cat(unique(scan(,"")))
```

This reads a string from STDIN and splits it into a vector on spaces using `scan(,"")`, selects only unique elements, then concatenates them into a string and prints it to STDOUT using `cat`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 22 bytes

```
 (\w+)\b(?<=\b\1\b.+)
```

Save the file with a trailing linefeed and run it with the `-s` flag.

This is fairly straight forward in that it matches a single word, and the lookbehind checks whether that same word has appeared in the string before. The trailing linefeed causes Retina to work in Replace mode with an empty replacement string, removing all matches.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>43</s> 39 bytes

```
StringRiffle@*Keys@*Counts@*StringSplit
```

Comment: Kudos for using `StringRiffle[]`.

Comment: could use `Keys@Counts` instead of `DeleteDuplicates`

Comment: @branislav Does `Keys@Counts` preserve order?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 `Counts[list]` gives an association whose keys are in the same order as they first occur as elements of list.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

Well this is why we're all waiting for Pyth5, could have been 5 bytes.

```
jdoxzN{cz
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jdoxzN%7Bcz&input=cat+dog+cat+dog+bird+dog+Snake+snake+Snake).

Comment: Why isn't Pyth5 valid? It appears to be [implemented](https://github.com/orlp/pyth5).

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't think it's finished. There hasn't been a versioned release yet.

Answer (score 3):

### C++11, 291 bytes

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;main(){string s;getline(cin,s);list<string>m;stringstream b(s);while(getline(b,s,' '))if(find(m.begin(),m.end(),s)==m.end())m.push_back(s);for(auto a:m)cout<<a<<' ';cout<<endl;}
```

I don't see a whole lot of C++ answers compared to golfing languages, so why not. Note that this uses C++11 features, and so if your compiler is <s>stuck in the dark ages</s> sufficiently old enough, you may need to pass a special compilation switch to make it use the C++11 standard. For `g++`, it's `-std=c++11` (only needed for versions < 5.2). [Try it online](http://ideone.com/LmEUp1)

Comment: If you compare the number of bytes with other languages, you will see why no one is using C++.

Comment: @CroCo If you realize the point of this site is to find the shortest solution in each language, you will see why I posted this answer.

Comment: sorry I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Why not use a `set`? It allows no duplicates by design. Just push into it.

Comment: @black A `set` is not guaranteed to have the items in the same order they were added.

Answer (score 3):

## K5, 9 bytes

```
" "/?" "\
```

FYI, this is a function.

### Explanation

```
     " "\    Split the input on spaces
    ?        Find all the unique elements
" "/         Join them back together
```

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab: 18 Bytes

```
unique(d,'stable')
```

where `d` is `d = {'cat','dog','cat','dog','bird','dog','Snake','snake','Snake'}`.

The result is `'cat'    'dog'    'bird'    'Snake'    'snake'`

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Submissions here need to either be full programs that read from STDIN and write to STDOUT, or functions which accept input and return output. As it stands, this is merely a snippet; it assumes the variable `d` is already assigned. You can rectify this by using a function handle: `@(d)unique(d,'stable')`, at the cost of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 55

```python
l=[]
for x in input().split():l+=[x][x in l:]
print(*l)
```

Yeesh, this is long. Unfortunately, Python's `set` doesn't keep the order of the elements, so we have to do the work ourselves. We iterate through the input words, keeping a list `l` of elements that aren't yet in `l`. Then, we print the contents of `l` space-separated.

A string version of `l` would not work if some words are substrings of other words.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 38 bytes

```
String.Join(" ",s.Split().Distinct());
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can assume input is already populated in `s`, I think you should get it as an argument.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please have a look [at our default answer formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422). Answers should either be full programs or functions. Unnamed functions (like lambda literals) are fine, but snippets which expect the code to already exist in some variable/on the stack etc. or require a REPL environment are generally disallowed unless the OP explicitly permits them.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6, 14 bytes

As a whole program the only way you would write it is 21 bytes long

```perl6
say $*IN.words.unique # 21 bytes
```

---

As a lambda expression the shortest is 14 bytes

```perl6
*.words.unique # 14 bytes
```

```perl6
say ( *.words.unique ).('cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake')

my &foo = *.words.unique;
say foo $*IN;
```

While the output is a List, if you put it in a stringifying context it will put a space between the elements. If it was a requirement to return a string you could just add a `~` to the front `~*.words.unique`.

---

If snippets were allowed, you could shorten it to 13 bytes by removing the `*`.

```perl6
$_ = 'cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake';

say .words.unique
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, <s>87</s> 80 bytes

*turns out the full program version is shorter*

```python
s=input().split(' ')
print(' '.join(e for i,e in enumerate(s)if e not in s[:i]))
```

Did it without regex, I am happy

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/mTZrPM)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 94 bytes

```lua
function c(a)l={}return a:gsub("%S+",function(b)if l[b]then return""else l[b]=true end end)end
```

Comment: An anonymous user suggested to replace `... return""else l[b]=true end end...` with `...return""end l[b]=""end...`.

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 25

```
BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "}!c[$0]++
```

#### Output:

```
$ printf "cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "}!c[$0]++'
cat dog bird Snake snake $ 
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>44</s> 47 bytes

```
(s:String)=>s.split(" ").distinct.mkString(" ")
```

**EDIT**: using `toSet` might not preserve order, so I'm now using distinct // that just cost me 3 bytes :(

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <strike>106</strike> <strike>102</strike> 100 bytes

```
function(s){o={};s.split(' ').map(function(w){o[w]=1});a=[];for(w in o)a.push(w);return a.join(' ')}
```

// way too long for JS :(

Comment: Try using JS (aka ECMAScript) 6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which should save 6 bytes. Also, I can already see porting this to CoffeeScript will save at least 30 bytes.

Comment: This answer is in native JavaScript (ECMA5), there is edc65's one for es6.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP <del>64</del> 59 bytes

```
function r($i){echo join(" ",array_unique(split(" ",$i)));}
```

Comment: `explode()` → `split()`, `implode()` → `join()`?

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestions. Seems `split` is being depricated though, but guess that does not matter for codegolving.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 91 bytes

```
func main(){d=[]foreach(w in input().split(' '))if(!(d.contains(w))){d.add(w)print(w+" ")}}
```

Run online and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=2878e3a892c3343d45498b864ea2fea9)

Answer (score 1):

## AppleScript, 162 bytes

Interestingly, this is almost identical to the non-repeating characters thing.

```
set x to(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned's words
set o to""
repeat with i in x
considering case
if not i is in o then set o to o&i&" "
end
end
o
```

I didn't actually know the considering keyword before this. *the more you know...*

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 6 bytes

```
blsq ) "cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake"wdNBwD
cat dog bird Snake snake
```

Rather simple: split words, nub (nub = remove duplicates), convert back to words.

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 21 characters

```
*\S=${$0;$0}@set{$0;}
```

(Very similar to the [unique character solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62096/4198), as there are no arrays in Gema, so allowing built-in unique functions not helps us much.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '*\S=${$0;$0}@set{$0;}' <<< 'cat dog cat dog bird dog Snake snake Snake'
cat dog bird Snake snake
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 37 Bytes

*Assuming `$s` is the input string.*

```
print_r(array_flip(explode(' ',$s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 24 bytes

Similar to Doorknob's answer, just a full program.

```
puts gets.split.uniq*' '

puts                     print
     gets.split          split input by space
               .uniq     make each element unique
                    *' ' join with spaces
```

Comment: If it's a full program then I guess it should have some output too...?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add `puts` *facepalm*

Answer (score -1):

## C#, 909 bytes

```cs
class Dictionary
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> InsertWordsIntoDictionary(string userInput)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> newWords = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;

        userInput = userInput.Insert(userInput.Length, " ");

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
        {
            char holder = userInput.ElementAt(i);
            if (holder.Equals(' '))
            {
                if (!newWords.ContainsValue(userInput.Substring(a, i - a)))
                {
                    string hello = userInput.Substring(a, i - a);
                    newWords.Add(b, hello);
                    a = i + 1;
                    b++;
                    hello = userInput;
                }
                a = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return newWords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PP&CG. This post is a [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), which means that you're supposed to solve the problem in as few bytes as possible. Take a look at the other answers here and you'll probably get the idea. Also you haven't told us what language youranswer is in (is it C#? Then [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) might prove useful), and there is no byte-count.

Comment: Wow, am such a noob! I see, thanks for your help! Yes it is C#

Comment: I added a header to your answer (it is good practice to do that yourself). The best way to respond to comments is by editing your answer. You really should make some attempt to actually golf your answer.