# Filter an array so that duplicate items are removed

Tags: code-golf, array

In the shortest amount of code in any programming language, filter out the duplicate items in an array of which the order is irrelevant.

Here are some test cases:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd'] => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

> I also should note that there currently aren't any open questions that meet these exact criteria.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59625/36398) (char input, no built-in allowed)

Comment: Preserving order of first (or last) appearance would be a different challenge that's perhaps more interesting (because Set builtins and sorting with duplicate merging won't work).  It might be good if one of the test-cases showed that you're definitely allowed to re-order the elements you do keep, like `[1, 2] => [2, 1]` being valid.  I'd also suggest tweaking the title to something that doesn't imply order preservation.  Perhaps involving the phrase "set of unique items"

Comment: Can answers assume that the list does not contain empty strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 1-byte built-ins

#### [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b)

```
Ù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Mz//6PVE9V1FCBEEpyVDGelqMcCAA)

Alternatively:

```
ê
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Kr//6PVE9V1FCBEEpyVDGelqMcCAA)

#### [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/)

```
∪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHqv9pj9omPOrte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fpmCoY6hjrGMChMY6RjpmOkYA)

#### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/wv/f//9Hqieo6ChAiCc5KhrNS1GMB)

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w)

```
U
```

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/)

```
u
```

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL)

```
u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v/T//2hDHQUjMDLWUYCwTWIB)

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/)

```
▀
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtIb//6MNFYyA0FgBRJvEAgA)

## [Seriously/Actually](https://github.com/mego/seriously)

```
╔
```

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/)

```
â
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///Ci//@jDRWMgNBYAUSbxAIA)

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth)

```
{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v/r/f0MdQx1jHRMgNNYx0jHTMQIA)

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk)

```
u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v/T////RhjpGQGisA6JNYgE)

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE)

```
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/v/b//2hDHQUjMDLWUYCwTWIB)

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas)

```
Ｄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v///Z4l//9HG@ooGIGRsY4ChG0SCwA)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal)

```
U
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJVIiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDIsIDMsIDEsIDIsIDRdIl0=)

Comment: And once again, the most boring answer gets voted to the top. But at least you took the time to compile a collection.

Comment: @wastl Boring answers getting voted to the top is another story, but at least [we have a consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11218/58563) about using a community answer to group all trivial solutions.

Comment: Ah, I can't see that it's a community wiki in the app, it just says "Edited by Arnauld"

Comment: It always bothered me that this is called **unique** elements. Shouldn't it be **distinct**? To me, the **unique** elements in ``1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4`` are ``3,4`` since they appear __exactly once__.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>15</s></sup> 3 bytes

Reduced to 3 bytes thanks to [a'_'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92069/a)!!!

```python
set
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5LCoMwEN3nFLNLAtlohIKQLnuC7tSF1UgFUcmMiyI5exo/lcIwvM885s0fek@jDp0pA1oKZJEQDAgmikRBuo9WcOCsUqeqNyJVvOI1V3Cs14WaC7U8Zv7s5hRjVjIXP61Pt9h84eWS3hId3Uc94E/IGu5ZNzkgZaEfYa@XM9gq4uTItmLokUQnSErJYHb9GBlfyYO5w4oeVldYY7DyXLLwBQ)

## Without set

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>35</s> \$\cdots\$<s>30</s></sup> 29 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [a'_'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92069/a)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [Jitse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87681/jitse)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to  [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!!!

```python
lambda l:list(dict(zip(l,l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LCoMwELznK/aWBHKpCgUhPfYLelMPUSMNpCrJemjFb0/jo1JYlpnZHXZ2fONz6NPQyTJY9apbBTa3xiNrTYPsY0ZmheWcB9QePUhghBUXAclWqYAdZ5U41HQlXMQtqqiAvdUnak7U0uj5GzeHGL2cuHhpfrhJ5xMtp@R6SeP0rqz/CVlDF9INDlBoMD1s8XICa0Q/ONQt297oGMb0BEZn@sjojAvIG8x@gdkVWkpfLZSHLw)

Comment: Or just... [3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzvzi15H9BUWZeiUaaRrShjoIRGBnrKEDYJrGamv8B "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @a'_' Brilliant - thanks! :-)

Comment: Very nice way of using `set` +1

Comment: Anyway, [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU5LCoMwEN3nFLNLAqHUDxSEdNkTdKcuokYqTVWSuJCQs9v4qRSG4X3mMW@c7Wvok6XlxaLEp2oEqMzJ7NoOGiR0PSh/ecvZELpYaawBDgSRPGIQb5Mw2HFaskNNVkJZuMICM9hXdaL6RA0OmT@7PsSQpUiHT@6pJ5lNuJjiW5QE9yGU@QlpjT1aa1q2Fd3qZQjWimbQVjZEdcaSllhKKYJRd31g2FkP/A7OeHA6l5yb0mO6fAE "Python 3 – Try It Online") without set.

Comment: @a'_' Sweet - thanks! :-)

Comment: `lambda l:dict(zip(l,l)).keys()` for 30 bytes

Comment: @Jitse Clever - thanks! :-)

Comment: ...without `set` save a byte: `lambda l:list(dict(zip(l,l)))` (of course `set` works in place of `list` too :p)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice one - thanks! Yeah staying away from `lambda l:{e for e in l}` too since it's not really *without set*! :p

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3 bytes

```python
set
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzvzi15H@Ogq1CtKGOoY6xjikYm@hYxHIVFGXmlWikaeRoav4HAA) It [also works on Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzvzi15H@Ogq1CtKGOoY6xjikYm@hYxHIVFGXmlWikaeRoav4HAA)

Or without `set`:

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>34</s> <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```python
lambda l:[*dict(zip(l,l))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKlorJTO5RKMqs0AjRydHUzP2f46CrUK0oY6hjrGOKRib6FjEchUUZeaVaKRpAJX8BwA) Thanks to Jonathan Alan and Surculose Sputum for helping me golf this one!

Comment: ...that non-set answer can be `lambda l:list({e:1for e in l})` saving four

Comment: The non-set answer can be `lambda l:[*dict(zip(l,l))]`, making use of splat operator to save 3 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```
->a{a&a}
```

or

```
->a{a|a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cusTpRLbH2f0lqcUmxgq1CNJeCQrShjoIRGBnrKEDYJrE6IAn1RHUdBQiRBGclw1kp6rFcsVxgo/RSE5MzFKoVahJrFAoU0vSSE3NyNBI1FWq5/gMA)

Set intersection (`&`) or set union (`|`), both of which remove duplicates. Shorter than the built-in `uniq` method.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>27</s> 15 bytes

```java
S->S.distinct()
```

Stream I/O.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVDLasMwELznK5ZcLBFnoY9TQwOh1zY9@Fh6WMtqkStLwVoHQsm3u@sHpWCKkIZlZndGW9OZtnX11RtPKcELufC9AnCBbftBxsJxKAFq0WHHzmPi1lKDxQhg1H9MoXfSeV3Jk5jYGThCgMe@2O4LrFxiFwwr3e8GxakrvShm4Tm6ChqJomSWC59v70B6ysE2sbrJb@Xc5QPejzYzkVGWj7ec0cxYZYs0o8nY9VrW1jAi/roUl8S2wdgxniQA@/Dnm4e2pUtCjlM4RXqzfoD1JqBZqqadiEajid6Lz3JhTxMR22Hos2xGaT3HvfY/)

**<s>27</s> 22 bytes:**

```java
java.util.HashSet::new
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

List input, Set output.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY9NT8MwDIbv@xXWLk21EomPU6cdEBcOYxx6RBzcNEBKl021OzSh/fbihLChTVFi2X6c93WLO7xqm8/RdEgET@j89wTAebb9GxoLq5ACtMLpgV2nK8tg1ClfOmJY5nPBDhN5iJGdgRV4WIwn7BHpQ0bL0tuvcR7A7VB3AiZ@t3ENrEVeVdw7//7yCpj/arMlVtfFjZzbIsS7qJYaGWZFvHWKJsUmuzAVReLUc91aw1rro8rZRoF6QLKwAHH8r3vf97gPiDqrkUaKdcyTv2pPbNd6M7Deyk7cefX37WxawnTmtTlW8uT2MP4A)

Comment: `java.util.HashSet::new` for the List input, Set output.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, of course. I always forget about `::`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 6 bytes

```
D`
G`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fJYHLPUHv//9ErkSuJCBOBuIUAA) Doesn't work on empty strings. Explanation:

```
D`
```

Replace all duplicates with empty strings.

```
G`.
```

Remove all empty strings.

Comment: Where do the rules state that your program is allowed to assume the input does not contain empty strings?

Comment: I'm not claiming it does, but as yet none of the test cases include empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 13 bytes

```javascript
a=>new Set(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i4vtVwhOLVEI1Hzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RppGtKGOERAag6EJFJrCIUwEIg9SaRirqWn9HwA)

Unfortunately `Set` must be used with `new`, otherwise the answer will be just 3 bytes: `Set`, as a function.

Comment: But you are returning a set, instead of an array.

Comment: @kanine the specification does not state we must return an array, it only specifies we'll be given one and must filter out duplicates.

Comment: @kanine Even so changing the set into an array costs only 5 bytes.

Comment: @JonathanAllan, but looking as the test cases, it demands for an array.

Comment: @kanine we do not define challenges by their test cases. We also prefer loose I/O rules on this site. Note that the OP has also specified the input as "an array of which the order is irrelevant" which I would imagine means I/O is less restrictive than a [list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/what-is-a-list) to the point of just meaning "container". If you think there is a point of contention here you should just ask OP to clarify in a comment under the question.

Comment: @JonathanAllan, good point

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, 182 Bytes

```
@Echo Off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In (%~1)do (
Set M=F
IF "!O!"=="" (Set O=%%A) Else (
For %%B in (!O!)do If %%A==%%B Set M=T
IF !M!==F Set O=!O!,%%A))
ECHO(!O!
```

[image: TIO not available.]

Builds a string starting with first element of the original string, compares each element of the new string against the next element of the original string, assigning and testing a troothy value before appending the next element to the new string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 5 bytes

```
Union
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PzQvMz/vf0BRZl6JgkN6dLWhjoIRGBnrKEDYJrWxXAh5pUQlHTBOgtLJUDpFqTb2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 18 bytes

Io doesn't allow assigning functions. It's terrible!

```
method(x,x unique)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/X6FgZasQ8z83tSQjP0WjQqdCoTQvs7A0VfN/hUZOZnGJhqGOkY6xjqGmpkJBUWZeSU7efwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｗ⁻θυ⊞υ⊟ιυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDNzOvtFijUEehVFNTIaC0OEOjVEchIL9AI1NT05oroCgzr0SjVNP6///oaPVEdR0FCJEEZyXDWSnqsbH/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works best on strings due to the way Charcoal prints numbers by default. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻θυ
```

Remove all occurrences of elements in the result from the input. While this temporary value is not empty...

```
⊞υ⊟ι
```

... push the last element of that value to the result.

```
υ
```

Print the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 41 bytes

Great thanks for the Haskell answer! (so that I can port it)

```erlang
u([H|T])->[H]++u([X||X<-T,X/=H]);u(I)->I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/W/VCPaoyYkVlPXLtojVlsbyI2oqYmw0Q3RidC39YjVtC7V8ARKeur9z03MzNOIBqnMzLcqL8osSdUAqjbUMdIx1DHWMYzV1NT7DwA)

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), <s>79</s> 72 bytes

It's a recursive definition of uniquifying. The premise is that Erlang doesn't have a set-conversion built-in.

```erlang
u([H|T])->case string:find(T,[H])of nomatch->[H];_->[]end++u(T);u(I)->I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYw9C8MgFAD3/oqMT6IB2y2BzMnuJlLEmPRB8wx@0KX/3drpuOHOx7elQ/jkIl653moBvXyVYWJ2Nvku5Yh0jDvSBorrxbCwdxROm91LzM2nZ4PxtPV9AcWmAmtr16GeFgn0f4Rh/ETMHtpb8juX/MGlYWyoPw)

## Explanation

````erlang
u([H|T])-> % Try to split the input into a head & tail.

case string:find(T,[H])of
           % Check whether H is a substring of T.
           % Strings are lists in Erlang, so it
           % doesn't raise a type error when applied on lists.

nomatch->[H];
           % If false, return head.
_->[]end   % Else, return empty list.
++u(T);    % Recurse down until ...

u(I)       % ... the operand is an empty list,
->I.       % where the operand is returned
```
````

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)=a:f[x|x<-b,x/=a]
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SpJ0zbRKi26oqbCRjdJp0LfNjGWK02hwrbif25iZp5tQVFmXolKWrShjpGOMRib6JjE/gcA)

This answer gives us the list with the first occurrence of every element.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)=[a|notElem a b]++f b
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SpJ0zY6sSYvv8Q1JzVXIVEhKVZbO00hiStNocK24n9uYmaebUFRZl6JSlq0oY6RjjEYm@iYxP4HAA)

This answer gives us the last occurrence of every element.

Comment: Does not `import Data.List;nub` do the same at 20 bytes?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Probably

Answer (score 2):

## [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer), 2 bytes

```
⠓⣻
```

Decompresses into this Wolfram Language function:

```
Union
```

Comment: Surprised that Sledgehammer doesn't have a 1-byte built-in...

Answer (score 2):

## perl -E, 23 bytes

```
@_{<>}=0;say for keys%_
```

Reads an array from `STDIN`, one element per line. Writes the unique elements to `STDOUT`, elements separated by two newlines.

(No TIO link, as it seems to not terminate the final line of the input with a newline, which leads to an incorrect output).

Comment: You can manually add an empty line at the end of input.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 6 bytes

```r
unique
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/NC@zsDT1f5pGsoahjpGOsY6JjiGQNNUx0tT8/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## perl -MList::Util=uniq -E, 17 bytes

```
say for uniq@ARGV
```

Accepts an array as arguments, prints the unique elements to `STDOUT`, one element per line.
[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhLb9IoTQvs9DBMcg97P///6n/k/8n/k/5nwQkk8HsJChO/JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0ABI@2QWl1hZhZZk5tiCDAEA)

Comment: If you take the input on STDIN, you can save 3 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhLb9IoTQvs9DB7f9/QwUjIDRWANEm//ILSjLz84r/6/qa6hkYGgBpn8ziEiur0JLMHFuQlv@6iQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 10 bytes

```
@Unique(i)
```

Takes input from multi-value field `i`. Screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Symja](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/), 16 bytes

```
DeleteDuplicates
```

[Try It Online!](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/input?i=m:=DeleteDuplicates;m(%7B1,1,1,1,2%7D))

Comment: Can't you just go with `DeleteDuplicates`?

Comment: @RGS I'm not sure about function rules with Symja. I'll probably ask a meta question about what I can and can't include.

Comment: [I'm pretty sure you can](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/input?i=m=DeleteDuplicates;m({1,1,1,1,2}))

Comment: @RGS I was more saying I don't know if I can say `DeleteDuplicates` without the function declaration `m:=`.

Comment: Assuming you saw the code I wrote in my link, having as answer the code `DeleteDuplicates` is, in my opinion, the same as [this R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201487/75323) or [this Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201454/75323) or [this Sledgehammer answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201475/75323) or [this Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201451/75323). When the function we want is a built-in, you can just use that. No need to rename it. Also similar to arrow functions (Java, JS, ...) or `lambda`s (Python)

Comment: We only need to include the renaming of the function when whatever we write afterwards is recursive. Either way, removing the `:` will save 1 byte.

Comment: @RGS I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 3 bytes

```clj
set
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2vzi15L8ml0ZBUWZeSU6egkaaQrShjoIRGBnrKEDYJrGaaGqUEpV0FCBEEpyVDGelKAF1/AcA)

Returns a set, or preserving order:

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 8 bytes

```clj
distinct
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2PyWzuCQzL7nkvyaXRkFRZl5JTp6CRppCtKGOghEYGesoQNgmsZpoapQSlXQUIEQSnJUMZ6UoAXX8BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## MOO, 36 bytes

```
return #372:remove_duplicates(@args)
```

Extremely implementation-specific. The shortest non-implementation-specific way of doing this is `return $list_utils:remove_duplicates(@args)` (43 bytes).

Unfortunately, functions aren't first-class objects in this language, so `#372:remove_duplicates` (22 bytes) is a syntax error and thus isn't valid.

The shortest way of doing this without using a builtin is `x={};for y in (args[1])x=setadd(x,y);endfor return x;` (53 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 24 bytes

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT v FROM t
```

Takes input as separate rows in a table *t* with varchar field *v*, which is permitted [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Without an `ORDER BY`, SQL returns the rows in a non-prescribed order.

Answer (score 1):

### [sh + POSIX utilities](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi/qERBt/T/f0MuIyA05gLRJlyJQJgExMlAnAIA), 7 bytes

```
sort -u
```

### sh + POSIX utilities, 9 bytes

```
sort|uniq
```

---

#### Notes

- The TIO uses `bash` because it doesn't provide plain `sh`, but it should work fine in any shell.
- I was flexible with the input (one entry of the array per line, no other markers) because `sh` doesn't have arrays. If you wanted to do it with, e.g., `bash` arrays, you could do this ([TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9FWw1DBCAiNFUC0iUIiECYBcTIQp2hyFRRl5pWkKairFsfkqSsoqVQnRjvE1iop1CgU5xeVKOiW/v8PAA)):

```
a=(1 2 2 3 1 2 4 a a b a c a d)
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" | sort -u
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome! You may want to add a [TIO link](https://tio.run) to your submission so that others can try it out, if possible. Also, in the first option, why don't you go with just `uniq`?

Comment: @RGS if uniq’s input isn’t sorted, it will only remove consecutive dupes. I was posting from mobile so no link :)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html#uniq-invocation Based on GNU uniq documentation, you could use uniq -d, but I'm not sure if that's available in POSIX uniq.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 69 bytes

```cpp
#import<set>
using s=std::set<int>;s f(int*a,int l){return s{a,a+l};}
```

This is what I like about C++: It has a lot of features.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBTsQgEIbvfYpJTAQUo0VPbbcvsu4BabuStNAA9WDTZ69T0E01Gidk8s8w3z8BNY53Z6XW9UoPo3Wh8m2os8lrcwZ/8KEpCuxU2oS69NBRFDeSY4aeza4NkzPgZ8nlbb@UC7oY1U9NC5W2PrhWDnWWbdOD1Ia@Wd2wbM4AY2tK5/LjCQ4w5xxEPI8ckn5ayv2cSHNEEg4pvVyUuqiGIBUxZY1HcAoWrvEBOcId3fZx8Pq9talg97vi@HBirPyNFl@02NNiT4tPOuKddTTCGgrYtrPY3iL@qLJTgKrCa0wESFr67Yo8G/LTTSU38YebepWOKvaf57J@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 86 bytes

```c
i,j;f(a,l)int*a;{for(i=l;i--;)for(j=l;j--;)i-j?a[i]-a[j]?:bcopy(a-~i,a+i,--l-i<<2):0;}
```

Hoping to roll the two loops together.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVDBboMwDL3zFRHVRDKSrc16auj6IYhDmsBmxAABnbYh9uvMIajdYadZVvycZz9bNuLFmHkGXqqCal4xqId7rcai6SgcKwVCKOaSEpPSJSDKk04hEzots9PhbJr2k2rxDVzHwIWoBCSJZIetmuYN1Ka62Jwk/WCheXh9DoKNzQuoc6KrvKYfjPTwlTcFoscVIUy3GQsCXIW8aajpewOWBWNA0Nyn7rpdmpEjGXecyMWfOPF4P6nfddLXRTrixD/nKzJXZCPsWtrwCCjO/XYOMqZuhLwR0hGecafCaYCDtgpDQvYY4pgttLO2w4KChneWhNyvD9kq3F6Gnobhf9TMqib/UpvmHw)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 87 bytes

```c
i,j;f(a,l)int*a;{for(i=j=l;i-=j--==l;j=j?:l)i-j?a[i]-a[j]?:bcopy(a-~i,a+i,--l-i<<2):0;}
```

Turns out longer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBToQwEIbvPEXDxtBKqyzuiYI8COHQLaDTIBBgjUrw1XGgZNeDJydN50v/mX8m1eJF62UBbmRFFa8ZNOO9klPV9hQSk9QSRGKESJBMYtIIK4RJVQa5UJnJ0@is2@6TKvENXPnAhagFxHHIokDOywEaXV@KksTDWED78PrsOIeirKApiarLhn4wMsBX2VZIjzshZkHOHAd3IW8KGvreQsGcySEY66Pq@2OWk4RMR07C7TxxYvk0y991oa3zlMeJvc5X0lcqPOza2vAX0Jzb7VZkTN6E8CaEq2CV9a9wGuCgQGKKyQmT77NNXqPrsaCi7l1BXG7Xh3w37i7jQF33P256dwv/cpuXHw)

Comment: I think you should return the resulting length, [like this 82-byter](https://tio.run/##fZDdToQwEEbv@xQNG0O7tLpUr7bgPgjholtAJ6lAgDUqwVfH4UfcC7Vp2pPmzNdprXyydhxBF8wIx6Hs9kb3RdUwiJ2WEjQ3CaRyb07Hs63qd2bkJwgTgJDSSYgixbWJXaRO7hgGmBKEmKOHcQeldZcsp1HbZVDdPj8SssvyAsqcGpeX7I3TFj7yqkC6WwkxOaScEGyEvhgo2WsFGSc9oTimQ9M0YZLSmPahoGqe94Iu/DDoa08tnm98QZflvJHdKPOxaivDxkIswnfgPWJpdELO9bWjvh3146jJmaX5@1AEtA4at2jORQoCPhvTqBt0CubdZNQTy7sgXa@pL13LPO//QPVXoF0D1W@Bw/gF). Otherwise we never know where the resulting array ends.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 7 bytes

```
members
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpSrFBQlFpSUllQlJlXomDNxVWtYKhgBITGYNpEoZbrf25qblJqUfF/vf8A)