# Implement String Projection

Tags: code-golf, string

Given two strings: a string `s` and an alphabet `a`, implement [string projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_operations#String_projection) in the **shortest code** possible.

String projection returns a string `o` that contains the characters in `s` that are in `a`. The order of the characters in `o` must match the order of characters in `s`. So if `s = "abcd"` and `a = "12da34"`, `o = "ad"`, since only `"ad"` is shared between `s` and `a`.

You will need to handle when `a` is empty (outputs empty string, since no character in `s` can match empty string).

### Test Cases

```
"string", "alphabet" => "output"
-------------------------------
"abcd", "12da34" => "ad"
"hello, world!", "aeiou" => "eoo"
"hello, world!", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" => "helloworld"
"Hello, World!", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" => "elloorld" (case sensitivity)
"Hello, World!", "abcdef" => "ed"
"Hello, World!", "!,. \n\t" => ", !" (newline, tab)
"172843905", "abc123" => "123"
"fizzbuzz", "" => ""
"fizzbuzz", "fizzbuzz" => "fizzbuzz"
"", "fizzbuzz" => ""
"fizzbuzz", "zzzzz" => "zzzz"
"", "" => "" (two empty strings)
```

### Winning Criteria

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: Surprised by how many golflangs have a builtin or two for this task

Comment: prolog builtin is  `intersection/3`

Answer (score 11):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 20 bytes

```
str::matches::<&[_]>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZLPTsIwHMcTj3uK33YgW1KH_DHiBC5evJvoAcjSdp2bjlXWTmSEJ_HCQd_Al9EH8SxbF2QBhF76a36f76e_Jn17T1Ihl98n134MYxzGpjXXNJ8nYGJEELUgjGGgQblMAxPqGQiMRtPDrbYBCMDAnmGhDSZgUcQRTHkSeXoOYxbyVLGM80Pw6gbmPwTh41M0jvnzJBEyfZm-zjJlKAIFXhXdKNH90aKcP1pTRg7BOrJhGA-lwhHoVb5x0ey0W5dn56W40WwpMi8qpB9mGUmzLAcVsr-_rgtufarw29x-X5YvBRXVlqgqGME8YhL83kcq_dPOp5CJ44yxpAETjtOtDdxRX7W-fq7WpnodC8ES6bKJblKbzCQTpmVTHkWMylXujtGu2--bFgJ_9RmhRv6DLGufuoyTTSKfl7g0wImAHhC7qHaL_0I7pLVSspm8lUkYP-QjqehCW6jXL5dq_wU)

This mixes up *three* I/O methods for strings: the first parameter is a plain string slice `&str`, the second is a slice of chars `&[char]`, and the output is an iterator yielding single-char string slices `impl Iterator<Item=&str>`.

[Doc for `str::matches`.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches) It can take several kinds of patterns (i.e. anything that implements `Pattern`) for non-overlapping substring search:

- single `char`: matches that char
- a `&str` or equivalent: matches that exact string
- a slice of chars `&[char]` or equivalent: matches any char out of the ones listed
- (and any 3rd party type that implements `Pattern`, e.g. `Regex`)

We use the third variety in this challenge, which is indicated by the `::<&[_]>` part. `_` is a kind of wildcard type, and it resolves to `char` by the compiler because `&[char]` is the only type matching `&[_]` that implements `Pattern`.

Answer (score 9):

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 20 bytes

```
s/(.)(?!.*␀.*\1)//sg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVHdbtMwFOa6T3EaodluU7dpi2CEbNoFEkMCJHaxiyZoaey0Lq6T2U67ZSuXPACPyIsUpxtlmnqHLyyf8/348/EiXaUm06K0PVUwvq2jQaijC6uFmlGdrq@2po8pwadt2nlBO3FA@n0z215RI0XGceD3AhKCyAHrySBpR8ggAnauizWgT8IYZwOe8VDYYhCBngTJA5udoB8I7u@B0WVqsznuTwa947NenKS9zUtMOl367uT0W9Ine7tztUqlYMC4FEthuXamujGlppTCYvY3CJVczewc2hGM9@pLXbgoqlpOuYYi/@diUAhml23osjWGX/ns/U2Jm7C@a48S4i7i15XQHCPNUyaF4ojQzJ0tP1fOJE/dMO6EKiv7ttRFxo2hxjKhNoQWCqOdwpfRyV0NR0fwhFJUlq61C4JRrJB7Qh0FYQt2L5FupFGEPDfSgwoJXfDg989fbu/Cx4svnx3e/JzIbzHe1WWqjbOeoK7sosSFXhTC5YkHiBCqeSmb4NoHQwgJN2TrpdOMeT54wZClo7HX8uZcysKHdaElazdIykVRHQSclOezuVh8l0tVlNfa2Gq1vrmtHfvDA/vyv9iHkLZPIVaxdVjwevhmPDoevHpUBMOR6@airqdVXTfNZ@X@3PKelU9ZdbMeKd4f) - ECMAScript 2018
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY7PTsJAEMY99ymGTZO2pC5d/kRlRTx4MB704MEDbZpCt1Bc2tI/oiW9@gA@oi@C0wBKCDf3sjPf7/tmJhGp7G2KTMDD89Mjh7q683Kv378rFolIuRLEqa6GA4tf33D8mbGGMEDFWCdpGOVA7IjwClQJA8iKcZaj3TXPmckMsawhDA90C4kBfVBdrgAOAn3PJLI6ohHNWKseTvPFJPaFO8/iCLSRRlVJNUfjsN2LAQ2@P78AFdVF@y2mqpHlUGJbhG475vBN1tKpoQ8btHlGmzYzWq1sutlP2W0X0d@qkeo6JjAT8FJeVRvijSc@MYGwtu91ukQhMyFlbMIqTqXfqIknwrg4CTAqguksnL/KRRQnyzTLi7fV@0eJ7vut@@Vf7lOkYVKwIztHxi7al93OldXbJVi7g2oQluW4KMtaPGp/a4UctYeusn47C/kB) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVfrdtpIEt7fPEVbs8dIILDByYwHWcnBWIk9g8GHyyYe4@gI0YKOhaTRZZwQ@@8@wD7iPsh6q1stIYSwM7Nn9QP6Ul9VdXV19dem59Xmpvn0wwxbxMHoqjPQmnqnf6bp497FSP9wcTY6R8elH4hj2tEMoxPP9HGzvnhTMl0nCJG5MHykeze3SEUD4fT@/m56FF1//fpxtPjxfiE@BQdiXRLf7tUrf6tXJg3p4CCYP0l5OUFBGXUVT9W9akNBAVlhPUSerdKWa4m6Jx3wZgXatSMl41kQzohLPcsO@cSZb44RF0axsdyWe1MiDliDZqhj33d9MevUEgeBMcfSN7DTapkggE5OEB@lTTaOnZmtIB@Hke@ghvK4pZL2TXeGJfSthOBjyrmWm@brH28VNkwsJLJQ63PMoTqXEilcRmK8V@POeXtwXJH4pIx4fBJ30UEykpGXJIlZod/GcgQmhJi9FhJ2rpCh01WWHktsGTNsk6V6qKCp69qIOL7hUHfplCOzPyP@m0rfODiCeBzroejUDAmdqGl/Cn2Inhf6M2JZkASQnjOdGdjYlUBOsmTfTkJquT4S@SgBdxREqtVkMgkuQW9UBBDuR62hpNPYDjCTCW7IraqWJ5MyoOlAtboNe9yFY86mkiTW/1iKU2JpEEdMfGKbbZ@8enioeHtqOSinqGzmCJckCCBN0UQIJoIgKfE6eJTj2FeqVU9@dSy/PpYeHjamHo6a8s8/yY3ma5iBfDcXoPHvolSp1k/evP0kyLG7xZYvnD8Mm8ziDSYh9ql1MKXA2aypTfhL94nnhg31ILNlnuzZ3GH75LDYyAffhcU50XKKfeRaa2MBtWZEoYt8laVgfFxBKdXpVVWbFgvqCW38H80H32E@lrRyktQ8c4zm91ET4uSqh5C6LvgZn8vh@HQ4uhiNR5qufRxpvTPtDD1sz417Q22ka5dXo2slSXaRmdw3W8jieWrms@9PrDS4J6G5AB1phTIgrcvzcou6@1Dg7/tu/7TdVUB0CoX1Tsmg2oBCGVS71znvD7QzBWW@LZSWR3W7/Q/xovVOtz0crm2hgwNkRkHoLlENGbbt3iO4iwxnhm4@3SKb3GGkdS7bQ9MnXpgx8XHLxEg/HY4/Fji2YQI7xtTGaBKhyZiZgfibeIaatRmZkxBNvmSMdAqMdC4GnfHlu66WmCowQhx0sERLVuY/TX4DbQ4UDNiVjG6S091pD7WuFodmd2TPcqizfrfbHuiQbv1e91rZgQq2UCPYkg1LBahf8qjxVa99qb3g4ZccKjkMz6N6OdRle9Q554fltN35daC9U4oi3bvqvA@QYYbPpMoyr3vcHV10L3qa8pxHTg7V6@vt8agP@3Q1Gg84dgsV5VDjzlVaBcajdztQ4zyq936gaWfXu2IGZM@I7LCVu/u1@NZPir1lG/SuYSTAZAK8U0h04mswpiyUoKCKjxXeZ7kLo06Iv4TApLJdqMpwHfo4AIfkmHgoSYm5@E1jI5YVYJh0o9DGzjxcKCjDZSp0fBpZCSeBipp4sfSIjUVOfIZXo4Hk100dirIoycivU4pAW66M9plh/s/NHUprKrbn48Jayn653OYq1aK16zBkhFg8pHV2fUFACLwoVNbkhYZkRYkUEwIGaAM5F@PdIo4cy4OOldrI85qVhGCOkiOxPHHKkrLJeijw5pCyGqGchaZMkHtkut5XkZvZEEr9A2Ylf1Yb8h1lWHlViT2q5uZzsbms3B1MUtk69iGjRSJnnWm1HM8NpOQAPxZqYZaA590CXzssK@hObSiFgvcLmhRMvFplrqEy4waJs8DA5BcYGAgI0l9XL7ykfiJQ/ehztbpt5DHmmbtjuY55TFwLBbPC/CBQ@g0uF7vWc8MFdc2wgCcgqnlXAFgmJRwiduU5J9bVMt5B@pCkiatkC9ZuoJ8D@t8LDHPA8GVgWjYzQL7CF7HFScv3cltd8eZCOuzIidLuXlo1uXq@25VmtVFwslN@StQtntf/hzZ4R5lYV@u9H50Xn/q4GIOt7HuzIsF76y1USCBopph6JKEWJFs6CLhMkZcK8iu@JtLaGkTTICRhBBXVX7@IWaFnK01rfWbdUNehfqIqkFnW3KjPmzqCtYJgfVlwP/fXjiqFpY/7Cs9FeHDsyI74Ibq/nyxsL2U9g0F/AJzhUrvsD64Lj2QM2WF8jyQ22Qv4mfSILxVYDL3ZWcFnVz369z//RS//ghTJXM5UNyInmYuZvbST48/eJaYahwwSPJ8v8Umc0MNvgeFAFCYTR2C132X3W0HYOMbPYvzvw4RZTPgCJj3syW26XkWh/GZULR9jjkiu@iTGUP3XyMfS@reILzA9G0OSkiFZ8Txwk5SJwV4/PgnG1JzB@oRGc2YcvRJKwgLDIZPRvevbsz06Y2DiRoUTAMXWfEE@39lLx/V@94Mw@uP@y9cVSJ/H0h/@J@mimT25jiYObEpJaPzUPH519PPha45oNI9g1CKr1TRarehgrpu2S0Kum5Va0Y@LCP8xKbkNnmo2i2Xt@L8) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVbdbqtGEO41T7GhVQwGO/5JenKMyZEqVWov2ou20mkVpwjDYm@8ZikLx7Fj97IP0EfsgzSd3QUb2/g4p1WRZVhm5ptvZ2ZnCJKkNQmCl89JHNA8xGg4ZoxnVyme4Kf2NEnutIDFPEPB1E@Rl9w/IBf9oH@1WMzG/fyX5fLnn6ZfLqbGC78y2qbx7qLd/KzdHHXNqys@eTEP9XQHVeCaieslVtdBnKywl6GEuuKJRYaXmFfFYxOeW31H2zEkQDDF/vxOIzEYpfDv4TRlqVHFnmPO/Qk2n3kWDgYBKKDhEBVvxaN8j@OQOijFWZ7GqOtskIDkyzjznwpM87mQVh3pP0oVJFe66Ww06TTElMzdjoMgiBSgUj@eYEOKYlvefHUbb1FzAL31MiNu@SYautv1GNYAm2RpSKIIghOROPSkg71tcruM3iU10bOG4IpYioziLQE6DiKWVQrFRSJkEHTnIjApeLS6zlaMKcdSh9@TB9dtjEYNsBYvLOvYbHPKTpLdahKFv9E2Mm1zn8RGyUnYJHR4vV43kwu3wRtbq72gf0c4J/EEjXQ@0iHqah9FlFXsm5aV2Ne39s2tuV7vidb9nv32jd3t3YAECiiYAuIXhtm02sO7d7/qtqJb7/nb@INPSagSTDIsco7AlQM123J7cNvmiap9UjgnlZQldkILwnTYqXfyPmWwuTifj3GKWLRzxoU3P88YSl1ZtUAf4gCgAjOxXCoOkWAiHv5H9/wV7pVmdKAp3Etior77PYgTA4ay1wwGstkMBjHz5iz05mhdL@Ali4oplPrcz7yIpDzzWEyXO@NC5NMiI7A2pP1lMEBRUdDBYZl@Qkj4gmTBFDDKMg58qP8GaQwQ7G7tqkOxvxUidBx08hpDY5s5FTSu0GDHQBz9Xh@Yo4gV4TpCe/oYN2H09Cnc5grtUqHVc5s7r0WbABo/QjtKsHMOLcSRn9NsgPYav/61SOkAlSc5or5oJLqQBVKhWNSOBdXjVN@tbhNUjNRGTFTDrt6h8yd55ux6sWh4KzEXpNIEZ5TE2FD8SGwrfcBYud2jNi1E9x3RhvVGVSiuqs@AJUujANpT2jKAUWA/ul17JkbCIVTpT8DcP9a7q@rNQCh02ziF7BnErpKB7CeMm2UBbmpRpCcYTA8wYDoNB83crlOruJgSihUxy5LUUEM2s5IsjAz7zMgABd389/D6OfiRLvDRo2UdO9mowXg6lruYq0mrnTqBpXJbDHdDfi8A5Xpq37NsKqj5EfQrJJBPBUBWUtnLFJWPkVCnNYbTqjIovggbo7ix125OG6YHhulrDbMDw@y84bYVVAyLHZ61rS/aIpfHcPXJhXI4URPa6VX1VLM8O5iTXooT6geqYm1IPZw8@LGD5IpSWZkI2oH4TjREgsomFQhQ6HSyWcjWh/7640/RDGsax3ZigpH5XNQJjLz9@lAZGomiiACUG/poFOuyJzDZ2WqCXdikVZv0dTZZ1SY7Y7MtgjIWQb3epiYLZaigAeyUN9ruvzh5HUfbvOj@OAiBjN7thX7/Wtf0KaaU2WjBUhpeCImPCctrBWCKo8mUPM7oPGbJbzDu8g@Lp@UKtL9R2u//k3ad5MJuo1EMEdT07pve7XX/beemsOj2@vA2IqvVOF@txMuD5fZZ0w@WVa2VuAoV/e9ATF3@0qKyoD1Zz/8A) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLdTtswGN11nsK1JtkumWn6M6AsQ2yrtkoFJMrGRRKktHGKmWNndgI0jNs9wB5xL9I5aTU21Lvlyt855/tyvp98WVwr2VvxLFe6AGZpXM3cG6PkIdC@hhCuzC6mBB@1aPsFbYce2d01i5UlAm/4yosaGaNZXMyvMbqibcuEEgehCadR@4iE0gLIVTmTGNK5ShgtuIKEahYnmJDAixyeAh10opaPDBoCHXPDwHQpi/h@pLXSGJ1wY7hcAGggIk7i602W0glOCOASGFbQUnIlsX1hHcsFw/19d7BPiPuEHOy5XnfwD/R64B70LPLQzuIc24IufIlJe4e@eXt0Bckj2WpoLG9jwROQMMEzXjBtbWngA01NLnhhTdX2hO1Zk5bf31rjUivbkiyzGdNApU@1jC2Winhh/M4hmKtSFr7npEqDtO5UB71o6ABbPvV9tLADW0s6DmDCsCFoUsF3HzwgjoZ2N@OPp2fno/fH05ELUNZAJ58nF@PJ@LRGTIN8OLs4nkxseN@EX0bn786mo8cgjRxj591dLzqoF17Zf9V2RDP4paGmSLi0nsCmZ0FALBMggnVgr8Q6DaW1KnwRdOqz2SLu1CqI6joNWQ1BrrksMGmQyvcON4CwNn/9@AmQC5hM/PpaaVJmucGBtW7KmR27C4xVhR1EbxSXuNEIFScGowDtiB0UIbv19ezc9cyItRCR9VmTFYxn8wS6AHrdJO71oQOvmRDKBXdKi6RVMzHjqtxK2FSWLq75zVeRSZV/06Yob@/ul5VVf1qrL/9LvY1puRSEMiws5@119/u9g85gk@F1exZNeVXNyqqqwWfhn7cDn4V/q6r620jgbw) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZHfbtowFMZ3zVMcvElOSgj/Om0tSyu0oo2ppRPt1EkhQ4Y4wZ1xUjspkNJe7gH2iHsR5gBlG@JuuUl8/DvfOfk@mQ7nS0nvUiYp4FsVCdwECQ6cta5btqTEL2HQJRaAdKte0cEqBwhTFK7mIiGztpSRtABfMKWYCAEppAkq/IKvZaRb81bd/gl@wrBYgO88Vdxq@ahV7nuk/PjKMA9K9ruT029eZb9wR9wTznzwKWcTllC5kc@3lLaKOUsM31yvaHMqwmQMRQcO96vdyEgvKdLJkEqIgj@qaiMbaNlqE0Kl3@UTZcUPylbp0Igt6dY981HLug3PpmQ0HozGRMIDLEYLGBE9alQAmI6pAO3Z9pNp4QAWDvRoSGfx8XHnQ/ey137fumpvmdku0/563e6etc@2xGSXuPhyft0573TbAC9BkQkFouAzlRwr0CFBwEkIRk/nqwt5wNpFKpL8n5@pCQamgPApmSuIhLkdFuIdA8J/HdA@PRZ68LyMLeh0lbQV5EvmbYYyH0LlKgt6nm7IHG3pdMw4Be6ENFF6lM4rK@p6nCaqqRWbmVNbpcjdcs1zHNQXqKlx7lZtu1z31vHAmqhqAKPcZIB80U9Xl107JlJRA7u4xEvYw6Z9GzFhoH4VmSswlkwbwC0Ev378BGStmkIqqCQJNQJXeeZqyHrSYKATGAyWqmLYpnFatA9e2Af9mlmpTMLlEpHhyEcWoFrdJ41DVEBjynlkwTSS3C/mN4SyKN17oVtpEI7Z7Xc@EVF8J1WS3k9n80zTH9f0zX/R@26Klg190U/0Xe1N/e1h46j6etNRqzd0NWBZNkyzLC/uHLffBbRz/JvK8meDoN8) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLfbpswFMZ7nadwLUtABzQknbY2Y20VtVonVZrUSb1I2ESDAXeOTW0TMhi73APsEfci2aHJ0j/q3XyBOOf7naPvHLuQFVU6p5yviApPrJXet33HPt7193b8vWng7O/rbGWdjFhqEzXpR56gWGOnMbmSFbIumdZMZAhyVkuSEJgguocTLzP4J/aksieKZnQZWZO@d3jqTaPYa4nt7L3y370//hJZjn8Zm1lONRQ5284XYhFzlqCEcjZnhiror6C/f1VwZjp07cnnVGQmB1/oYFt8rSSYEuX8hiok04cm2mp7RHc2B9EIkSwM4JuGeCznBeM0wSM0meWxmkQRMMPox7lUZ/Esb3TFwKNNvjpND8GxMgs1JEMh8oJ2nWFdJoUMJk3auheZkIqOY03xBpg/BS5LbhhnYqvrp/oVLJbTx4B4CpwtYRUzZsZxYUq1pZYv@fgUGxhfXOewBV3Es45uYRcq3NzO0ZGglX1/fy5JnR6pw/4ohcq4G5sjJhBhoiiN03R7591boHcWttZx7TSVgt5eLrVpoTgYPcTIExK6d6OAKY7@/PqNiD2WYkGV@Sy9j1pCd@UrWnCwZv@TzpWcr0U8ITzCjncrwQfewS7RLskcB7ftCsc3swS7CAeDJB4e4B7u3rN0USUVT3Y7JaZMli8KUErTLGe33/hcyOJOaVMuquX3GugPa/r6v@iXlF3XR1MxNaAFbwZvD4aH/debimAwhGzK6vqmrOsu@Szc/vfws/AxVXdng@C/) - .NET

This is a single regex substitution, to be applied once. Input is taken in the form of the two strings delimited by NUL (ASCII 0).

Above and below, `␀` represents what is actually a raw NUL character in the regex.

```
s/              # Begin substitution - match the following:
      (.)       # \1 = one character
      (?!       # Negative lookahead - match if the following can't match:
          .*    # Skip over as many characters as possible, minimum zero, to make
                # the following match:
          ␀     # Skip over the NUL delimiter
          .*    # Skip over as many characters as possible, minimum zero, to make
                # the following match:
          \1    # Match the character we captured in \1
      )
/               # Substitution - replace with the following:
                # Empty string
/               # Flags:
s               # single line - "." will match anything, including newline
g               # global - find and replace all matches, going from left to right
```

This automatically erases the NUL and everything following it, because NUL and all characters following it are themselves not followed by NUL, so the negative lookahead matches for each of them.

(More test harnesses to come.)

As far as ECMAScript goes, this requires ECMAScript 2018 (aka ES9) due to the use of the `s` flag.

In Ruby, the `m` flag is used, which is the Ruby equivalent of what is `s` in most other regex engines.

### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

```
sub{$_=join'␀',@_;s/(.)(?!.*␀.*\1)//sg;$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY7NTsJAFIVZ8xSXySRtyVAoP1EZCyxYGBe6cOECSFPoFAbbGeiPSEm3PoCP6IvgVFAJYeds5t77nXPuXbEo6OzTmEGcRHyWUCjqjRsJLubxobt/enw4VEM3cbvdYRquWEQh3AL27X2cTnfYsZeSC62kkYFD47puGnq/YlZLZnVsGfV6PKfYyffUl5EebjG3G/S2R9VvGTvgvo65sVtFXCSAxgLR/Ds7ABtUuDpMxw6pWcQy2Lrg0D@ZNxQxoAvYoWVQWaD/sECxwqIhzdhhV6V5bCY95ixjKUAbaSYOTG2iUTiuVhs/3z8AkWMCE3/yEfZrPX2AXWNCwCKgltI83yN3OvMQAWQ1PbfVRmW0YEEgCWxkFHiVgriMy/QiUFbmzxd8@RKEQq7WUZykr5u3babUdwf187/Ul0iFmDAW40Qx66p53W7dNDpHh9VsqanPs2yaZlkxPGt/6zI6a09VWfGOEvQF)

Takes the two strings as arguments.

Beaten by a **35 byte** solution based on an unposted solution by [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY3LToNAFIZd9ylOJ5MAyfRCL/EyUt2YGBca48JFqYSWoaVOGTpAayFsfQAf0RfBIaI2TXfO5sw533@JmOTDMo0Z3D093FPAvlXG6TTHjhWJiMad8Yv9iHNbLYV9czLpdOYUO0VJfSH11Q4HVpdejqiappFD4Os4MPJIBmECyA4RLWC1A8zBApUaJ1LHDmmZxDTYuuJwtXfvKmLABWCHNkBlgf7DuGKVRUOakWNXpXlsJjzmLGMRgjbW2pi3tYlGoa5WjZ/vH4BIncDCP/kY@62RLtmGyZjp19g1jAkBk4Bqp0VRInc68xABZPY8tz9ADbRgnAsCWyG516yIywKRHgXKyvz5Ili@8lUoorWMk3SzfdtlSn37rX7@l/oYaZI22KGdKGae9s4G/fPusHaYvb66@kGWTdMsq44H6@@/gQ7WfVVWvVqCvgA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

*-1 byte [thanks to Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250861/add-parentheses-to-polish-notation/250875#comment559054_250875)*

```
->s,a{(s+?␀+a).gsub /(.)(?!.*␀.*\1)/m,''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY3BUoMwFEW77lc8sgmUNC20jjoMduu40IULF8CCSqDUFGgC1sZx6wf4if4IBtpxnE53vkXm3XvPfRHNct@mfju@kSR@N6W9GNixRTPZLGFiUstcGHQ0oKPQsSYbgvFHK9i2yQUDvJZlgT1Q/tSD3SrnDLifsVoOAfIUlKH9qqmlx4rEU77jdS4Pxk7k@ygskKdxHkwpHbuRBxo69LSlAYywlgASfLh7fLinVSwkM3GAbW7jCFt9Wom8qIETBN@fX4BIT2asYCKumZkGUt8iMnCiyOp/6J8WxcvnBBFAjpvEszkaohXjvCSwKwVPjC6JWV42ZwNdZWm2ytcvfFOU1VbIunndve2Vpm8P9NO/6HOJQSiERVjrzLl0r@az6@nFseG4M@2muVLLRqnOPJG/@xCdyL@U6uaIoB8)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes

```
$args-join'␀'-creplace'(?s)(.)(?!.*␀.*\1)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY/RTsIwFIa55inKSeNWwhYGGDUL4cLEGK9NvAAuyuhYsbSj25iW7NYH8BF9kdmFRQ3hznPRnP//vz8nTVXJdJYwIWocT481pnqTeVvFpdNxvEizVNCIOe4sI65P3FnP73f8/iIgTl2F2EyHYaw0o1HiYoG4RJjLtMjJkcfWmA@XHts74Jy0IcdS85x5icryypaDENPpvZIHpvMHrXbeU6YkgjkWSwjRL4s8qSQrBZcMgb3z9fGJsNsWn1Vbw@4VjhGm9mrzBksCBKqqBrqK1jBAEIzWdDyBLjTfVQNUKi3WvSahjKviYmCrLN4kfPsqdlKle53lxaF8ezeWfjzRL/@iLyW9gY8WcpHbLLgZ3U7Gd8PrthGMxtaNuTGrwpjGPJM/exfO5F/KNNMi8A0)

Takes the two strings as arguments.

## JavaScript (ES9), 43 bytes

```
a=>a.join`␀`.replace(/(.)(?!.*␀.*\1)/sg,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pYzNUsIwFIVZ8xQhC9JADRRw/OkUt@pCFy5cUGYIbQrBmJQ0BQnD1gfwEX0RDMg4DMPOu7hzzznfuTO6oEWieW4upErZ1kbtMIu2NOpTMlNcjiojolkuaMK8lkewd1cjjQppxAFuFRMfIbwNNZuXXDMPaUZTwSVDmCTuNuxBGqazXXfNZV6a21yrhBUFKUzK5QYTJT20b/gi6q8tqNfBEaJKQ5aaG/c6lgiHwEZBWAWAZ8ATg/YwihBE@HxDgCaA4Pvzy@0meHx5fnK55nLCs5WXeXsjp7pwvweoKZpoiLCbcIO3kI6TFPoABp2UdnuwCqdMCOWDpdIire0SyrgqzwauyrLJlM/exLtU@VwXplwsP1bW0fe/9Ou/6HNJzScglrFxWXDVue51b9qXh0bQ6To349aOS2t35on8u6vwRB5TdjcHBP4A)

Takes a list containing the two strings.

## Java, 52 bytes

```
s->a->(s+"␀"+a).replaceAll("(?s)(.)(?!.*␀.*\\1)","")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZLPctMwEMYLxzzFRgOJ5Dqa_ClDwSSZHuhwAC45cKjLjOLIiYoiG0lOGlOuPAA3hksP8FDtkSdBjp3SMeGELtLq933r3ZW__7hgK3Z9800s00RbKCKaWSFpnKnIikRRL4C_oBc0IsmMgTdMKPjUAEizqRQRGMus21aJmMHSMTyxWqj52TkwPTdkKwU4rXK_KKlfj8ttNIIYhj8zG3eOb45MZ8Q6I2wO0QE6ZIRqnkoW8RMpMcJjQzAleNyk3gH1wrBHkI8QKb23D1vBNEkkZwryYcyk4QFMIqYU1yBUmlkYguLr3R2ebIzlSyoUCWC9EJID3srogpm3_NJismukLBSkS1AqlMOvheLYWUUMWFLJ1dwuMBl1odUCSaMF0ycWd8lw2EbtXaK7VNqlQiHCePw8dItenb0P0TnxSIjA88Hbj1Cw8xvnl7vhnAptLNY-oEc9RKjVTBnJLH9pIpZyUxRZ2dg_bP39tqpmEeOcVNNKXPdrLSzH7VC1SZAPrc6KQf_BqfuUjTF6bODXl68QuoMr3QfpQ0xZmsoNNqQ61F84RFdF08W7Fvu2n_uCUFVE1YGtgK0DXQGNCAk-u1X-Lte3D5qITaOZqwz1-jM2OEINtOBSJj6sEy1nzYIwLpJsL3BWHs8X4uKDXKok_eiGma3Wl5vcqV-V6nf_pd5Hmj6FULkmG6j3tH98NHjWfVI5ev2Bu41Fnk-zPC8ua-HduYFq4X1VXqxKgspR_QY)

### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 37 bytes

```
$_=join'',<>;s/(.)(?!.*␀.*\1)//sg;say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYrPzNPXV3Hxs66WF9DT1PDXlFPi0FPK8ZQU1@/ON26OLHy/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFBkUdPQUuzn/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Takes multiline input (terminated by EOF) using NUL as a delimiter between the two strings.

Beaten by a **19 byte** solution based on an unposted solution by [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPzouJlClOsbGrjbGlSFWXz/9/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFBkUdPQUuzn/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULDAA) (they should really post it), or 25 bytes to insert `chomp;` at the beginning if being picky about the output being followed by a NUL.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
f
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/t/@Hl@o@a1kT@/x8drZSYlJyipKOgZGiUkmhsohTLpROtlAFUmK@jUJ5flJOiCJJMTM3ML8UlBzQgNS09IzMrOyc3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKyCqLBA6IhnFINOCQVdfQUYvJiSiDShuZGFibGlgamUH2GRsYQibTMqqqk0qoqkDimCJwNlsEUQVZbBQIIhUBWLAA)**

This is exactly what Jelly's "filter-keep" dyadic atom does - takes a list on the left and a list on the right and keeps those in the left that appear in the right.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 16 bytes

```hs
filter.flip elem
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY6xTsMwFEX3fsWthVCiphFpioChTAwMbAwMhMFN7MbUiU3sEPDHExxaNSBVnbBk6fnce55cUrNlUvai0qqxuKOWxg/C2AlfZT0X0rIm5lJoMMmqvqKixmoC6NY@2gYx2lqKmhmcoaIaQRaYyIaY38KUqoPBbAaCc3/98IPsDvnGyALusQlDPPvVQEDoOi9IBJIsCpouSRjteem/qiJ0qpHFdChQJlR7KveLGN@U4nUrq1rpt8bY9r37@HSjdL@Tnv5DOlGYRjGyOrNjJblaXC/Tm4vLvZ8s0jHkwrl169yQHaeH@ZAep78dN5y/Agn946X/yrmkG9PPc62/AQ)

Takes arguments in reverse order.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/) `-m32`, <sup><s>54 53</s></sup> 45 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*
*-8 bytes thanks to [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)*

```c
f(*s,a){for(;*s;)write(1,s,!!index(a,*s++));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJLU8IwED6TX7HUcaYtgeHl@Kji1YN3D8IhpCmNlhSTFLBM/7p1C0gZRziZS77HfpvM7PI2T5ialWXk@oYybxOl2g18E3grLa1we9TQZlOqUKxdRn3TanleUJQXUvEkCwXcGxvKtBOPCJHKkjmTyl2mMvTIhjRQARmQBk@VsWCszrgF1LcGvgEIecw0@IyCLwxnCxFifQFWGGteJ/CwLd/As8OmPHQoOL1@yAZDBwq6N2KRJCmFVaqTsFlVMCHT7GwBthLRLJZv78lcpYsPbWy2XK0/86PU0y718i@pcxVN2oGxGtsDRoKsTvSu@zfDwW33at@v1x8cuZHM82mW55V5Qj7g2j4hH6fy6vyK/NBudRUBIQ1cF3Alzqkb7IcmJx2cbKslve3sFhqHHbnO2LlMzBibIMAb2iNESOvQEd6vAjze1RrzcDMakftnYGcuMmuql5yKFfg7LWymFf6NFOUXjxI2M2V7Puh/Aw)

#### Explanation

```c
f(*s,a){      // function f() takes a wide-character string (s) and an int (a)
 for(;*s;)    // while we're not at the end of the string
  write(1,s,N // write N bytes from s to stdout
   !!<expr>   // if <expr> is NULL, return 0, otherwise 1
    index(a,c // if the character `c` is found in `(const char *) a`,
              //   return a pointer to it's occurrence, otherwise `NULL`
     *s++     // return the current character and increment s
    )         // end call to index(3)
  );          // end call to write(2)
}             // end function f()
```

#### Caveat

There is undefined behavior in the form of an unsequenced modification and access to `s`, but clang happened to evaluate `s` (the second parameter to `write`) before incrementing it in the call to `index(3)` so in this case it works.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##rVJNU8IwFDyTX/Go40z6AfLlqFPk7MG7B8shtCmNlgSTFLBMfzu@UtSOM3Cyl@6@3X3JzCbuxTmTy8MhpZ4JmLtPlaahZ0J3q4XldBiYoNsVMuE7ygLP@L7rhtXhSsg4LxIOU2MTofrZjBAhLVkxIelGicQle9LBCYiQdGIljQVjdRFbwPlRwDMAYZwxDR5DVwWWG2te5/B4NO3h2WGLOHECcIajhI0nDlTBSch4nqsAtkrnSbd2MC5UcdGAq3i6zMTbe76Sav2hjS02291n2Uo9NamXf0ldcnSDPkQysi3P8G50Pxk/DG5PG4ajcUtNRVkuirKsxTPjH/wrnxm3U2X9/Yk0tAoJ6eB7ACqwkkEIAqZgRMlV2lQFN9/UO/IQfF@4x/LWGjtOqRM517mJcCcC/ENvhghpU7WY900LMxefQSelF8R1YU291alZhffT3BZa4u1IdfgC)

Comment: `sizeof a` needs to be 8, otherwise it would segfault if the string is on the stack, or any address that doesn't fit in an `int`

Comment: You can change it to `f(*s,*a)(...` if you really want to.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 15 bytes

```
\(s,a)s[s%in%a]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZM9TsMwAIUHNk7hBFWyJYNIU0QYygx7EQNhcBq7NaR2iZ2G-ABcgiUgMfc-nIb8CBwVRdB4sfyk931v8etbWr6z6Uem2XGwDaHCBKk7NeJiRO7b9PPghQs9kzeaBZDBKgtm8lpo6JJoHrsIg07kjWPiT1yE0BGYXgKXxO5hT3tJk0RikMs0iZ0dDKFcZpZCpRyGqQZStljyh8dkJeT6KVU62-TPhbHspt-0exVXreJ2qKKuNwIA50RRoKhQXPMN1wUa7uzwh0138AkIRagtCAOn2ihonnBBMdAk6t3nnY-DiX9xevZ7mzf2LbJ-9DEYNybKjNlB2PK-TRt_E36SPtKfhH03mPrYevP6p7wjBVDnEtDVWhdA6ZSLhULtdyzL9v4C)

Takes input and outputs through vectors of character codes (as in linked test suite) or vectors of characters.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
dᵗ∋ᵛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFiQ/3NVZ@3DrhP8pD7dOf9TR/XDr7P//o6OVEpOSU5R0FJQMjVISjU2UYnWilTJSc3LydRTK84tyUhRBcompmfmlOKSA2lPT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKqvA6j0g6sMpVI9dTlFHT4GLEyxnaG5kYWJsaWAK1WNoZAwWT8usqkoqraoCCWMIwNkgCQwBZJVVIABXphQbCwA)

Takes a list `[s, a]`, and [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) a list constituting the projection.

```
dᵗ      Deduplicate a,
  ∋ᵛ    then yield some c from a pair of elements [c, c] from s and a.
```

Deduplicating a is necessary in order to not generate multiple pairs from the same element of s.

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 4 bytes

Uses set difference (^) to compute the intersection: x∩y = x-(x-y)

```
^/^\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyNkUsOgjAUReddRXkjTYjKx/jbgDtwQkiKUEErVQTRDly75RMkkQIdNe0997y0dOvOXQchID7gD6YTIN7Rhx0Ypk8sG6a4dyEIOK/BMGCM6zjnCfM12UCCiGeqAlTFy7CKl4ME9BRG5wu7xvx2Tx5p9sxfbyFLpVimW/S+og9j6X5OMTYCHWsKUNNn2ImdtBNF8j2tGjRW5tq2NotlZSsu1K+MoKZoJISXCSGhoU8pqCb+RzdbZUvjHJX+UUJ0+UR53Ie3fcMedc0Xxxajww==)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>35</s> 28 bytes

```
lambda a,b:filter(b.count,a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZ7chJzk1ISFRJ1kqzSMnNKUos0kvSS80vzSnQSNSFKbioVFGXmlWhEa6VpKGWk5uTk65TnF-WkKOkoJaZm5pcqacZCVS5YAKEB)

Takes in either strings or lists of characters, outputs a list of characters.

---

-7 bytes from @dingledooper by using `filter` + `count` instead of list comprehension and `in`

Comment: [28 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZ7chJzk1ISFRJ1kqzSMnNKUos0kvSS80vzSnQSNSFKbioVFGXmlWhEa6VpKGWk5uTk65TnF-WkKOkoJaZm5pcqacZCVS5YAKEB)

Comment: Don't think it works, @dingledooper: [ATOL](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZJBToQwFIYTl57igRtI6kRgjKMJ-7mBGzYFylAtLdLHIFzFDYnRU3gST6NAZ4YYZ7Sbvpd-__fapC_vZYu5kv1rFkZvNWaXqw9BizilQEl8l3GBrHLiRaJqiYS6E_J5tqZaswohc2waJ6lNwPb8lAZL24UwBJum9vkByZkQikCjKpFaA0sZV7VBmVKn2W8_yzY5f3gUhVTlU6Wx3jbPbWcEY2Lk55715Ln_v2cIjBa4ACehmoFmUnPkW46t-7d6pzl9DYssIJIRGpqANc6TrBFcMgJI4_ks78ZfLYPbq2szx_MDkxyqGZjxrovrrhs4Qxw73tcTtm9n-C_YMVs3LMOM5Q_NLj68EhsFrCixBY0VlxttPlTfT_sX). Think that [list comprehension](https://tinyurl.com/24udkash) was right, tho.

Comment: After correcting the "filter-count" method to join the characters into a string, it comes out at [37 chars](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZJBTsMwEEUllpxiaoSUSKaiaREFqfvegE02TmK3Lq5d4knT5CpsIiG4E5wGnLglQrTgjWfk99_Ykp_fNhUujW5exCx-LVBcTd8vFVsnGYMdre4JGa6M1IGQCnkeVMPUFBrpLgw7-ONszqzlOYIICEvSjFAgoyhj4wkJYTYDwjJy_o0suVKGQmlylQ0cy7g0hUe5MafZLz8Xi6VcPaq1Npun3GKxLXdV7QVtouX7nnnnefi_xwVaC1xAkDLLwXJtJcqtxCr8W73XnL7GgA4h1jF6msKgnad5qaTmFJAl_Vmj22g6Gd9d3_g5o2jsk67qgULWdVLUteM8cez4UHfYoe3hv2DHbLVbnmnLH5p93L0SSwN8vcEKLOZSL6z_UE3T7Z8).

Comment: @dsillman2000 `filter` returns a generator, so it doesn't work unless you unpack it as a list, such as with `[*a]`. And [according to meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/88546), it's considered an accepted form of output.

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), 1 byte

```
∩
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8GCpaUlaboWtxhz0x61TXjUsZLrUd9UIEs9MSk5RT1N3dAoJdHYRB0mmpGak5Ovo1CeX5STogiUTkzNzC_FLQs0IzUtPSMzKzsnNy-_oLCouKS0rLyisgquxQOiJZxiLTilFXX0FNR1gJKhzsEKhgYKljCFhuZGFibGlgamEDMMjYzhZqRlVlUllVZVAWWwicGZMDlsYkjqq0AAWbE6JNShgQ-LBAA)

Answer (score 4):

## sh + coreutils, 6 bytes

```
tr -cd
```

Takes string `s` from `stdin`, alphabet `a` as an argument.

Comment: Incomplete code snippet. An actually useful function using `tr` is at least 14 bytes. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZJBTsQgGIUTl3OKf-gsOknH2HaMY9IDeAM3s6EtTNEKWujUwXgSN03UrQfyAl7DQk01cUrKBgLve-9BeHnVsmjfqL98eq8VXW0-VAWrLIdFlCTJIuw3P0--SFYImD3PKOC0Ow6jHMdrmDI8wHmHoYKUpQigEVWZzxEgTJiokQNDRAh0lOwaELor2M1tecfF_UMlVb1vHg8a_ZCWsHprcNUbXE83MIDFwc-wJCAJl0yxPVOH5bjj6G2M4_Eq8-AUtnyrRlAPAAXQCX1OmpJxEoDCqa0QXkSbdXx5dt4JTH4YxeOvaSsYhSEp0zqttTagC_kl_2HD2okNKoNPxFyp2gw36_WqIXFC0t_E_r-3bT9_Aw)

Comment: It is not a function, it's a shell command. Inputs are not given as function arguments, but as specified (`s` from `stdin`, `a` as a third argument).

Comment: @roblogic see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5415/73593

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
a@X^b
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhQFheYiIsIiIsIiIsIlwiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIVwiIFwiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXpcIiJd)

#### Explanation

```
    b  Second command-line argument
   ^   Split into characters
  X    Convert to regex that matches any of those characters
 @     Find all matches of the regex in
a      First command-line argument
```

By default, the list of matches is concatenated together and output.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 6 bytes

```
within
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldNNT4MwGAfwO5/iGSeWkEXYjG9xV/XixRgPzkOBMqrQIn02hIXPjh0VNEZe7InD8//xb5uGxEeR1Y8Pd/c3l0CkFL6ENKOIRZoxjiApSrgyjIMBah3AJJ4fmGA6bkCWKxMqGFkzuF6rVGC2QETjWNiQiywOZkoilIndAKQBKkS/oCrRcBux17c44SJ9zyTu9vlHUWpWC02qyXTQrYae/gcdQw0Dlk8kVUfEJUO2Z1jMh@X@XX7J/dVm9gI2fIN9hAZsULMWp3nMOLUBidc1cs7c89Xy4uRUt3Hc5fDlafA41gohK0tvV6qzMCfceyv8Ff/@rMbi3WjLTI2PtyiPa8zQ8WbyR4NJf/7VACzMBdAkxQIkqse1lXOjgmejzhlGjNcvEOoXuE5ICov6Ew)

Answer (score 3):

## [C#](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 33 bytes

```cs
(s,t)=>s.Where(c=>t.Contains(c));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVRbb9MwFH4mv8LNkyOFiLZDgLLmBQ0YYhLSkPpAeXCd09bg2q0v6xbU316Onayq0KSwSpyH@Dj5LlZ0PnP7kmsDB2@FWpLbB@tgXSanu@K9lhK4E1rZ4iMoMIL/hfgi1LZMuGTWkq9GLw1bk98JwbKOOcHJnRY1uWFCUesMEr//IMwsbdahQn3wil@2X3PyuF5fKb8Gw@YSLvmKmaoiCzIhB2pzl00qW0xXYIDySeXwmMqhg6U8y8rDN79BTqfTLhW6CrXxDhVaXwU78hSQpmzO6zQn6XBUs/FFmuU9@BVIqXOy00bWg0BkILQ/h4fGsFiuxM9fcq30Zmus83e7@4emX@xTKzb9n2JnEAd5QWZq5vqpwzejtxfjd69ed37D0biftBBNM/dNEzjPQx/7Xtbz0KceTah/M0izZF8mx4DA/QZTB3WYVvwbcRxB67DEqYkzE1/i5tjHZ04G7fCOo@7p4bt9PFXoCVomGB2rJRRTIxxgmKGLafFZY2TTmUJoTE5xC@EqoJZMqi6kIXecObqgtrjGy2CI6Y3NKAtVPiF@lhTitx4Uh6utZ5I@/h10eJHsk/3hDw)

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes

```
∊/⊣
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oiKL+KKowoiaGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISIgRiAiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoi)

```
 /      # Replicate elements of 
  ⊣     # left argument
        # by
∊       # 1 if each element of left argument is in right argument
        # 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 27 bytes

```
f(a,b)=[c|c<-a,[d==c|d<-b]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZFBTsMwEEXFTVyvYslBTVJEkRrWnKBduFY1sePWYBI3JJRavUk33SAOwU16msYJVEiFFV79-e_NZrz_sFDpxdIeDu9NrcLxpwqAZiRlYicmIVAm01Ts5CTMOO-N45UFa802ABTeI1vpom4j9gNGKpjmIgAWcUJRH2NOSDswhiETElOEo1hCMsKcMrzKjSkp2pSVkQPPINdl8wdq13O1XOnHJ_NclHZdvdTN6-Zt6zr_ofdn__R_ZwN6jebFvO5odBuPR8nd8OZrK4qTrlfauaxxztcXxTl7cFH8NJ1_Zw1zTvrDf3_RCQ)

Input and output lists of characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ã
```

Another 1-byte builtin. Takes the inputs in the order `alphabet,string`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPP//4ZGKYnGJlyJSckpAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGWSvpPCobZKCkn1lwv/Dzf91/kdHKyUmJaco6SgZGqUkGpsoxepEK2Wk5uTk6yiU5xflpCgCpRJTM/NLscsA9aampWdkZmXn5OblFxQWFZeUlpVXVFaBlXtAlIdTpByrlKKOnkJMXkwJWNLQ3MjCxNjSwBSix9DIGCyclllVlVRaVQUURefDmSBxdD6SuioQgClSio0FAA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
Φθ№ηι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMtM6cktUijUEfBOb8UyM/QUcjU1NS0/v8/IzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFkSsxNTO/9L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Trivial port of @dingledooper's golf to adam's Python answer.

```
 θ      First input
Φ       Filtered where
  №     Count of
    ι   Current character
   η    In second input
        Implicitly print
```

Newlines and other unprintables need to be entered using JSON format.

Comment: 30 bytes or 5 bytes?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Whoops, I'm trying to do this on a tablet and forgot to update from the verbose to the succinct byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
s=>a=>[...s].filter(c=>a.includes(c)).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pYy9bsIwFIV3nsJ4ILFCLQJU/YnM3HZohw4dIBImccCpawfbgWLE2gfoI/ZFqENRVSG23uHq3nO@c0q6oibTvLIXUuVs70gvKcjekBElozHG2KS44MIyHWZew1xmos6ZCTOEcKm4nE73iWbLmmsWBprRXHDJAoQzf1t2L32yoBkLt1xWtb2ttMqYMdjYnMsdwkqGwSHRFWS0daDTAX8QVVu81tz66okMUAIciZMWALwAoRj3UkICGCCwLcnD89Mjrqg2Hh0HkYiCtOHPdgkQAQi@Pj79jsAhaazmcs6LTViEpS9GfscpQijZ7dAe0lmWwy6AcT@ngyFswQUTQnXBWmmRtxuHMq7qs4aPsmK@4OWreJOqWmpj69X6feM8ffdDv/yLPue0uxhM5MR6L77qXw8HN73LYyLuD7xacOdmtXONePL@3i148v6lXDNHBH4D)

Unfortunately, using `.filter(a.includes)` for 38 (wow!) throws `String.prototype.includes called on null or undefined`

Comment: The output from that test harness is a bit hard to read, so for convenience: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pYy9bsIwFIV3nsJ4ILFCLQJU/YnM3HZohw4dIBImccCpawfbgWLE2gfoI/ZFqENRVSG23uHq3nO@c0q6oibTvLIXUuVs70gvKcjekBElozHG2KS44MIyHWZew1xmos6ZCTOEcKm4nE73iWbLmmsWBprRXHDJAoQzf1t2L32yoBkLt1xWtb2ttMqYMdjYnMsdwkqGwSHRFWS0daDTAX8QVVu81tz66okMUAIciZMWALwAoRj3UkICGCCwLcnD89Mjrqg2Hh0HkYiCtOHPdgkQAQi@Pj79jsAhaazmcs6LTViEpS9GfscpQijZ7dAe0lmWwy6AcT@ngyFswQUTQnXBWmmRtxuHMq7qs4aPsmK@4OWreJOqWmpj69X6feM8ffdDv/yLPue0uxhM5MR6L77qXw8HN73LYyLuD7xacOdmtXONePL@3i148v6lXDNHBH4D "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: And in any case, nice answer! I find it quite interesting how close in length it is to my regex one.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

Loosely inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59644/36398) to another challenge.

```
l~:A;{A&}/
```

Input is a line containing the two strings separated by a space. If a string contains special characters it needs to be defined explicitly as an array of chars.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P6fOytG62lGtVv//f6XEpOQUJQUlQ6OURGMTJQUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T@nzsrRutpRrVb/v59hbfp/pcSk5BQlBSVDo5REYxMlLqWM1JycfB2F8vyinBRFoERiamZ@qZICFgmgxtS09IzMrOyc3Lz8gsKi4pLSsvKKyiqgKR4QxeEUKMaUiFZXVNdR11NX8FO3jOVSMjQ3sjAxtjQwhWgxNDIGaknLrKpKKq2qAoqh8uBMLiVUHpKaKhCAKFACAA).

#### How it works

```
l~          e# Read line and evaluate: pushes the two strings onto the stack
  :A;       e# Copy the second string into variable A, then pop
     {  }/  e# For each character in the first string, do the following
            e# Implicitly push current character of the first string
      A     e# Push the second string
       &    e# Set intersection. This gives the current char or an empty string
            e# Implicitly display stack contents
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2 bytes (4 nibbles)

```
|@?@
```

```
|       # filter
 @      # the (second) input array
        # for truthy results of the function:
  ?     # index (or 0 if not found) 
   @    # in the (first) input array
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 22 bytes

```
{$^a.trans($^b=>""):c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYzRCoIwGEZf5e9HQmFIVnQR6HVv0EVoTN3Sms6mZrb27MvwOujqg3M4X8OU2NlqhCWH0GonoX6naN26TpKGEaK3z4xt6Qio/dMqNgSmDWIDYQSaw9s5GwQuFbhI0yxHAhisc7rZokcmVjAhJIFBKpEvvpKyUva/3HTA@KUorzdR1bK5q7brH8NzfM3BYQ6OfwX2Aw)

`trans` is Raku's beefed-up version of Perl 5's transliteration operator `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org), 29 bytes

```ruby
->s,a{s.gsub(/./){a[_1]&&_1}}
```

Previous version which had flaws indicated by [Deadcode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250781/implement-string-projection/251055#comment559347_251055):

```ruby
->s,a{s.tr(s.tr(a,""),"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY2xTsMwFEX3fsWrF7eqGzVpESDLzIgBBgaGNINLnNbFOKntUGrEygfwifxI6qQVQlU3LPnp3XvPtU292DUFa8Y3lvAPGzkz6AYnCA3b@9kYsamlEYDXttSYgmcTCtuVVAIUWwpnewCyAN8PflU7S4XOqWcxbV2VjuOMMTTXiAZcpZMoGicZhQAdesEKAEY4SAALDO4eH@6jihsrBjjFIzXCGR52aWWkdqAIgp@vb0CkI5dCC8OdGBSpDW8Rm8ZZNux@6EaD@OI5RwRQnOR8OkM9tBJKlQS2pVF5v024kGV9NghVUSxXcv2iXnVZbYx19dv2fecDfXugn/5Fn0v6JIK5nruQxZfJ1Wx6Pbk4NuJkGtxCer@ovW/NE/m799CJ/Ev59hwRtAc)

Comment: `tr` parses `a` like a regex character class; ranges (e.g. `a-z`) are parsed, and `^` at the beginning negates. So this answer is incorrect unless `a` can be quoted/escaped in such a way that no characters are treated specially.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Nice. This can be shortened further, to 25 bytes: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZAxTsMwGIXF2lP88eJWTdImLaIoCjNigIGBIYlQQpw0xSSpHVPqqisHYGWpEByCjWvAyElwkgqhqhseLL_3vvdb9vMrE9Fy85K4b6JKjMm7ccL1cMXNlIuoOzAHvVXoXVvBet3mnx-MzEXGCOAZL3LsgHSHDiymGSVA3ZRUvAOQJSA15Zei4g7JY0e6llO71DOswHWRnyNH4dQbmqZhBw4oqO0pSwEYYSUBOLhwdnlxbpYh46SLPdynfRzgXpOWLMsroDqC78cnQHpDpiQnLKxIN_G4mqVzzwqCXnNDs7Xv2HwdaCiMbmKkA7LsOByNUQdNCaWFDouC0Virk5BkhdgbqCpJ0mk2u6V3eVHOGa_E_eJhKRV92tJX_6L3JZpugp_7lcqsI3syHh0PD7cNyx4pN8mkjISUtbkjf88dtCP_UrJeWwS1X_UD "Ruby - Attempt This Online")

Comment: Also, 27 byte version that works on the older Ruby version on TIO: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY2xbsIwFEV3vuLhxSBMIIGqrax0rjq0Q4cOIZUS4oRQ1wl2XIqBlQ/oJ/ZHUiegqkJsfYP17r3nPksdb@rUr4d3ikRb5WRKx72RM@pvd/NdFMzD/b6WbKVzyQAvVSEwBeOPKawXOWfA/YxVqgOQp2C61i91pSgTCTW@SxuXB0M39H00E4hanAdjxxl6IQULHXvWsgBG2EoABT48PD89OmUkFevhAA/4AIe436alzEUFnCD4PnwBIi2ZMcFkVLFeGih7i6jADcN@@0P71CiK5wkigFwviSZT1EELxnlBYF1InnSbJGJ5oS8GtsrSbJEv3/i7KMqVVJX@WH9ujKXvj/TLv@hLyWuXODATs8qG7rV3M53cjq9OFdebWDfNjYm1MY15Jn/3DjqTfynTzAlBPw "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 20 bytes

```
a#b=filter(`elem`b)a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 70 bytes

```
|a:&str,b:&[u8]|a.bytes().filter(|d|b.contains(d)).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZLPTsJAEIcTj32KaQ9kN1kb-WPEghyNT6AHIGS33ZVq6Uq7FSnlMTx54aA3X0ifxrZLGhtEmMvOZL759vJ7e4-SWG0-RQgz6ocIr8TVR6LEaffrOqNOI1YRYU5jmHTHGbXZUvEYYVv4geIRyryM2a4MVX4ZIw_jfAgC7irH6d9ytz8ZDBDWtu-T155hCBkBooQRF4MfwtCAbSGLMtezCFjNlkfbHQsIgEU9C5NfzJQHgSSwkFHgmQVMuS8TzXIpD8H5D1zcT_2Hx2AWyqd5FKvkefGyTLWhPCjxuuhGi-6OFhX80ZrtySHYJDaMwpHSOAGzzjcvWt1O-_LsfCtuttqaLJoaKfw0ZUmaFqBG9u-rvuSqqcbvcvt9aVEaKrsdUV0whlW1p3HMIzXhcxO5VQz_SBsBkQcMGuw_CONeKV4ba53OzUa_Pw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 3 bytes

```
F¹F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiRsK5RiIsIiIsImhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCFcbmFlaW91Il0=)

Unfortuantely, the builtin doesn't work with duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```hs
s#a=[c|c<-s,elem c a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY6xTsMwEIZ3nuLqMiSSG5GkCJAoEwMDGwNDkuGauMTUsUN8IWDx7iERUQNS1YmbfP//fSeXaPdCqV5WtWkI7pEweJSWervETZJ/5bcry4USFeSAWV@h1LA5A6hbeqIGAmi1klpYOIcKa/BSz3LyYXUHUpNoclRIAtgYsImxpekgGTBul5T5kAznADyG27xgHFgYFRivmc@nvBz@Zzh0plHFYgRQSNOe6odDYvdSyte9qrSp3xpL7Xv38elm6eFHev4P6QSw4AGkOqUZCa@i63V8c3E5@WEUz@VOOrdtnRu74@nhfWiPp78dN85fgfnDkvXf)

Comment: you can save 2 bytes by doing `s#a` instead of `f s a`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY6xTsMwEIZ3nuLqMiSSG5GkCJAoEwMDGwNDkuGauMTUsUN8IWDx7iERUQNS1YmbfP//fSeXaPdCqV5WtWkI7pEweJSWervETZJ/5bcry4USFeSAWV@h1LA5A6hbeqIGAmi1klpYOIcKa/BSz3LyYXUHUpNoclRIAtgYsImxpekgGTBul5T5kAznADyG27xgHFgYFRivmc@nvBz@Zzh0plHFYgRQSNOe6odDYvdSyte9qrSp3xpL7Xv38elm6eFHev4P6QSw4AGkOqUZCa@i63V8c3E5@WEUz@VOOrdtnRu74@nhfWiPp78dN85fgfnDkvXf "Haskell – Try It Online") it's shorter yet to use `filter`, but an answer using that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 63 bytes

```
;=aP;=bP Wa;=c b;=dF;Wc;I?AcAa=dT0=cGc 1Lc;IdO+A Aa"\"0=aGa 1La
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv3eXwFzU4uQaFrOdLoT0bTH8SaZzKZONnbXMyspEQhCEhuKVPiwk0rsX3fvBfgAJUvOfkhCAQf3hXMfyB/sjqU8CZbZURT74oGHLE3Jv6NgNs9eJUmcEPEtE5GfEvlrVSjAB5akor2vnalQH/MoCxZP466zRLDFisdRmiU5z@LEZHSVzYPUTuM84cJlBewEy9t5kIl0ybgwy/0Fy/jcPP5kDkfj0XCUwnoxGPfW/xh@GkXjrjmK1s8o7R7TYinEF9hNRJYnEdGED/vj9TrKw7BQwjyLu326CkVGmOvZ4pvgpganTikCj7iuy87xY6BDXO3bTnMPbDcZqLFDEc2yObXYkI9pkcXgeBDNHrWqKGQ4yI07HDsqTP9lYS5WacaygJMl3oDp0ZVnb4XGmUIE71gC9vcddnpT6nVYr6f84u7NkI3tSoYTTE1OSxt4oflXJHkkQ53E9yQS94oFhS@8fPbI@g6PpBC72SyiRwHwp/Ae3YHVouTKO3AzYWFNJxWUDeqk@VIkJrWkiM8@yxgwSLmiCX/E3PJ3c65l61W@8ECuvqvZ@zKOQ8Gi1rb4GqI9JYKRAMxkERfxVLmn2X14qFkLtFJfldsovPa5jMEWFSrKNklx83pMhxdH/xt3j62Tmrns8BDvDGWaxo2B2mjh54tl7cykcuaZTLOCToowmzeuHDS2Hh4yeT8zfZ/o@wcKUNzYyzydmyiaOordr9xVUbL7rS@ibONan3JwyI7@/DzGv/tHLz6Dk5suSqFgVrGPIAGCgCDtCMijwTQAnAqCwmEowNxgFqGcV8NmZ1xzTJnZ2sMUu4sDn/QPMNqVlU6TQXqxNCe/R1@i@D4iQW0F6bTM6EyaiEpTaRVHLYo/SpSR39sOHQSuJDyjm/QoNxp2MN/Xbr8637CgxzC9aQHVcC/uqMQt8nAvrlvi/OBOdwjWMNKtIFeHf2PZ3AYORFyTcwy@7boE45JFUZwR0AExJ9538qdIYgOMi/0fVdpo@pk9qQjk5mGsKVrG9zsUNXLX6wOTnfbpD7nb7f6Av@LbMo6QdiwT0hKSxVC7IjEDFt0JAlaJBKwLd2T8qbybnQXhTG3X5G2oewUdZz93tVpak/eqLHBU8RaFtNK9ynbsZxs8NhBsUmNfnZbySlefCByPF2CmkEdso47A/3mqCgz@riIDfenJwCBLPJdp1d/ojCkMRunoetw9p6OTY@u5JBBGAjjk6ZQBDTgJqOmA2WpaQrDRwQbB1@uO0cEP2rjTTIFYsMCqRRABZ3zyNY@BOiLicY7Lwh@QZytWTFrdVBrezhHrpE/X6/5GsSmb8r5ig9ZPSkCpabuCIKjRZSdiKRg0B1lI9rJZm1z2kFpDVVcIC9SBQQzwzL/@HvEBK9xEfM2DRJjGNDWotcL5Um552hafB6H/eZnEXKSIev371eXN2/dX102/fA2Zva9daoxQlwljbS1m6GkdSd6qNvQ5GofOBzK7emubHit2CBxIccDEHz4MmP4prwZMvxowp660yK5MQWUH0x3U@S2AfhrNCEtm@QKHgGcrv3dSEFBCpugldD4PG54jVFintNCuFQNhcsuzxEabhyW@0epRnMvUd8QWwvXUN6hOXb49IsoDpm3bNaquIKooG6g9C@LINHq11Do8HqkGPXmU9VzDIkbPs5WMuuP2jK0a9N77Q/DMDlJJWQtGmGJaqiIf0Te6gpieYM@pnhUb07hpXIEtZJHDnOVBNn5jPAu/EyjthM9ZAr9gqAjjaAZFx2mYwcau16jCiNQdSL/TMqHg3WZ6GvWpXmCaOUfN8c6j929cxeQOJUMlzEMfbZUq/AMohmUiYZSp9dE0PhiWSd2z8hVjGJbnvsynU5HYLAxjbsKQ68cYGWb24f77MPVaQHAPXl/UA2u/OLwH/t1DfgnzBDqp3JEPIBsz6TaABDdGkUEpd7mdhgE8qPoWOWqm56qUcFpIkz4qk1p9dxrG4Nkvz1/88uLXfz5/8WtXriYs8uMFBkkefGVYzD3DyLBWBGGvc9HBvTqDVfhKAzy9PYHK88oiJcKeJvHiEm74Eh70cDnqKUIHlYH6ddm8xF1kOE1Js15Ks5j8vlTf5TNM/i3XJ3K97httBzadMf4j0WU1gwd1UFdd3D2oZckHiXotqK139RYariupOC9h/0IanNVjUitYldY08@M8s@8T6J4gSSUgvMSVz@/bEho9pRhjNJLPpJIQwIbzHYIrxgCEDh7FTLBBjaIJtepxRdrQAx5hXjfxxj5XuqMcPdqC4DzdgnS3INgIW5DjLYiconXIz9tS4g1bPm1B5LSqQ05rSH27FRa7bY2V4LPd4NkW@Hw3GMtoG3xYg01W5ZL8P4XzEjdQZF/vxLGBp5Hf0XBq2Wq57Wr7rVTFZ9p6DcK1p2k7WZhdvi09t9boKam3tdQVthdHpolDN@jeptRbdQbaIN6S7jHX/HmjoaTnjUmWp54dFhZD/LdKeVb9vxYeW68No/T9upTlS2kVepdU3/Vr6dp21dFwRD1nPZiaKm1Q02mP9xrtPR9bDhTMvzp6qSifkRAW8LLKQujBd8PnUO0fHh7mAtqFRe7jJPQPfmIiiPOfHhyXfXBc7wO5ZY7Liee4/mvnljtvzy/4BXP9m77L33By8g6W/Pe9C3LBjJHRd9kbBovsbw)

Comment: You didn't edit this into the list of answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
Cases[#|##&@@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZC7TsMwFEDn@CtcW8oUHkmKAIlWlioh2EBUYog8uInTGJK4@EHBffx6iKl4VMCEt3vO8R1uw0zFG2ZEzrpy1E2Y5jrDa4xDQjANOw1HEG@n8s4o0c631@3CmkupmhDcWsENuemxyfQRWWG8ORjrrMwmFVMsN1xpghO6N9KLMUKU9rvJCiA2ywsUBGuI4qRg6RBFAFW8rmUEl1LVxQB5x7iQ9g/VL@DlvBIPj3XTysWT0sY@L19ene@vdv39f/vf3SA6hCDwLj5Nzobp@fHJx584ST0vhXMz69w7/gE@h17sjvCd7KXOv68OgU33Bg)

Input and output two lists of characters `[alphabet][string]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart (2.18.4)](https://dart.dev/), 55 bytes

```dart
f(s,a)=>s.split('').where((e)=>!!a.contains(e)).join();
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes

```matlab
f=@(a,b)a(ismember(a,b))
```

Technically, only the call of `a(ismember(a,b))` is required to fulfill the task, but to make it a callable function a function handle is created. Also, the inputs have to be of type char, not string, as a char is an array whereas a string is more like a complete unit in MATLAB.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zdZBI1EnSTNRI7M4NzU3KbUIzNXk@v8fAA)

Comment: You don't need to count `f=` (an anonymous function is valid) or the final linefeed: https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSTNRI7M4NzU3KbUIzNX8n6ahnpiUnKKuo6BuaJSSaGyirvkfAA

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library/), 5 bytes

```
fl<fe
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TYyxDcMwDAR7T8EIadOniHfQChJEOkQoU5GladKoMTyTt4kAu_A3_38P_G97u-WDIm2_cUyaC9jhDN_qhIkxgM0oNeBaCz2eG40kLzrbbqPjGUYIOgCkDHcgMNhlwHjEYi7Y69TppF54vvKSOfZhSapijt_WDv8D)

Pretty straight forward.  `fl` filters `fe` checks if something is an element.  Ends up being the same as the vanilla Haskell answer.

### Reflection

This is a very simple task so there's not a lot to be said but:

- I'm not sure why `e` was given the shorter name than `fe`.  `fe` is almost certainly the more useful of the two and probably they should be swapped.
- Since this is such a simple task, hgl should probably follow the lead of the golfing langs and make this a builtin.
- There are a bunch of builtins that are similar to this task like `nx`, but the descriptions were not the clearest.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 48 bytes

```red
func[a b][foreach x a[if find/case b x[prin x]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZPBUoMwEEDv/YotJzrDqJQ6ah09e/bigXIIZFOiaVJJKJSfR0jQznRKW/eUyex7u5udFEjbd6RxMmHLlpUyiwmkScxUgSTLoQYScwaMS3qbEY2QQh1vCy6hTpKklWIJVKEGdyexElxiMpkw8EiaUQ@8cE5JtPBACjgbz/Dy2kHU69kchVABVKoQdNpJCHJVjjsci0qdhrtGkK1z/vklNlJtvwttyl1V7xtrdLCFLGIdb87x8S9Hz1gD@PatNErNDd9xs5@NS0fHGqSnG5oGN7CSKzNCOzaALtUfthKAIantI3yYPy6ip7t710M4j86ux7n6rB5mvGnSsunm9i4v9Rc@Jg/HcYMj/zJ7w5Xk@dpNHxdwR9rEoe419Y7qgm8qBbjZmj1o0/2PtZ61Pw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~`{1$?)\''if}+%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy6h2lDFXjNGXT0zrVZb9f9/pYzUnJx8hfL8opwUJQWlxNTM/FIlAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```scala
_.filter
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFEV3v@LZqU0MH0CiiXFxcWJwIMQ8oIXio8VSUTR8e23U7d5zknvHCgmDLTtZeTihNvBe1VJBHyNH14wp7J3DOc@806YpRPQTEqgUfgS2O8ikzw8tuuJb/jhcEqXJSxeGCDwZrjg7SiK7gbN1VK@Z4AzLKt41re6u1Bs73Nzo79PjOb9Y4m0cFmK1LOED)

This is an expression of type `String => Set[Char] => String`. It uses the fact that a `Set[T]` is a function `T => Boolean`, which is used the predicate here.

Answer (score 1):

## brev, 34 bytes

```
(as-list(c lset-intersection eq?))
```

Brev imports all of srfi-1 by default. The partial application combinator c applies eq? and then the as-list combinator makes the list operator work on (and return) strings (and other stuff) as if they were lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
fV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cQpWcQ&code=ZlY&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiLCAiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoiCi1Q)

Takes input strings as character arrays

3 bytes w/ strings for input:

```
oV1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=b1Yx&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiLCAiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoi)

```
oV1
o     : only keep characters in first input and
 V    : second input
  1   : case sensitive
```

Comment: Welcome to Japt :)

Comment: [You could do this in 2](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cQpWcQ&code=ZlY&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiLCAiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoiCi1Q) by taking input as arrays of characters.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, forgot you are allowed to do that lol. This is my first Japt answer I've posted, but I've been messing around with it for a week or two, since I mostly just write JS answers

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 104 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s,a string)(o string){for i:=range s{r:=s[i:i+1]
if Contains(a,r){o+=r}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVJLTsMwEJVY-hRuEFKimoo2RZRIYdMNS3Ys2go5H6emrR1sp6WJchI2FRKH4ChwGuw4ReJTgWVrJm_em5dk_PSc8d1rjuMFzlK4wpQBusq5UD2HrJTzUihyOnqb7zGpBGWZdAApWAyJKxGGFvNcvs8qwgWkQSgw0z1lJYJQTmhAu_0ZoASOOVPaR7oYCa_i3VDUNRCpKgSrrd_7ka-2eQrHpmMRK1gBjCK0NwA1sP7mdV1PV2MsUwmDEE5m4wpUDo7ixEFOf5Bgf6gTnDg10vg8XS45ghsulknH4CnlhY4p5wcIulFKsjm9XyxXjOcPQqpivXnclrrYkBuqFV9b8e2_xIb7l9TQDhA6qAenbKp0imDHcvoXg9HQvzw7tw36A7_5B76tElqWUVEab7O_Y7-lDedr7YeuNKuNn4KWaOakr8Idis1s7HWwo6oAD0Lixj2M4l7kgRs9V0Vc5-R4DdszZVCv8Aq6J2vPAvpTW4U-3DzwMNSRe9qqvTu7nY0f)

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX Shell + Utilities, 26 bytes

```sh
printf %s "$1"|tr -cd "$2"
```

Fundamentally, the operation is `tr -cd alphabet`, all of 11 bytes on the right side of the pipe; more than half of the space is spent on turning the specified calling convention into data in a file. Unclear if taking the input from the standard input stream is allowed.

The tr alphabet accepts `\n` and `\t` for line and tab, but the spec does comment that it means a literal one, I think? Either work, but.

Transcript of test cases:

````
$ cat c.sh; echo; wc -c c.sh
printf %s "$1"|tr -cd "$2"
26 c.sh
$ ./c.sh "abcd" "12da34"; echo
ad
$ ./c.sh "hello, world!" "aeiou"; echo
eoo
$ ./c.sh "hello, world!" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; echo
helloworld
$ ./c.sh "Hello, World!" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; echo
elloorld
$ ./c.sh "Hello, World!" "abcdef"; echo
ed
$ ./c.sh "Hello, World!" "!,.
        "; echo
, !
$ ./c.sh "172843905" "abc123"; echo
123
$ ./c.sh "fizzbuzz" ""; echo

$ ./c.sh "fizzbuzz" "fizzbuzz"; echo
fizzbuzz
$ ./c.sh "" "fizzbuzz"; echo

$ ./c.sh "fizzbuzz" "zzzzz"; echo
zzzz
$ ./c.sh "" ""
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ƈị
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU4NyVFMSVCQiU4QiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMmElMjIlMkMlMjJiJTIyJTJDJTIyYyUyMiUyQyUyMmQlMjIlMEElMjIxMmRhMzQlMjImZmxhZ3M9)

I/O as a list of characters.

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
 ị  # Keep only the characters of the first input
Ƈ   # which are contained in the second input
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 79 bytes

```rkt
(define(p s a)(apply string(for/list([c s]#:when(string-contains? a(~a c)))c)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU29CsIwGNz7FJ90@TIU0TEOrg6@QXE40q9pMKYliUoXX71GquBwcD/cXYS5Sl5qj2AproI76V0QnigRFGOa/EwpRxcs92Pcepcyt4bSpdbPQQKvWWPGkOFCOhL4BTJKqQ@WMsRR0DW@rKp/rqrqQOfCaKe/Dz9jr@mGbIblhIcQyJZWpg7zpoK48f4G)

---

### Explanation

We create a function called `p` that receives two inputs `s` and `a` which are the string to match and the string of what to match respectively. We loop through the characters of `s` and see whether each character appears in `a`. When a character does appear, we accumulate that character into a list. Once the list is obtained, we convert the characters to a single string.

```rkt
(define (projection s a)
  (apply string
    (for/list ([char s] #:when (string-contains? a (~a char)))
      char)))
```

---

### Conclusion

*Have an amazing weekend!*

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>5</sup> 4 bytes

```
e.#[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY27DoJAEEV7vmLQYmIiRB4@ILEyMRZWNhbGgsciKLqK4mN/HtdFIAaMsdhkds65d7aZJdvaeiDbFqLUUjGAsQ0IXeiBzZ@iwmQxn2ZEba@yjiQRL6SAjo@gcM1xPT4FgJruO4aJb0wozXlI4ph24UaT2JeF6JCIpoUnsIBfdX6ABJsw2u7i/YEeT8n5kl5v9wcrb/FI1TDLG5Z/NfzIFp6mG7moDfWRaVi9fiG9yFvKjSBizE0ZE0KBqmVNKT8fLY2IscYGJvb1OGZP)

*-1 byte thanks to seeing the word "filter" in [Jonathan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250785/15469)*

Filter by `#` element of `e.`.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

Presently invalid as does not handle alphabets containing `-` or `]`. (as pointed out by Deadcode)

```js
s=>a=>s.replace(RegExp(`[^${a}]`,'g'),'')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZPLbtQwFIYX7PIUZ6yRYqOQ6VyqFkYZVpVYsylSpyhu4lzAE4fYoUOiPAmbkaAPVZ4GX2aCVCpENj72-f7zn2PF339WImWHHxlED63KXl0-EhltaLSRYcNqThOG37P8al_j-ObjtKfDbRz4uU8C3ydO8OvFh7XnxR6id0mKAkDzRUqXKwTRBhBNkYcKxrkI4F40PJ0YgrJStA5gQjxL6Fosy4vy02e-q0T9pZGq_Xq__9Y5mRVYXKvfOfX1f6sN_2_tkXuWmAQhbLfVVjkogImm5heLy9Xy9dn5scZ8sXRpE3goK7vuru06k3XnTw7H2CbHnYf-Tj5RduZzGRs5yQmNQ9WUO0xCWfNSYX9b-STMRHNFkwIrJpXheg8gEZXe7KhKCojAZMYfYKanneUBOLFF8Azh8CUxTna1bjaaSbLW5coM8MSixJZ3BoKzkIscxxktOUtBCahpIxlMe-M4xFYL0DDVNpWJh7G1mwCknqXSjVBeFzQAtq9Zom51u9ZoPaINky3Xk0GGnYRgKyF_kJpKqYETGUXHaifi1Kltx8Jv9fzt4uLs3Ic3LlwlfgAWiNG0d06DuRL9Tozd4K5l2juXQUenSqZGDNh56ouY9i4cSDzEuqTudCBr98AOB7f-Bg)

Comment: This fails when given an `a` string containing `-` or `]`. There's a really neat way around this in Perl, but I don't there is in JavaScript.

Comment: @Deadcode, Thanks for pointing this out! I don't think there's an easy way around that. If I think of something I'll update the answer.

Comment: @MatthewJensen you could change `a` to `a.replace(/-|]|\\/g,"\\$&")` inside the template literal while you're trying to think of a better solution

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 2 bytes

```
IN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5BU8IwFITv/RWPdyoHHdviqMPAWS9eueAhpQ8IhKQ0CbVx/O01TRgdRpwxp83ufpuUthGkj5b6D5zNcTq9eaupf3ntPxeiR1auKgTM8ooVE4TZHJBVmOCWhFDQqkZUI58z4srGmJS6kvsZWm@2fLcXB6nqY6ONPbXvnYtQqIe2Z58Du/gvO7QDCemKaQJNUnPDT9x04z/GzuCVx0a3sJRLEwvgnVRSK7gkMKz0c9lD/jgpnu7u41aWF7E6iATX3LnSOv8xjPal9yOH7PuW4K/sknPDiUFQATgXITWtAjrUpgNtGi43evwF)

Builtin intersection.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` 24-bytes solution — it's not *all that* short but it gets the job done*

— **some bugs still exist*

```
echo 'abcd 12da34' |
```

> ```
> awk 'gsub("[^"$NF"]",_,$--NF)'
> ```

```
ad
```

```
echo 'hello, world!=naeiou' |
```

> ```
> awk 'gsub("[^"$NF"]",_,$--NF)' FS== | 
> awk NF=NF FS= OFS='\n' | awk '!__[$_]++' ORS=
> ```

- or

> ```
> awk 'gsub("[^"$!_ "]",_,$NF)
>      gsub("[^"$NF"]",_,$!_)($_=$NF)' FS==
> ```

```
eo
```

Comment: Which code block is your solution? Put that at the top so it's clear that it's your solution.

Comment: @bigyihsuan : i don't really have ***one*** solution just yet, since those approaches always had minor gaps in the set of test cases, and i'm still trying to come up with an `awk` solution that is all encompassing without using loops, which would be my last resort

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 38 bytes

```arturo
$[s,a]->join select split s'c[in? c a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?M0Gf0C)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 3 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
▽∊,
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa94oiKLAoKZiAiMTJkYTM0IiAiYWJjZCIKZiAiYWVpb3UiICJoZWxsbywgd29ybGQhIgpmICIiICJhYmMiCmYgImFiYyIgIiIKZiAiIiAiIg==)

```
▽∊,
  ,  # over
 ∊   # member
▽    # keep
```