# Partial Sum of Harmonic Sequence!

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Definition

> In Mathematics, **Harmonic Sequence** refers to a sequence where
>
> $$a_n = \frac 1 n$$
>
> i.e. the \$n_{th}\$ term of the sequence equals the reciprocal of \$n\$.

---

### Introduction

In this challenge, given a positive integer \$n\$ as input, output the Partial Sum of first \$n\$ terms of the Harmonic Sequence.

---

## Input

You'll be given a positive integer (within the range of numbers supported by your language). It can be either of Signed and Unsigned (depends on you), since the challenge requires only positive integers.

You can take the input in any way except assuming it to be present in a predefined variable. Reading from file, terminal, modal window (`prompt()` in JavaScript) etc. is allowed. Taking the input as function argument is allowed as well.

---

## Output

Your program should output the sum of the first \$n\$ terms of the Harmonic Sequence as a float (or integer if the output is evenly divisible by 1) with precision of 5 significant figures, where \$n\$ refers to the input. To convey the same in Mathematical jargon, you need to compute

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 i$$

where \$n\$ refers to the input.

You can output in any way except writing the output to a variable. Writing to screen, terminal, file, modal window (`alert()` in JavaScript) etc. is allowed. Outputting as function `return` value is allowed as well.

---

## Additional Rules

- The input number can be either of 0-indexed or 1-indexed. You must specify that in your post.
- You must not use a built-in to calculate the partial sum of the first \$n\$ elements. (Yeah, it's for you Mathematica!)
- You must not [abuse native number types to trivialize the problem](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245).
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

---

## Test Cases

The Test Cases assume the input to be 1-indexed

```
Input     Output
1         1
2         1.5
3         1.8333
4         2.0833
5         2.2833
```

---

## Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Could you give us some testcases?

Comment: What precision is required?  Exact output is generally only possible as a fraction, but in many languages that will have to be separate numbers for numerator and denominator. Can we output a)a float, b)a fraction or integer pair c)either?

Comment: @Arjun  The harmonic series grows to infinity so it will get hard to meet 10 decimal places as the number gets into the thousands and millions. I would go for significant figures rather than decimal places, and I see no need to be so precise. 5 significant figures should be enough. so `9.9999E10` rather than `99999999999.9999999999`

Comment: Can we go over 5 significant figures?

Comment: By the way, it's known that the harmonic sequence does not contain any integers other than the initial a_1 = 1. (Idea of proof that a_n is not an integer for n>1: let 2^k be the largest power of 2 not exceeding n; then 2^k divides the denominator of a_n.)

Comment: Is it fine if the output is a fraction instead of a float? Clojure's default type in division is a ratio, which is basically a fraction.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp No, sorry, that's not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
İ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IhkdNa4L///9vCgA)

1-indexed.

Explanation:

```
İ€S Main link, monadic
İ€         1 / each one of [1..n]
  S Sum of
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 27 bytes

```
h=lambda n:n and 1/n+h(n-1)
```

Comment: 0-indexing or 1-indexing?

Comment: Throws `RuntimeError` when handling input greater than the recursion limit, 1000 by default.

Comment: you can do `sys.setrecursionlimit(473755252663)` but the stack will eventually overflow quite easily

Comment: @Arjun it's 1-indexed

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @RickHitchcock*

```
f=a=>a&&1/a+f(--a)
```

This is 1-indexed.

```js
f=a=>a&&1/a+f(--a)

for(i=0;++i<10;)console.log(f(i))
```

Comment: From what I've seen of other posts, you can remove `f=` from your answer to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I cannot remove `f=` because the function is recursive and it references itself in `f(--a)`. But if this was not a recursive solution, I would have been able to do that

Comment: Ah, makes sense!  Save one byte with `f=a=>a&&1/a+f(--a)`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Nice one!

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 16 bytes

This solution is 1-indexed.

```
Sum[1./i,{i,#}]&
```

Comment: It is 1-indexing

Comment: > You must not use a built-in to calculate the partial sum of the first n elements. (Yeah, it's for you Mathematica!)

Comment: OP means I can't use      HarmonicNumber[#] &

Comment: @Jenny_mathy True.

Comment: Question only asked for 5 sig fig so you can shorten it to: `Sum[1./i,{i,#}]&`

Comment: And one can further shorten to `Tr[1./Range@#]&`.

Comment: @Ian Miller  If you see the edit you'll see that OP was asking for 10. Thanks for letting me know! and for -4 bytes

Comment: @Greg Martin nice approach!

Comment: @GregMartin come on, 1 more byte and this will be as short as the built-in :-)

Comment: @Ian Mathematica may *display* 5 sig fig, but the function *returns* machine-precision numbers (52 binary bits or just under 16 decimal digits of precision)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
+/÷∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR2wRt/cPbH3XMeNS7@f//R20TNdQd1XUedS3SUbdV13HUPLQCKGFoYAAA)

You can add `⎕PP←{number}` to the header to change the precision to `{number}`.

This is 1-indexed.

#### Explanation

```apl
+/÷∘⍳                     Right argument; n
    ⍳                     Range; 1 2 ... n
  ÷                       Reciprocal; 1/1 1/2 ... 1/n
+/                        Sum; 1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
n->sum(i=1,n,1./i)
```

1-indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1OwVfifp2tXXJqrkWlrqJOnY6inn6n5Py2/SCMPKGeoo2BooKNQUJSZVwIUUFLQtQMSaRp5mpqa/wE)

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
1.ri,:)f/:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31CvKFPHSjNN30r7/39TAA)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 33 Bytes

1-indexing

```
for(;$i++<$argn;)$s+=1/$i;echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zNbX@n5ZfpGGtkqmtbQMWstZUKda2NdRXybROTc7IVym2/v8fAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, <s>8</s> <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
õpJ
```

With some thanks to ETHproductions

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=9XBK&input=NQoteA==)

Comment: 0-indexing or 1-indexing?

Comment: I think you can save a byte with `õ x@1/X`

Comment: ...and another couple bytes by using `XpJ` instead of `1/X` :-)

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions :) I twigged those as soon as I walked away.

Comment: Actually I don't think you even need the `_` due to auto-functions. I should really write that tip :P (I should have time today or tomorrow, due to it being Memorial Day)

Comment: Nice one, @ETHproductions.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

*1 byte removed thanks to Erik the outgolfer*

```
ri),{W#+}*
```

This uses 1-based indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UqalTHa6sXav1/78pAA)

#### Explanation

```
ri            e# Read integer, n
  )           e# Increment by 1: gives n+1
   ,          e# Range: gives [0 1 2 ... n]
    {   }*    e# Fold this block over the array
     W#       e# Inverse of a number
       +      e# Add two numbers
```

Comment: You can use `W` instead of `-1`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer has outgolfed himself :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I like my name, it's just a name. And yes I outgolfed myself in the process of helping a fellow golfer golf even further.

Comment: @Erik It was meant as a joke. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
LzO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fp8r//39TAA)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 20 bytes

```
f 0=0
f n=1/n+f(n-1)
```

### Original solution, 22 bytes

```
f n=sum[1/k|k<-[1..n]]
```

These solutios assumes 1-indexed input.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 15 bytes

```r
sum(1/1:scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@19cmqthqG9oVZycmKehqfnf9D8A)

Answer (score 3):

### Tcl 38 bytes

```
proc h x {expr $x?1./($x)+\[h $x-1]:0}
```

That's a very dirty hack, and the recursive calls pass literal strings like "5-1-1-1..." until it evaluates to 0.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher for the formatting. With that, the duplication of backslash was no longer necessary.

Comment: No problem! It looks better

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
scL1S
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=scL1S&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

## Axiom, <s>45</s> 34 bytes

```
f(x:PI):Any==sum(1./n,n=1..x)::Any
```

1-Indexed; It has argument one positive integer(PI) and return "Any" that the sys convert 
(or not convert) to the type useful for next function arg (at last it seems so seeing 
below examples)

```
(25) -> [[i,f(i)] for i in 1..9]
   (25)
   [[1,1.0], [2,1.5], [3,1.8333333333 333333333], [4,2.0833333333 333333333],
    [5,2.2833333333 333333333], [6,2.45], [7,2.5928571428 571428572],
    [8,2.7178571428 571428572], [9,2.8289682539 682539683]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
(26) -> f(3000)
   (26)  8.5837498899 591871142
                                        Type: Union(Expression Float,...)
(27) -> f(300000)
   (27)  13.1887550852 056117
                                        Type: Union(Expression Float,...)
(29) -> f(45)^2
   (29)  19.3155689383 88117644
                                                   Type: Expression Float
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
:l_^s
```

This solution uses 1-based indexing.

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%3Al_%5Es&inputs=10&version=20.0.0)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input (N)
:   % Create an array from [1...N]
l_^ % Raise all elements to the -1 power (take the inverse of each)
s   % Sum all values in the array and implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
ṁ\ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxpiHOxb////fFAA)

Output is a fraction.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ɾĖ∑
```

Lame answer, but range -> reciprocal -> sum -> implicit out, same as jelly

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%C4%96%E2%88%91&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 2 bytes

```
ɾĖ
```

2 Bytes w/ -s from @lyxal, -s sums the stack

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C9%BE%C4%96&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Comment: [2 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C9%BE%C4%96&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 54 bytes

```
i;float f(n){float s;for(i=n+1;--i;s+=1./i);return s;}
```

Uses 1-indexed numbers.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 21 bytes

```
f n=sum$map(1/)[1..n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
⟦₁/₁ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rJHTY36QPxw6wTt//9N/0cBAA)

This is 1-indexed.

#### Explanation

```
⟦₁         Range [1, …, Input]
    ᵐ      Map:
  /₁         Inverse
     +     Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 13 bytes

```
[:|c=c+1/a]?c
```

Explanation

```
[ |        FOR a = 1 to
 :            the input n
   c=c+    Add to c (starts off as 0)
   1/a     the reciprocal of the loop iterator
]          NEXT
?c         PRINT c
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 8 bytes

```
F1LP,+|B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvhv6Oju6Wrt7vffzdAnQEe7xun/f0MuIy5jLhMuUy5DAyAyAAA)

#### Example full program & How it works

```
1AGIE;GN
F1LP,+|B

1AGIE;GN
1AG       Register row 1 as function G
   IE;    Take input as int, halt if EOF
      GN  Call G and print the result as number
          Repeat indefinitely

F1LP,+|B
F     |   Repeat n times...
 1LP,       Compute 1 / (loop counter + 1)
     +      Add
       B  Return
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```rust
|n|(1..=n).map(|n|1./n as f64).sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcmxDkVAEEDR3lcM1UzCyHqPgvAvW5hkEzsRuyp8@6JW3nO3PcQkCt46RYIDljmC9KLofg1Vk3T/MZ16omEeldjbFZ80XCvYAM8mDrtHSkO2bk7jojkWx1WUgoboi@2LV7oB)

Input is an integer, if the input is <=0 the output is zero, and inputting one gets one.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 9 bytes

```
1#.1%1+i.
```

I'm only posting this because I think it looks really pretty.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmux0lBZz1DVUDtTD8LfpMmVmpyRr5CmZqdgZ6WQqadgCpFYsABCAwA)

```
1#.1%1+i.
       i.  NB. range 0..n-1
     1+    NB. add 1
   1%      NB. 1 divided by each element
1#.        NB. sum the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
ř⅟Ʃ
        implicit input
ř       produces a list containing 1 to n
 ⅟      takes the reciprocals
  Ʃ     sums the list
        (implicit print)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MxHrfOPrfz/39AAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 47 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xCsIwGIT3PsVROuRHrO3gEogguDg4iZM4pDVtI/WvJHGQ0mevaQ9uuu/jfK17PQ/Vy9QBF20Z4/w0DTrB8syB5Gn4Vr1RthGsVEEFTO8NyrzY8SZC25JmYDHeURbatV7i6Jz@3a/BWW4fJHFjG6AwJogRJcKAPeXN4IyuO4xgqMO6AZ/ohJ6FTzuRMUUrG@MNTSmtxJQsneY/)

```scala
def h(n:Int):Double=if(n==0)0 else 1.0/n+h(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RỊ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVIlRTElQkIlOEEmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01JmZsYWdzPVNl)

##### Explanation

```python
RỊ  # Implicit input
R   # One range
 Ị  # Reciprocal
    # Take the sum
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 61 bytes

```
proc h {x s\ 0} {time {set s [expr $s+1./[incr i]]} $x;set s}
```

[Try it online!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV1VtaUV3Mk9TSUk)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```c
float f(n){return n?1./n+f(--n):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#FYxBDoIwEEWv8oMhmUkBy1ZQL@KGWCZOglNSy4p4dqyr/15e8k9qz2ULM8ZPDhq71@2QJU4ZQsZ7mvOWDHbvu7M5obY1vvjhe6hlvCc14l1ior8qrvBDmRG9RwHnwFhTaUJVHRi1PKxqtBFS5nLyAw)

Answer (score 0):

## Braingolf, 20 bytes [non-competing]

```
VR1-1[1,!/M,$_1+]v&+
```

This won't actually work due to braingolf's inability to work with floats, however the logic is correct.

#### Explanation:

```
VR1-1[1,!/M,$_1+]v&+   Implicit input
VR                     Create new stack and return to main stack
  1-                   Decrement input
    1                  Push 1
     [..........]      Loop, always runs once, then decrements first item on stack at ]
                       Breaks out of loop if first item on stack reaches 0
      1,!/             Push 1, swap last 2 values, and divide without popping
                       Original values are kept on stack, and result of division is pushed
          M,$_         Move result of division to next stack, then swap last 2 items and
                       Silently pop last item (1)
              1+       Increment last item on stack
                 v&+   Move to next stack, sum entire stack 
                       Implicit output of last item on current stack
```

[Here's a modified interpreter](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#zRprj9u48bt/BbNJTlLW61jbxwfvOu2hyKFX4HqH6zUo4PgWOpleq7ElVZQdL@7Qv54OHyKHFOm1s8FuAyQxyeFwXpyXuGyqDWF3jBSbumpakjW3u6vBks8ut2XeVtVarzV0sc2pWs2r9ZrmbVGVen1B/7OFZTWq2KjO2pUZ17TJ2qrRE0VLG4FfzzRZuag2ZgjIBvk6Y4wwgTsW/yaTAYGzluTm5pa2gGVzcxMzul4OSVEu6F6sE1IsScGKkrVZmdNYrAwJWxc5VQAEDmi3TUnau5oKBEmsaRoVAhTjHQGqpjWDqja/aZ0kA4RSEDoKETgYAKr8AyNTMptfDfJt04gJGI@vBrRcwI9vsjUD/uuGMtrsqJnJq3IHRJqJhsKYIQjWNkV5a8aU5VmN1jfbdVvUAIOQsA9FbUbFEpHAijXFoMu1AP2p4cpeVxXad9tQurgzY74qpCY5E2fm1VZgOztTlOSrrFHjAVcr11obM6GltrlT2hRTWMT8fBjTfU7rlrzL1lv6tmmqZoKBBB0SrbQ/Gnd2OCTLAsQONkFBpAtxnNrVgcQ2hKIPdCq0tcvWsfgxJJ2WhoBhJzCB9XWTFkFiw2w85wAASyjQpyYvUrAFImb6W0Z1Va/pso2T/k6@FnuoYwfJA6XK9YS8Iam@MzbVhPBDQTv30y0oLm5XBjr1Ql8qaMOnfcgxnHpOO26bOTTMqs3EOExu73x5hlJbzKGGEshVTiyUcLuufsnWcjtDO@XETLuFudoN12dDb5YZeOWGxaVUJJx/Cf@rWeFRYPhxBZcWFl/B3@spKTXPJXlJio6PgpxPSdpjrySvX09JoUYK8yira/BMcZEMFCJtNQ5EmRhW1JKiPwM3dQMRhsX8H3XjOi8ofnc4lL9PhECXVUP24AF4cGKWc2/jPXLmDJTVIdgnndqENYw2WZuv4ujn97PRq/fzF9GQmJ1Z03xb1luuSsov9d5YWIAiwTVQVUiq5PYOHaKuSMykpBAui5akAND4FK38WhYJmU476Xr3Vs3C3Wv011GXc@oKPOvFkydJ38T1/r3Zb0sYbVXKhnWwVKPqOK8WMtg@F54/jn6AaR6aXrII7FAsX/kugpIDT0aQd1JBE2zWtqTdLJ3MnestYYPmdMdZg3TjlsbjofaEnL3EpA96bnYHnoyRsmp5HOoEYi1PZYRCU5gzfZXRHNCFRp0vwptkoEczKtJbIuOhHmMVsR5NmGCPt0G0R0MI93hRxHs0wQM@GvKgjoYy5jvrIuhb7HWR3yWNR38@t5cpQue69uRamIA2ISVvgDJOVJptDnMcbLZXrnov3BqYIh88D6s70bfzeadtv6YBQK8iRUsla2sBmWrHuuRUTUn0W0TEReK/J5HBZ6dbxm8s3EkwgrYoeabVncPF2ztnHlneR0frN2SM77@evxACMgtc@pbe/F7FzvYcvCYCm6U@@cYeERPSW@bIW6JUEZSZ@zD6SOySS47OoEhktNcYRWaQYrkLjUvDx/wqtxWN/l0VZTzLV01cCHrBOtM0/X2aXkpk48TEAylkY2UX4tDJfJ4M@aWfRlHSO9pNRZB/MWmAzkkmLnKRaEnernFiJ1Mg5fzMob4CwLDsFhyaHqcO8KhKZfHaCrlz6tnqWUSgzhNsS2@FroVVuQwsSXA7mMm4Z2StXcjcZk7XFAMUWuXx79/bd8VHByG6ZlJlRt/UzDncQE2yody2FSWcmGnuNq7kBg6hEyMncAwa3wddfbkbziJzqJKjD@wmQirh2KUHN5xBDoTcbKjM4ZEoOfYKARJt/EFTC1iaV/r2bcMHBinpaDmKsYdRi6Q9vU/akqhZ4bA0T7x8F6I5MLbkwFq9i/VFf/aSTSDhOoOEi3dBhsQ@ap4kWHiAXtcE/I9d0bvM/fk@5ixPE7xK3FzxbT2kXgHLb9wBX/zZ3lV6ytn8CK1L4XJq@qZyWGjPtdCMA/Dd0/9GprTpOjw@uBfm2neW6AMb3qerQE9AKYR3QuxaFwtTNEjCy9gHCkzBVdVqCZhJICAa1SlJLboE70iVfKVlo@F8IhxFXq@u2yCJu@FXvUE3suQtq0WOAkVjbBkrTPWKuJWo4uwFX1hZIW7dvM2Cvki1eGXv7O3336DOWRAe8bX2CwJl1u6Ohd5xenQJ3EGn7zlwZQZ3k8edJMCWyDhXfUobP2@yNz3i/3WFxHFMJL2LNXb81An8IToZvs8G/8PCeNDd@YWtfQlgD9rb@Gi75Ng41dediPqW987WTr/C71wr6qmb@j4hF7rfpVHujD9Gm8zvc5J2bHZSEMQZiAsdMDlSPf3GOhoVKbjf79t4jau2EzjJvSbBhDMXuaTGNTkq0qpmhtX6s4Tf0E21o8ryDvCHaPzuAI2PbLsl3bdBdWNtIDLBSOXldaOSRqbFxX2Py/3m/537C5d77a58tncy/z9i/j3WeNB0/vGAGGJ5mk3WrkYMKnpOYo/Gv3zRY/KK@Y/56Yse02YBbuoHBd5iI/rz9pcHrVjsPaqmhbRL7giG3B51P2jqSvrRyeX6Z9i2InJ/8LG/uxS@TXzoSC//iF1Yh7TnwXypZAfs0rh9KI2ym6h3f3EC9/6MZVMEs7F/BXZk@9AOis2I2XbE7jUkkdqKLoBosZNnUzOGtLnXF0WVYtcVRVOfly@9Pcr1mrY/Ev2zaW/yPJ1bsdJDt4fyE900ov5vmHq3cgvbpWuZmC2naSIK6oRDnmW0qLZfv/32@3@e2VWHa64pruPc5K4PPk4O1nKWfbv4Picm2rR2THL35bLZ6xwgPS0DerLndeG49Knvr7g1JzpzuqnMy5QiCXV/DrUpUtVk5fim8sdsMoE6VHHTr0fLk12Z32D4fT7kxg6k/EETOsXj/f2R@EiP52P8OXz86QHB2fjUhEe@8aM40ZkmWH0KQhjxY5@9u/H8iKbzyWHFbYM4L3xG2WIxtALN0ApDyb3Zs9N7XYY7iboO3W56vSdv1Ru402b//GDzKkg0kvnrp5B5CwaxKHZfUu7OBZ/Jd4jmyCVYXiPOPEZySECvnkJAm@36MYUjjjtRLhdPIRe2/eUx5SKOO1EuPz@FXOrq42PKRRx3olxePsk9qhaPeo/4cUfLxX3Q0O8890usZ1qKiGDfZ4hrp3prqpZLxtOnf@OH7ANeaUD5@lgcO/A@2Dj9iYX3i6zvacVRjygSC6kbkLUaAw8l5ObQAwj/44f@w4fu2UCpPst3HwOduC4/hNn1JlpG3wLEm5ABq7ZNTqdRFH1692N6kc7S4bPX3w1f3KTn891X559g4Wogn9ZJ0BH//ljzd22fPv3hfw) that supports floats. First argument is input.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 17 bytes

```
~),{2.-1??./\/+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Tp9pIT9fQ3l5PP0Zfu1br/39TAA)

1-indexed

```
~                   # Parse n to an integer
 ),                 # Make an array from 0 to n
   {           }*   # For each number in the array, skipping the 0
    2.-1??          # 2^(2^-1) = sqrt( 2 )  We just need any float
          ./        # Divide previous number by itself, this will result in the float 1.0
            \/      # Divide 1.0 by the current number of the array
              +     # Add the result
```

Without the [convertion to float](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26553/98257) it could be reduced to 10 bytes, but the output would be a fraction.

```
~),{-1?+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Tp1rX0F67Vuv/f1MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
$+/\,a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRVs/Rifx////pgA)

#### Explanation

```
     a  First command-line argument
   \,   Inclusive range from 1 through that number
  /     Invert each number in the range
$+      Fold on + (summing the list)
        Autoprint (implicit)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
n[:1f/f1-]&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8v2sowTT/NUDdWTfv/f2MA)

Found a simpler way to do this...  The original was: `0ns[1f/+l1-s]p`

And here's what it's doing.

```
n
```

Get 'n' from the challenge (the number of iterations) from the input and push onto the stack.

```
[...]
```

As long as the top of the stack is non-zero.

```
:1f/
```

Duplicate the top of the stack (the iteration counter), and compute `1/n`.

```
f1-
```

Flip the two entries on the stack so that the `1/n` calculation is second and the iteration counter is on the top.  Then decrement the iteration counter.

```
&+
```

Once all the values have been computed, sum the stack and print.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel (2016), 28 bytes

```
=SUM(1/ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,A1)))
```

### Excel (current), 20 bytes

```
=SUM(1/SEQUENCE(A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculate), 16 bytes

```
total(1/[1...n])
```

[Try it on desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vaatqdue8c)

Uses the total function instead of sigma notation to be able to shave off the latex. Also uses desmos's built-in vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

## HP 28S, 18 bytes

```
0 1 ROT FOR K K INV + NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 15 bytes

```
{sum 1 X/1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0V8FQIULfUE9PJb72f3FipYKSSryCrZ1CdZoCUERJIS2/SAEoa/ofAA)

`1 X/ 1..$_` is 1 cross-divided by the numbers from 1 up to the input number $_, producing the list 1, 1/2, 1/3, ..., 1/$_.  Then (of course) `sum` sums them.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 16 bytes

```ruby
:+|:sum+(:/&1.0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWG6y0a6yKS3O1Naz01Qz1DDQhwssKFNyiTWMhnAULIDQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 17 bytes

```
0$:@?!n$:1-}1$,+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30DFysFeMU/FylC31lBFR1vx////umWmAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Itr, 4 bytes

`#¹¯S`

outputs result as fraction

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I7mvUw==&in=NQ==)

append `0e*` for floating point output

### Explanation

```
#    ; read number from stdin
 ¹   ; 1-based range
  ¯  ; replace elements with their reciprocals 
   S ; sum
     ; implicit output
```