# The most unreliable gun ever

Tags: code-golf, probability-theory

You are given a very special gun with a full magazine.

Let `n` be the initial number of bullets in the magazine and `i` the number of bullets left.

That gun is really unreliable, hence each time you shoot, you have a `i/n` chance to successfully shoot. The fewer bullets you have left, the more tries it requires to shoot.

The goal is to find the average number of attempts to shoot before running out of ammo.

#### Example

You start with 3 bullets (`n=3`). Your first shot is always successful. You have now 2 bullets left. You will shoot first with a probability of `2/3` and misfire with `1/3`. The probability of emptying your magazine in just 3 tries (no misfires) is `(3/3) * (2/3) * (1/3)`.

The average number of tries before emptying your magazine for this example is `5.5`.

#### Test Cases

```
f(2) = 3.000
f(3) = 5.500
f(4) = 8.330
f(10) ~= 29.290
```

Comment: Can you give a few more input/output examples? I suspect that this is a very simple equation.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123173/partial-sum-of-harmonic-sequence)

Comment: Now I'm picturing a revolver with a small motor attached to the cylinder to keep it spinning.

Comment: Aside from being a trivial variation on a question which was posted three days ago, this a) is underspecified, making no mention of the required precision; b) gives an incorrect test case: `f(4) = 25/3` exactly, which under no circumstances rounds to `8.330`.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
L/O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fR9///39DAwA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVln530ff/3@l0uH9VgqH9yvp/DfiMuYy4TI0AAA)

**Explanation**

```
L     # range [1 ... n]
 /    # divide n by each in above list
  O   # sum
```

Comment: Explanation is needed

Comment: @sagiksp: Explanation provided :)

Comment: This is pure magic, I'm moving to 05AB1E now, nothing can stop me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```hs
f n=sum$(n/)<$>[1..n]
```

**[Try it online (TIO)!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7a4NFdFI09f00bFLtpQTy8v9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagqHBfwA)**

---

Previous, more self-explanatory version:

```hs
f n=sum[n/i|i<-[1..n]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 4+1= 5 bytes

Inspired by [Emigna's 05AB1E solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123945/58974).

+1 byte for the `-x` flag.

```
õ@/X
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9UAvWA==&input=MTAKLXg=)

Comment: Are flags worth 1 byte again?

Comment: No, @Oliver, this was posted before they cost 2 bytes (or before I knew they did, at least).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have looked at the date.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
D@/Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/fxUH/3OL//w0NAA)

Inspired by [Emigna's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123945/58974)

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>41</s> 34 bytes

Based on [Emigna's insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123945/58974)

Could almost definitely be golfed more.

```
  9jpX
 {:s_=1(
 &_L+&l@
iM!l
rLz@
```

#### Rough explanation

Part 1: Making a range and dividing by each of the numbers:

```
 {:s
 &_L
iM!l
rLz@
```

Part 2: Summing them up

```
    _=1(
    +&l@
```

Part 3: Printing, exiting, and making sure we don't visit this earlier

```
  9jpX
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 37 Bytes

```php
for(;$i++<$argn;)$s+=$argn/$i;echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ2toYP0/Lb9Iw1olU1vbBixmralSrG0LZuqrZFqnJmfkqxRb//8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>44</s> <s>34</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

[Also](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123946/58974) inspired by [Emigna's 05AB1E solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123945/58974).

```
f=(n,i=n)=>i&&n/i+f(n,--i)
```

<sub>(Look at me , going for recursion over array mapping for once!)</sub>

---

### Try it

```js
f=(n,i=n)=>i&&n/i+f(n,--i)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
o.innerText=f(i.value=1)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
rid_,:)f/:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vygzJV7HSjNN30r7/39DAwA)

Inspired by [Emigna's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123945/58974)

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 30 characters

```
. as$n|[range(1;.+1)|$n/.]|add
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq '. as$n|[range(1;.+1)|$n/.]|add' <<< 10
29.289682539682538
```

[Try in jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/9GnepHRjOL)