# Output the hours at 90 degrees

Tags: code-golf, integer, clock

Today while playing with my kids I noticed that an apparently simple toy in the park hid a challenge.

[image: Clock]

The wheel has a triangle that points to a number, but also has three circles that point to the numbers every 90 degrees from the first one. So:

**Challenge (really simple)**

Given an integer between 1 and 12 (the one pointed by the triangle) in any acceptable form, output also in any acceptable form and order the three numbers pointed by the circles (the ones every 90 degrees).

**Test cases**

```
In       Out
1        4, 7, 10
2        5, 8, 11
3        6, 9, 12
4        7, 10, 1
5        8, 11, 2
6        9, 12, 3
7        10, 1, 4
8        11, 2, 5
9        12, 3, 6
10       1, 4, 7
11       2, 5, 8
12       3, 6, 9
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code for every language win!

Comment: May we take the input as 0-indexed? Like, `0 -> 4, 7, 10`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder sorry, this time I'm going to say no.

Comment: Is this the fourth challenge now based on some activity involving your kids? :P

Comment: @FlipTack Perhaps we need an inspired-by-kids tag ;)

Comment: @FlipTack I've lost count. :-) But given that I spent most of my free time with my kids, guess where does my inspiration come from...

Comment: @Steadybox That would be a meta tag, which is _**BAD**_. But yes, we do. (Perhaps a meta question with links would suffice?)

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda n:{*range(n%3,13,3)}-{n,0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqlqrKDEvPVUjT9VYx9BYx1izVrc6T8eg9n9afpFCnkJmngJE3hAoq2lVUJSZV6KRp6OQppGnqfkfAA)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda n:[(n+c)%12+1for c in 2,5,8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlojTztZU9XQSNswLb9IIVkhM0/BSMdUxyL2P4ifB@IXJealp2oY6hgaa1oVFGXmlSjk6SikaeRp/gcA)

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
12Rṙ’m3Ḋ
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QKOjhzpmPGmbmGj/c0fUfJAAA)** or see [all cases](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QKOjhzpmPGmbmGj/c0QXiHt1zuP1R05qjkx7unAGkDQ4tA5LeQBz5HwA).

#### How?

```
12Rṙ’m3Ḋ - Link: number, n   e.g. 5
12       - literal twelve         12
  R      - range                  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    ’    - decrement n            4
   ṙ     - rotate left            [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4]
      3  - literal three          3
     m   - modulo slice           [5,8,11,2]
       Ḋ - dequeue                [8,11,2]
```

Comment: Alternative solution: `12Rṙm-3Ḋ` (output in reverse order)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda n:(range(1,13)*2)[n+2:n+9:3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSqMoMS89VcNQx9BYU8tIMzpP28gqT9vSyjj2f1p@kUKmQmaeAkyJAlCNFZdCQVFmXolGmkampuZ/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org),  <s>29</s>  28 bytes

*Thanks to @Giuseppe for saving a byte!*

```r
function(n)(n+1:3*3-1)%%12+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1MjT9vQyljLWNdQU1XV0Ejb8H9afpGCRqZCZp6CoZWhkSZXNZcCECQnlmikaWRqasJ5SjF5Sppctf8B)

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
I:I*+12X\
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39PKU0vb0Cgi5v9/EwA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `4` as an exmaple.

```
I:     % Push [1 2 3]
       % STACK: [1 2 3]
I      % Push 3
       % STACK: [1 2 3], 3
*      % Multiply, element-wise
       % STACK: [3 6 9]
+      % Add implicit input, element-wise
       % STACK: [7 10 13]
12     % Push 12
X\     % 1-based modulus. Implicit display
       % STACK: [7 10 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

## APL+WIN, 13bytes

```
(⎕⌽⍳12)[3×⍳3]
```

Explanation:

```
⎕ Prompt for screen input of indicated time t

⍳12 Create a vector of integers from 1 to 12

⌽ Rotate the vector by t elements front to back

[3×⍳3] Select 3rd, 6th and 9th elements.
```

Comment: Quite neat. I like that indexed rotation approach

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 48 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=4;--i;printf("%d ",n%12?:12))n+=3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEETv@YolUNgl5pDWU9fQb5FIJAfXUuup5NtjUsXObebtDBvsPYRSEkcU2uJzweTPbG3ieUmyRtTdDfRJOtdPo@uJxPiBc6kMHtckSGpTUFWrgC0V7xjk4gYGY4R2@D1pOlbHOgtC/Eftg8PN7/WFWv@SrHL5AA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

Similar to [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152118/58563).

```js
n=>[2,5,8].map(k=>(n+k)%12+1)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>[2,5,8].map(k=>(n+k)%12+1)

for(n = 1; n <= 12; n++) {
  console.log(n + ' -> ' + f(n));
}
```

Comment: I had `n=>[3,6,9].map(v=>(v+n)%12)` then realized that it returns 0, not 12...

Comment: @ericw31415 Actually, my 1st approach was `n=>[3,6,9].map(v=>(v+n)%12||12)` (but that's 31 bytes).

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes

```matlab
@(x)[a=1:12 a](3+x:3:9+x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc47CsMwEEXR3qt4TUDGg/FI/goM2UdIIULcpgnBu1fm42Kaw1x4n9e3/N712Pu@r/dwto@yc@aI8gypO3PKW3e29QiMFrhhJCwEHpojRJeJsIqwSHKZCZtIFBldLJETmVwsIejP7GIJIYksLpYQRpH1Ek0Ik8h2iSaEWYQHF7KRCmyggWxUiAb6LxOb@gc)

Fairly simple anonymous function.

We first create an array of `[1:12 1:12]` - so two copies of the full number set. Then we index in to select the values of `x+3, x+6, x+9`, where `x` is the number input.

Octave is 1-indexed, so we can simply select the array elements based on the input (although to be honest 0-indexed would use the same number of bytes here).

This seems to use a method that is unique to the other answers in that by having two copies of the array, we don't have to wrap the indices using modulo.

Comment: Very nice, but the "boring" mod approach is shorter! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc67CsJAEIXhPk9xGmGXDCGz2c2lEHwPsRA1naQRydtv5pJimo/54Wyv3/P/qeu167p6C3v8bu@wt/eEgvlBnGLLdQ2MCFyQCROB@2YNyaUQZhEWGVxGwiKSRLKLJXIixcUSgv6MLpYQBpHJxRJCFplP0YRQRJZTNCGMIty7kI1UYAMNZKNCMtB/mdjUAw "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe lol, I'm sure I tried using `mod` and couldn't make it shorter. Well done! Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge-93, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
852<_@#:.+1%+66+&p
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=ODUyPF9AIzouKzElKzY2KyZw&input=Ng)

**Explanation**

```
852                   Push 8, 5 and 2 onto the stack - the offsets we're going to add.
   <                  Reverse direction, and start the main loop.
852                   Push 2, 5, and 8 onto the stack, but we don't actually want these.
                 p    So we use a "put" operation to drop the top three values.
                &     Read the hour from stdin.
               +      Add it to the topmost offset.
         +1%+66       Mod 12 and add 1 to get it in the range 1 to 12.
        .             Then output the result to stdout.
    _@#:              Exit if the next offset is zero (i.e. nothing more on the stack).
   <                  Otherwise start the main loop again.
```

This relies on behaviour specific to the reference interpreter: on end-of-file, the `&` operator returns the last value that was read. That's why we can safely re-read the hour from stdin on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Neat. I didn’t know `&` did that

Comment: @JoKing Technically it's a bug in the interpreter, another related side-effect being that `&` can also be used as a kind of [one-off random number generator](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Ji5A&input=). That is less reliable, though, since it depends on the compiler that was used to build it. It's working on TIO at the moment, but there was a time when Dennis changed to a different version of gcc and we lost that functionality for a while.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
1+12|2 5 8∘+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//9m4oaQMSsxMnwyIDUgOOKImCv//@KNqijiiqIsJ@KGkicsZinCqOKNszEy)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ƵžS+12%>
```

At the time of writing this, this submission has the lowest score submitted. Technically I am winning!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//2Naj@4K1DY1U7f7/NwEA)

## How?

```
ƵžS                   # Push the list [2, 5, 8]
   +                  # Add the input to each number
    12%               # Mod each result by 12
       >              # Increment each
                      # And print the ending list implicitly!
```

See [this tip of Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/98140) to know why `Ƶž` is 258!

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
3{3+:6«‰P
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MyU3QjMrJTNBNiVBQiV1MjAzMFA_,inputs=OQ__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 44 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@n=[(n+i)rem 12+1\\i<-[2,5,8]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4zLIc82WiNPO1OzKDVXwdBI2zAmJtNGN9pIx1THIjb2f3BJIlCtrYKDguH/f8lpOYnpxf91PX3@u1TmJeZmJhcDAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 42 bytes

```cs
h=>new[]{(2+h)%12+1,(5+h)%12+1,(8+h)%12+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BisIwEIbPyVMM4kJKq9jCglDtRfCkILjgofQQstEOaAJJVCTk2euwrMrA/N/hn2@Unyjr9HD1aE6wf/igLzVXZ@k97CL3QQZUsL4atUATCqDVdg384EXvezwGWMLQLxuj720XRZX32VdZ5WUhvj84f2Eaav5S3iz@wlaiERmPnB2tA0FyQDKWNcWCsiLI84wzarCbdCCdkw9qvP8LzMjJ2Moab896enAY9AaNFuNRxASTBuLfUTvrUvGP5QerLo3IwBKnGZ4)

Essentially just a port of many of the other answers to C#.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 11 bytes

```
3ÆU±3 uC ªC
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=M8ZVsTMgdUMgqkM=&input=OA==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`. Generate a 3 element array (`3Æ`) and, for each element, increment `U` by 3 (`U±3`), modulo by 12 (`uC`) and, because `12%12=0`, return the result OR 12 (`ªC`).

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 11 bytes

**Solution:**

```
1+12!2 5 8+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31Db0EjRSMFUwULb8P9/AA)

**Examples:**

```
1+12!2 5 8+1
4 7 10
1+12!2 5 8+2
5 8 11
1+12!2 5 8+3
6 9 12
1+12!2 5 8+4
7 10 1
```

**Explanation:**

This was the first solution that came to mind. Might not be the best or shortest.

```
1+12!2 5 8+ / the solution
     2 5 8+ / add 2, 5 and 8 to the input
  12!       / apply modulo 12 to the results
1+          / add 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 46 bytes

```
~13,1>:x?:y;0:i;x y 3+12%=x y 6+12%=x y 9+12%=
```

This is the first time I'm doing code golf, so with my lack of experience I've probably not found the best solution, but I need to start somewhere, right?

[Try it online](https://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=IjEifjEzLDE+Ong/Onk7MDppO3ggeSAzKzEyJT14IHkgNisxMiU9eCB5IDkrMTIlPQ==) or [try all cases](https://copy.sh/golfscript/?c=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)

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This looks like a nice first answer :) Unfortunately, I don't know anything about golfscript, but you might be able to get some tips [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5264/31716)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 84 bytes

```
(()()()){({}<(()(){})(((()()()){}){}<>){(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}<>(([{}]{})<>)>[()])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDEwQ1qzWqa23AnOpaTQ0NuHAtENnYAaWB8hBV0RqasZo2drXVtUAJDY3o6tpYoBRQjR1YBij4/78JAA)

At least I beat [Doorknob's face solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152240/31203)...

Explanation:

```
LOOP 3 TIMES: (()()()){({}<

  n += 2:
   (()(){})
  push 12:
   (((()()()){}){}<>)
  n mod 12 + 1; pushing to both stacks:
   {(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}<>(([{}]{})<>)

END LOOP: >[()])}<>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
%R12+LQ*R3S3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzXI0EjbJ1AryDjY@P9/EwA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica) 20 bytes

```
Mod[#+{3,6,9},12,1]&
```

The normal modulus operation, threaded over a list, offset by 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zc/JVpZu9pYx0zHslbH0EjHMFbtv0t@NFdAUWZeSXSmjoKSgq6dgpKOQlp0Zmwsl45CNVDMEIiMamP/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
⁺ẇf+12%›
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigbrhuodmKzEyJeKAuiIsIiIsIjQiXQ==) ([All test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIxMsm+xpsiLCLigbrhuodmKzEyJeKAuiIsIm4kd0o74oGLIiwiIl0=))

Port of [SunnyMoon's 05AB1E solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215712/80050)

**How it works:**

```
⁺ẇf+12%›
⁺ẇ        The number 258
  f       ...as a list of digits ⟨ 2 | 5 | 8 ⟩
   +      Add the input to each
    12%   Mod-12 each
       ›  Increment each
          (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 62 bytes (46×2=92 codels)

```
TABdDTvVvVnNNFJAQUiIiIIAeEeEuUUMTJBCSBvVvVNMLnNnNfFFVBQIMEiCcc
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxdj8EOwiAMht-l55LQMYbyKoSDmZgsmbpkejJ7dxspDsahP7Tla_8PjM9rAh-CRjpHDDSI9qIdUsdaykj_6ND9Yi6YrKcWIxQrWabogzZDGeYqtWirz5RVt4PKntJlDulm34YjM4sLJyZMZYZaWL-7qEHk9ryVVWyMCGtawINSChDm6c530nz4ldYR_O0yrwlheizvF9cG2L7PpGCu)

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 45 bytes (5×18=90 codels)

```
tAaaqreeumccsqqqijlVa rbiqaaueljnvea?_ t?B tt
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJyVj1EKgzAQRO-y3yNkNYnGq6gfxaYgWCvYfknv3l27HsBk4G02M0uy0_i6Z2q7zoEjOF3SgE5DER4luFYFMIODqpK2bnZoIDZzJ_UeXY9_OmgwikkmHGOk24g0kOCOg7_2Ko25a38ZQFteqaWiKAg0T0-p2cmSU95Gah-3ecugaVk_b73rF7H2S2msjN4YjNFYGxtjMrI7i3Mil_T9AV0UXkY)

[image]

My looping template is getting weirder and weirder... :P

```
inN 4    [n 4]; force toggle CC at the exit of 4 region
Loop:
  dup CC+    [n flag] switch CC on 3rd iteration so it will exit after the loop
  2 1 roll   [flag n]
  2 +        [flag n+2]
  3 dup dup * + %  [flag (n+2)%12]
  1 + d outN [flag next_n] compute and print the next number
  1 outC     [flag next_n] print the separator (ASCII 1)
  2 1 roll   [next_n flag]
  2 /        [next_n flag/2] divide flag by 2; flag becomes odd after two loops
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṇɗd+12%⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU4NyVDOSU5N2QlMkIxMiUyNSVFMiU4MSVCQSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTcmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
ṇɗd+12%⁺  # Implicit input
ṇɗ        # Push compressed integer 258
  d+      # Add [2,5,8] to input
    12%   # Mod each by 12
       ⁺  # Increment each
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 9 bytes

```
12Rᶠ{-Z3¦
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FmsMjYIebltQrRtlfGjZkuKk5GKoxIJdhlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJZchgZchoZchkYQFQA)

```
12Rᶠ{-Z3¦
12R         [1,2,...,12]
   ᶠ{       Filter by
     -          Subtract the input
      Z         Check if the result is non-zero
       3¦       Check if the result is divisible by 3
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 10 bytes

```
258¢D+12%→
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FmuNTC0OLXLRNjRSfdQ2aUlxUnIxVGbBLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuCy5LLkMDLkNDLkMjiAoA)

```
258¢D+12%→
258¢D       Decimal digits of 258
     +      Add
      12%   Modulo 12
         →  Increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 12 bytes

```
258s{K+12%h_
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/I1KK42lvb0Eg1I/7///@GhgA)**

```
258            \ Push 258                            
   s           \ Split into digits, yielding [2, 5, 8]
    {K+        \ Add input to each
       12%     \ Modulo each by 12
          h    \ Increment each
           _   \ Print (space separated)
```

### 12 bytes

An alternative for the same byte count:

```
12R{:{;$...#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/QKKjaqtpaRU9PT/k/kAsA)**

```
12R            \ Push range(1, 12), inclusive
   {: ;        \ Input times do:
     {         \   Rotate left
       $       \ While there are items on stack:
        ...    \   Pop the top three
           #   \   Print top item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Laikoni.*

```hs
f n=[mod(n+i)12+1|i<-[2,5,8]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6Nz9FI087U9PQSNuwJtNGN9pIx1THIjb2f25iZp6CrUJuYoGvgkZBUWZeiYKeQpqmQrShnp6hUex/AA)

Not very original, no...

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 45 bytes

```
proc R i {lmap c {2 5 8} {expr ($i+$c)%12+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVBCoAgEAXQq3zEoHClEETHcCsuYjAYqBQzCMSzW2/zCh29pxwJFox6nFsCoRrMWBpqeFPGKFlJmgZtlG6tFz4DanrKDeEsHF@Uwd5jj/8rJIsGbfoH)

---

Different approach using the command line arguments:

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 39 bytes

```
time {puts [expr [incr argv 3]%12+1]} 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWCE6taKgSCE6My@5SCGxKL1MwThW1dBI2zC2VsH4////xgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 30 bytes

```swift
{n in[2,5,8].map{($0+n)%12+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQpmD7vzpPITMv2kjHVMciVi83saBaQ8VAO09T1dBI27C29n9afpFCJlCFgqGenp6hUXVBUWZeiUamTppGpqZm7X8A)

Port of many other answers to Swift

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica) 35 bytes

```
Range@12~RotateLeft~#~Take~{3,9,3}&
```

The above asserts, in infix notation, what can be expressed more clearly as

```
Function[Take[RotateLeft[Range[12],Slot[1]],List[3,9,3]]]
```

`RotateLeft` rotates `Range[12]`, the sequence 1,2,...12, leftward by the input number.  `Slot[1]` or `#` holds the input number, n.

For example, with n = 4,

```
Function[RotateLeft[Range[12],4]]]
```

returns the list

```
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

`Take...{3,9,3}` returns every third element in that list from position 3 through position 9, namely

```
{7, 10, 1}
```

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi/JLEk1Sc1rSQ6KDEvPdXB0EhHOTY62tja2tLa2jg2Vu2/S340V0BRZl5JdKaOgpKCrp2Cko5CWnRmbCyXjkI1UMwQiIxqY/8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
258á←+26*%⁺
```

Explanation:

```
258               Pushes 2,5,8 onto the stack
   á              Converts the stack to an array, and pushes the array onto the now-empty stack
    ←+            Adds input to [2,5,8]
      26*%⁺       Mod 12 plus 1 (the 'plus 1' allows for '12' to be output)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fyNTi8MJHbRO0jcy0VB817vr/39AAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 23 bytes

```
{map ($_+*)%12+1,2,5,8}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvhCkAwFAbQV/laJuO22oqkvImS4pYy1uyP5NmH36fjl7A1yV3IGX263eRRZGNVKmlsZchSTe2T@AgwWhuLGz6se2QIaecO8hx2QchGAn9PaXax@EkoPOkF)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 37+1 bytes

```php
while($i++<3)echo(~-$argn+=3)%12+1,_;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/815e176646446e4dd35a41e6c47f69f1a4a2034d).

Answer (score 1):

### [face](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/face), <s>96</s> 94 bytes

```
(%d
@)\$*,c'$ooiim%*m1*6%+%%%11m!*mn*m~*3!m&!r!&!is!&$pn3!:L+nn1+nn1%nn%+nn1p~>$inw~>~o-!!1?!L
```

This simply adds two, mods by 12, adds one more, and prints. Then it does that two more times.

Commented version:

```
(%d
@)

\$*,c'$ooii     ( store format string in $, ip in *, get stdin/out )
m%*m1*6%+%%%11  ( initialize constants, %=12, 1=1 )
m!*mn*m~*       ( malloc space for a counter, input var, and length )
3!m&!r!&!i      ( read into & )
s!&$pn          ( scan into n )
3!:L            ( start of main loop, executed thrice )
  +nn1+nn1      ( add 2 to n )
  %nn%+nn1      ( mod by 12 and add 1 more )
  p~>$in        ( sprintf n into > )
  w~>~o         ( output to stdout )
  -!!1          ( decrement counter )
?!L             ( conditional jump back to loop start )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcU9DoMwDAbQnVt8UhzAwGCQGBhoD8ARulT8SBnsRO3QLVdPxfD0rvd@ltLQUT3bl@N@r12MISixCs/UEZGIgtVYM09Qjw88whfeJZuwbJ2Z3MiM7lNeXbBfXnMcAHlgq0oZ/w) (The trailing newline is required on TIO due to a bug that's been fixed in a newer version of face.)

Comment: Creating a variable that holds the value 3 `m3*33` allows you to replace the three `+nn1`s with one `+nn3` https://tio.run/##BcE9DoMwDAbQPbf4pDiAKUNkiYGB9gAcoUvFj5TBTtQObLl6@t712c/Wejrca3h7fuydzzklJdbIM41EFKOC1ViFRbSyQAO@CEg/BF9MsGyjmZAZlbr6ZHdda56A@MTmWpv/

Comment: @Cowsquack Note that the output in your link is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 bytes

```perl
sub{map{($_+$_[0])%12+1}2,5,8}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKk6N7GgWkMlXlslPtogVlPV0EjbsNZIx1THova/NZdKjK1STJ4SkKFjq6QApAuKMvNKFFTidRRU0nTtgPo0FdLyixQM9fQMjf4DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 30 bytes

```powershell
param($a)2,5,8|%{($_+$a)%12+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVR00jHVMeiRrVaQyVeG8hVNTTSNqz9//@/CQA)

Port of the other answers (e.g., xnor's Python 2 answer). Ho-hum.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 23 bytes

```matlab
@(x)mod(x+[2 5 8],12)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc67CsJAEIXhPk9xGmGXDCGz2c2lEHwPsRA1naQRydtv5pJimo/54Wyv3/P/qeu167p6C3v8bu@wt/eEgvlBnGLLdQ2MCFyQCROB@2YNyaUQZhEWGVxGwiKSRLKLJXIixcUSgv6MLpYQBpHJxRJCFplP0YRQRJZTNCGMIty7kI1UYAMNZKNCMtB/mdjUAw)

Takes the same approach as most others; and it is golfier than Tom Carpenter's somewhat more unique [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152158/67312).

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```java
n->new int[]{1-~-~n%12,(5+n)%12+1,(8+n)%12+1}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NU/basMwDH3fV4hCwcaNwYXBWJZBP2B96WPpg5e6Q1kqB1vpKCX99UxLOpDQ0e1Ip/EXX8QuUHP8HuvW5wwfHun2BIDEIZ18HWD7l06F/QFqJRFIl1IbxMUye8YatkBQwUjFO4Wfefrmintxp6Vbr9SzIS3AuJV6@YfDWM4UXf/ZCsWD6RLxCGf5Q@04IX3tD17PP5ximu5j5Up8q9y6RGP01ALYXTOHs409207WuCWFZvEKC9OITNsztnaTkr9my3FmVmRFkNYPOcP4Cw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 39 bytes

Input is taken from the stack and output is placed on the stack

```forth
: a 2 + 12 mod 1+ ; : f a dup a dup a ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrBCoAgFMDufcXukWDd9GtE0yLjhdX3m3XossFYlHItQ4qvajU4Rnr0yC4B3WMxxFbDffy07UvoCU0Q1q@qdqkTX/B5duW8nN/IIge2S/UB)

#### Explanation

```forth
 : a 2 + 12 mod 1+ ; \ helper word to handle adding the hours
    2 +              \ Add 2 to the input
    12 mod           \ get the result modulo 12
    1+               \ add 1

 : f a dup a dup a ; \ word that calculates and outputs the result
    a dup            \ add 3 hours to the input and then duplicate the result
    a dup            \ add 3 hours to the duplicate then duplicate the result
    a                \ add 3 hours to the duplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 27 bytes

```perl
say+($_+"@F")%12+1for 2,5,8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbQyVeW8nBTUlT1dBI2zAtv0jBSMdUx@K/NVBSXd36vyGXEZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXBZcll6EBl6Ehl6HRv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91EwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
tĊ3ṙḣ12←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v@RIl/HDnTMf7lhsaPSobcL///9NAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 12 bytes

```
00000000: b903 0004 02d4 0c40 aae2 f8c3              ...........
```

Listing

```
B9 0003     MOV  CX, 3          ; loop counter CX = 3
        CLOOP: 
04 02       ADD  AL, 2          ; AL = AL + 2
D4 0C       AAM  12             ; AL = AL % 12 
40          INC  AX             ; AL = AL + 1
AA          STOSB               ; [DI++] = AL
E2 F8       LOOP CLOOP          ; if --CX > 0 goto CLOOP
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input in `AL`, output to buffer at `[DI]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Batch, <s>137 125 111</s> 68 bytes

```
@set/ab=(%1+2)%%12+1,c=(%1+5)%%12+1,d=(%1+8)%%12+1
@echo %b% %c% %d%
```

Port of the `add value to input and mod 12 + 1`

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 29 bytes

```
->n{3.times{p 12+(n+=3)%-12}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
{&((,])}.i.13)@+&(2 5 8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q9U0NHRiNWv1MvUMjTUdtNU0jBRMFSw0/2typSZn5CukKRjCGEYwhjGMYQJjmMIYZjCGOYxhAWNYwg00gLPgZhsa/QcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äÆL6C╪Θ♪
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84924c3643d8e90d&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12&a=1&m=2)

#### Approach

```
3 times:
    add 2
    mod 12
    add 1
    print current value
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel + Google Sheets Polyglot, 21 Bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and returns a 1x3 spilled array beginning at the calling cell.

```vb
=MOD(A1+{2,5,8},12)+1
```