# Make me speak L33T

Tags: code-golf, string

I want to be down with the kids of the 1990's and start speaking this L33T speak of their's.

For any given input I would like the resulting L33T speech as an output.

I don't want to go to far down the rabbit hole so let's start simple.
Consider the following replacements:

B or b = 8

E or e = 3

I or i = 1

S or s = 5

Lets get down with the kids people.

Comment: Bruh, it's 1337

Comment: Not sure why this was VTC  _questions without an objective primary winning criterion are off-topic_, since the challenge was tagged as `code-golf` from the beginning.

Comment: We need an answer in [l33t](https://esolangs.org/wiki/L33t).

Comment: @some_guy632 There is no 7 in L33T as OP mentions. But then again, OP thinks that "i" is substituted with 1. So yeah, this might be a whole different dialect! Not sure which 90s kids were using this, though ...

Comment: 1 in Chinese sounds like an ```i```.

Comment: Typically `L`/`l` is substituted by `1`, not `I`/`i`

Comment: Can you confirm that input will consist of printable ASCII only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„ÛãbÂu«ŽKcº‡
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy* by using the dictionary word `sie`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8w7MPL0463FR6aPXRvd7Jh3Y9alj4/39IRmaxAhAlKpSkFpdYKTgluaZ6ZgYXAwA)

**12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative (from *@Grimy*):**

```
2F.š„ÛãbŽKc‡
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyE3v6MJHDfMOzz68OOnoXu/kRw0L//8PycgsVgCiRIWS1OISKwWnJNdUz8zgYgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
„Ûãb          # Push dictionary string "sieb"
    Â         # Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy)
     u        # Uppercase the copy
      «       # Merge the strings together: "siebBEIS"
       ŽKc    # Push compressed integer 5138
          º   # Mirror it: 51388315
           ‡  # Transliterate "siebBEIS" to "51388315" in the (implicit) input-string
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)

2F            # Loop 2 times:
  .š          #  Switch the case of the string (lower- to uppercase, and vice-versa)
              #  (which will use the implicit input-string in the first iteration)
    „Ûãb      #  Push dictionary string "sieb"
        ŽKc   #  Push compressed integer 5138
           ‡  #  Transliterate "sieb" to "5138" in the string
              # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„Ûãb` is `"sieb"` and `ŽKc` is `5138`.

Comment: Iterative is the same: `.•ª³•vyŽWœNè:`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn That program only replaces the lowercase letters, though. Uppercase `BEIS` characters remain unchanged I'm afraid.

Comment: [-1 with dictionary word `sie`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8w7MPL0463FR6aPXRvd7Jh3Y9alj4/39IRmaxAhAlKpSkFpdYKTgluaZ6ZgYXAwA). And here's an [alternative 12](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyE3v6MJHDfMOzz68OOnoXu/kRw0L//8PycgsVgCiRIWS1OISKwWnJNdUz8zgYgA).

Comment: @Grimmy How did I miss that `sie`.. I've looked through the dictionary in search for useful words containing the letters, but couldn't find any. I thought about `is be`, but the space and being two dictionary words (requiring four characters) would only increase the byte-count. Thanks! And nice alternative with the loop and switch-case, I'll add it. :)

Answer (score 27):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[beis]/gi,c=>parseInt(c+1,31)%9||8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxLDsIgEADQq0yamEDENo0bXbR71y6NC0oHpCIgQ@snvTv6DvAmuUhSyca882HEortCXU91wuikQtZcBrR0bYwVquujTIQnn5natmLf8s1xXQ@8qOApOKxdMEyz6hxv1r8haBj@xx2es0z5K2CaR4Pw@MASXhXn5Qc)

#### How?

By using `parseInt()`, we don't have to worry about the case at all since lowercase and uppercase letters are parsed the same way. The downside of this formula is that we have to explicitly turn \$0\$ into \$8\$. It's still 1 byte shorter than the Node version, though.

```
 char | +'1' | base 31 -> decimal | mod 9 | || 8
------+------+--------------------+-------+------
  'b' | 'b1' |         342        |   0   |  8
  'e' | 'e1' |         435        |   3   |  3
  'i' | 'i1' |         559        |   1   |  1
  's' | 's1' |         869        |   5   |  5
```

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>54</s>  50 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[beis]/gi,c=>17/(Buffer(c)[0]%16)|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxLDoMgFADAqxCTJpBY0U27wkWv0KVxgfigWORREPtJ7047B5hF7jKpaMN29DhD0aIk0acmQnBSAeXDBDaN3Nhaib47c3rJWkOkig3teOhO7NuyotAndNA4NFTT6hpu1r8IajL9kzt5ZBm3T02WPBsg65vs@KwYKz8)

#### How?

We look for `beis` in the input string in a case-insensitive way. For each matching character of ASCII code \$n\$, we apply the following formula:

$$f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{17}{n\bmod 16}\right\rfloor$$

which gives:

```
 char | ASCII code | mod 16 -> x | 17 / x | floor
------+------------+-------------+--------+-------
  'B' |      66    |      2      |  8.5   |   8
  'b' |      98    |      2      |  8.5   |   8
  'E' |      69    |      5      |  3.4   |   3
  'e' |     101    |      5      |  3.4   |   3
  'I' |      73    |      9      |  1.889 |   1
  'i' |     105    |      9      |  1.889 |   1
  'S' |      83    |      3      |  5.667 |   5
  's' |     115    |      3      |  5.667 |   5
```

NB: we could use \$16\$ instead of \$17\$ just as well.

Comment: +1. How did you figure out that formula? (And the past ones, for that matter)

Comment: @Malivil There's usually a good deal of brute-forcing, but not that much for this one. The `mod 16` was trivial, given the way the ASCII table is built. And once I had `2,5,9,3` to be mapped to `8,3,1,5`, it looked very promising to try `something / x` (I did write a short script for that, but now I realize that it's not very hard to find it with mental calculation.)

Answer (score 11):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS) with `i` flag, 15 bytes

```apl
B
E
I
S
8
3
1
5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCoAwDAXQPaf4m5sgIjgLDs6eIGK1hdpoG/H4UZc3vOvmNZsNNNJEM/XUUkOd2YRVUqV4OClUsMvvxvn7J0G9Q@ZlCQov0aEIotOqoChnRQnHGV1t4QU)

I don't need to explain this, do I?

Comment: 1'm afra1d 1 don't und3r5tand th353 5trang3 charact3r5 `B`, `E`, `I`, `S` 1n your cod3, 1 hav3 n3v3r 3ncount3r3d th3m 83for3

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda x:x.translate(dict(zip(b"BEISbeis",2*"8315")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkKvpCgxrzgnsSRVIyUzuUSjKrNAI0nJydUzOCk1s1hJx0hLycLY0FRJU1Pzf0FRZl6JRpqGkkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiiJQigsu456fn5JUmaqj4KlQnJiZogeU/A8A)

-17 bytes thanks to Jitse

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkKvpCgxrzgnsSRVIyUzuUSjKrNAI0nJydUzOCk1s1hJx0hLycLY0FRJU1Pzf0FRZl6JRpqGkkdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiiJQigsu456fn5JUmaqj4KlQnJiZogeU/A8A)

Comment: @Jitse I thought translate had to be used with integer keys... whoops. Thanks!

Comment: It does, but I'm using a bytestring which does contain integers.

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), <s>19</s>, 18 bytes

-1 thanks to @manatwork

```perl
y;BbEeIiSs;8833115
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/S2inJNdUzM7jY2sLC2NjQECimoKikrKKqpq6hqaWto6unb2BoZGxiamZuYWllbWNrZ8/l4Ojk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vnHxAYFBwSGhYeERkVHRMbF8@VkJiUnJKalp6RmZWdk5uXX1BYVFxSWlZeUVlVXVNb9y@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Comment: You can cut off the last “5”, because “if the REPLACEMENTLIST is shorter than the SEARCHLIST, the final character, if any, is replicated until it is long enough” — [perldoc `y///`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlop.html#y%2f_SEARCHLIST_%2f_REPLACEMENTLIST_%2fcdsr).

Comment: sure, I had the idea but then forgot about looking for another approach

Answer (score 8):

### tr, <strike>23</strike> <strike>20</strike> 19

```
tr BbEeIiSs 8833115
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwSnJNdUzM7hYwcLC2NjQ0PT//6TUzGIFJ1fPYAA)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwSnJNdUzM7hYwcLC2NjQ0PT//6TUzGIFJ1fPYAA) from man `SET2 is extended to length of SET1 by repeating its last character as necessary.`

Comment: This is the same as @Delta'a Bash answer (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196065/61292)

Comment: @Wernisch: which I posted 1 day before delta

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 39 bytes

```r
chartr('BbEeIiSs','88331155',scan(,''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzkjsaikSEPdKck11TMzuFhdR93CwtjY0NDUVF2nODkxT0NHXV1T87@Pq2vIfwA)

Comment: Beat me by 10 minutes... but I had this exact solution typed up. I was too busy experimenting with `utf8ToInt` to see if it had any possibility of being shorter.

Comment: @Sumner18 Yeah, I was originally looking at using the formula in Arnauld's answer. Then I remembered `chartr`!

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (x86-64),  <s>71 70</s>  65 bytes

This is essentially a port of my [Node answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196042/58563).

```c
c;f(char*s){for(;c=*s++;)putchar(524836>>c&c/64?48|16/(c&15):c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLDoIwFADAPad4YUFakBAUCLERD@EJ6sOWIlAsPxW5ujXOcjCUiNYiEwQrbvyBrkIbwvDkD0HAaD@N/yfpPskPWVGgh1GWnJP8E2cRQS9O6REp2@ysVQktVx2hsDoAgriXvlLdE7SAa8PxDo@Jm/G9g3oq5Q3aF8x6cSlzNvtF0XA52HD5AQ)

#### How?

On x86-64, `524836>>c` is turned into:

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR c[rip]
mov     edx, 524836
mov     ecx, eax
sar     edx, cl
```

The count operand of `sar` (and other shift instructions) is masked to 5 bits. So this is equivalent to `524836>>(c&31)`.

Therefore, `524836>>c&c/64` is truthy if \$64\le c<127\$ and \$c\bmod32\$ is one of:

```
 10000000001000100100
 ^         ^   ^  ^
19         9   5  2
(s)       (i) (e)(b)
(S)       (I) (E)(B)
```

Answer (score 6):

## PostgreSQL, 54 characters

```
\prompt s
select translate(:'s','beisBEIS','83158315')
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ psql -Atf leet.sql <<< 'aA~bB~eE~iI~sS~zZ'
aA~88~33~11~55~zZ
```

Answer (score 5):

## sed, 20 bytes

```
y/beisBEIS/83158315/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1I/KTWz2MnVM1jfwtjQFIT1//8HiSmABAE)

Answer (score 5):

## [l33t](https://github.com/TryItOnline/l33t), 1346 bytes

```
5o y0u want t0 l34rn t0 sp33k 0n teh 1ntERn1t... 4r3 y0u t3h 14m3rz d00d?
is s0 EZ t0 8e 888888881 awes0mes!! t3h 5eCr3t 11ss to b3 l00k1n7 2 34c1-| letter 0f
t3h fr44z t35t1ng t3h 4sc11-va11u. R34c7 to t3h
zer0 8y go-2 t3h end. 8efor a11 8e g0 w3 n33d-2 5m4sH all t3h l4m3 9999999999996 1etters.
5ome 0f the 1e7ers d0n't n33d t0 b3 ch4ng3d!1 S0 we le4ve them 4l0ne.
5o j00 b3 z33ro s0 w33'1l 999997 1n 5o y0u r3m3mb2r us 4 t33h next 0ne.
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4t thi5 p0int w3 n33d t0 4r3 7777776 & pr1nt 50 j00 5e3 the '0ne' 4 th33 'i'
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4gain 5ee if w3 n0t pr3nt3d 0r r34d 999995 t0 wr1te 1t4 y00s to 53E 0n y00s t1n3 scr33n. Then
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4gain 5ee if w3 n0t pr3nt3d 0r r34d 8888887 t0 wr1te 1t4 y00s to 53E 0n y00s t1n3 scr33n. Then
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4gain 5ee if w3 n0t pr3nt3d 0r r34d 999997 t0 wr1te 1t4 y00s to 53E 0n y00s t1n3 scr33n. Then
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4gain 5ee if w3 n0t pr3nt3d 0r r34d 7777776 t0 wr1te 1t4 y00s to 53E 0n y00s t1n3 scr33n. Then
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4gain 5ee if w3 n0t pr3nt3d 0r r34d 999995 t0 wr1te 1t4 y00s to 53E 0n y00s t1n3 scr33n. Then
cl3r m3m3r11s to bre4k out.
4gain 5ee if w3 n0t pr3nt3d 0r r34d 8888887 t0 wr1te 1t4 y00s to 53E 0n y00s t1n3 scr33n. Then
50 j00 r34d all tH3s3 c0Des, n0w 2 r43d m0re 4nd l00p
bye 5uXz0r5!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VRLc9MwEL77V2wu@EI9UlaK0xMDbSC8IS1QenNsxXZjy0FS4sbDfw8rJcxw4sIhg062vPs99pPVILrDQXawZ1voM@3AMWhQGO0f7AZxDYyeVQVcu9lCc5ckCQiDocMh7YsWzQAFY8WzqLZgGczuffdUwfS0OGS9sqxVdjQKTVJdGXTAubXgOlgiNIytuU5hDChyfvETGuWcMsBWkW9YGSEGapWO6zJACJtzfrHLON8msKCm1CPRl2hQhtj3UHYX41CqdJGQnFVngMq9sJJBj6ARCyqRrbBzyJomFDfkBy7/WBPgQYpNItm1ihSBqxRtprRHvnXsApL3TEbySugSixGHGyJR5EPslO9oQTRMK48CDyzUDoim8xPrEWPeHGlTGjWcIjHYYrscG9haECSP9Gn16CDg5A0aoO9oaI5hjEaJNXRbl0SCkqxqCRtWU6gnr16hjy4NawJPYGMoVpAsCJIKg7OY0GNPVyFCXMd/JyqzmuQqBfUq8DBHqKgd0TFDBkRxtCU9e2@4o9E5Qe5YgJI48yfs@Mo1gs0Nok7gtlL6n5mPxy89B/UpyzMw/473XKb/t6RPxz/AhFtgjpb@Y3at7FPi6ulOMoKoWmYUCF34u2oTLfcK5PZuYEaOosMhW@aFWpVV/bBuWt1tfhjrtrv@cT88f3F1PXv5av76zdt37z98/PR5cXP75eu3u@/3jI9RyEk6vfwF)

I think its self explanatory really. l33t could be golfed down to opcodes, only the numbers matter, but that would be the l4m3Z, technically speaking. (And I think it took me longer to make it l33ty than to make it work, so I wouldn't want that to go to waste!)

Here's the [l4m3 version](https://tio.run/##pVTbUsIwEH3vV6zjAzrjMIVSCo@iqHhXvKBvKd3SSCmYBgr@fE3TK9dhhrzkbM7pnu0ms66m8TC0A0sHFajXN8RmkmEdVIVZ1eREobamgIX9hsAKOMgQAgSOPgfiuoB04HCYEXeKPnAHvUTcSFZFAZkBvDGHltglWxUgPpbn7QjERGoFmUAqOhJJrilhSkq2G0NJG0YcZAKpMBOcuS9LpAbTYK2SFbFU0ywqVLUqlEo/D49Fh0RjPWQwIYyXy@Wck/1uFlY95wJWyYPkxuLy0hvL2L6LhAHlhcS2loqR2rWMWArSZyC0ccZCPUbkv2IbfbzqvcWoiLfYGHLV9/PZbFOAu/5F38tjo0WOthjEL36vbm0yyMChd7Ehebof2v/11Ml2WM/X0tq0Fg2OaNQ4ZIZeicOEUY@jdSbeNoymYvxEBJiIHrTgJMCSmEw@J0I1AMJBPVUOvKf8@6XZCIXhKIs1Fwj6dN5TmX6kKOueO23CkJh9C@2BQ3@G7sgbT36Zz6ezYL74O29dXLavrm86t3f3D49Pzy@v3bf3j8/e17daqWo1vW40mv8), for those interested.

Answer (score 4):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/) (with `-i` switch), 15 characters

```
b=8
e=3
i=1
s=5
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema -i 'b=8;e=3;i=1;s=5' <<< 'This is a test: BbEeIiSs'
Th15 15 a t35t: 88331155
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8nWgivV1pgr09aQq9jW9P9/zxL1YoWS/HyFtMQihcy84pLUxBSF/DSgEFjEukDhUcNkBe/Ussw8Beei0sys4uLUvP@6mQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>36</del> 34 bytes

```php
<?=strtr($argn,BbEeIiSs,88331155);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEhDJbEoPU/HKck11TMzuFjHwsLY2NDQ1FTT@v9/mOC//IKSzPy84v@6bgA)

- -2 bytes thx to @manatwork!

Comment: Why the quotes around the 2nd argument?

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>56</s> 19 bytes

```
?(¦b8|e3|i1|s5║ ™⅍,
```

Uses the newly implemented switch statements to remove 37 bytes!

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>66</s> 43 bytes

```bash
sed -e"s/b/8/Ig;s/e/3/Ig;s/i/1/Ig;s/s/5/Ig"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUE3ValYP0nfQt8z3bpYP1XfGMLI1DeEMIr1TYEMpf//0/LzFZISi4C4SiEnNbVEobggNTEbAA)

**19 Bytes**
I will leave it hear as it was suggested by @WGroleau as an improvement but was already posted by [@Thor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196050/89793)

```bash
tr BbEeIiSs 8833115
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwSnJNdUzM7hYwcLC2NjQ0PT//7T8fIWkxCIgrlLILFbISU0tUSguSE3MhqsFAA)

Thnaks to:
-@MD XF for saving 23 bytes
-@WGroleau for saving 23 bytes
-@Jo King for saving 1 byte

Comment: Works fine without the function stuff... [try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUE3ValYP0nfQt8z3bpYP1XfGMLI1DeEMIr1TYEMpf//0/LzFZISi4C4SiEnNbVEobggNTEbAA)

Comment: But you can use `tr` in bash for only twenty characters.

Comment: Is "bash" the right title for this answer, rather than something like "GNU coreutils" or "POSIX commands"?

Comment: @rexkogitans I would argue that the core utils from gnu are a part of the bash utils or am I wrong?

Comment: @Delta no, at least neither in Debian nor in Manjaro, coreutils is a dependency of bash, and also not the other way around. `tr` is part of coreutils, and `sed` is standalone.

Comment: Although, this is now the same as the `tr` answer...

Comment: You could easily remove the `tr` command and call the language `tr`. Same for `sed -e"..."`.

Comment: @Neil I'm sry didn't check if there was an answer when this was suggested as an improvment, i will roll it back

Comment: @JL2210 your are rigtht i think, but i would argue that this is work under bash...

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 71 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set s=%s:b=8%
@set s=%s:e=3%
@set s=%s:i=1%
@echo(%s:s=5%
```

Takes a line of input on STDIN. Batch's substitute operator is automatically case insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @Laikoni!

```hs
map(\c->last$c:[b|(a,b)<-zip"BEISbeis""83158315",a==c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEADQXzlChxZaQUQQMQ6Kg@BQcBGsQ5KeydGYBnNQEL/dqMMbn1NpQO@zlV1@qFh2ptl6lbgw66t@l6rW1aZ5URS7w/GskZIQq8V8@SdqJaW5Vb9HASTEJwWGAiyIE3ICiwz9OAWYiB2wQxioTxBxjB5nIn/M3SubcnPZt@0X)

Comment: 55 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEADQXzlChxZaQUQQMQ6Kg@BQcBGsQ5KeydGYBnNQEL/dqMMbn1NpQO@zlV1@qFh2ptl6lbgw66t@l6rW1aZ5URS7w/GskZIQq8V8@SdqJaW5Vb9HASTEJwWGAiyIE3ICiwz9OAWYiB2wQxioTxBxjB5nIn/M3SubcnPZt@0X "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni Thanks! The `Just` was just so inefficient:)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 147 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"B",8),"b",8),"E",3),"e",3),"I",1),"i",1),"S",5),"s",5)
```

So elegant...

Comment: I'm afraid you forgot to transliterate “s” and “S” to “5”.

Comment: Yeah but the nested "SUBSITUTE"s look really cool even though it´s never going to win.. It´s the sort of thing I´d do with Lotus Formula using `@ReplaceSubstring` just for the fun of it but Formula is even more verbose than Excel. +1

Comment: Exactly, @ElPedro. 2 more `SUBSTITUTE()` calls and the part of the code visible at first glace will be just those, needing to scroll for the rest. Will have a definitely unique look.

Comment: Thanks @manatwork, have updated.

Comment: @Thor Are you allowed to alter other letters? I don't see any other answers doing that.

Comment: @Neil: You're right, I did not think it through

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33</s>, <s>31</s>, <s>29</s>, 28 bytes

```
->x{x.tr"BEISbeis","8315"*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukKvpEjJydUzOCk1s1hJR8nC2NBUScuo9n9BaUmxQppecmJOjoZSak5mSaqS5n8A)

-2 bytes thanks to @manatwork

Comment: 1) No need for `!` as you only care about `.tr`'s returned value, not `x` itself; 2) no need for parenthesis around `.tr`'s arguments.

Comment: @manatwork Nice catch! Thanks for saving me those 2 bytes!!!

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>98</s>, <s>92</s>, <s>70</s>, 55 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Select(x=>(x+"88331155")["BbEeIiSs".IndexOf(x)+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3BCoIwGADge08xdtqoBBFBUHdQrAZRB4MO0UH/fnNgC/ZP2NuvQ98LfEB7IBMPq4WKvDP2vdOdXT/ohnHBCubBKcUmVkeqFSU9LghehFqJsOVFkWVpmudcPngzdqhNTzzR9oXhOokgt@lTxnJzd8bj2VgU/yFpvxYGLybBG@NhRmIjskbf2pO@HLmUsow/)

Comment: If you inline the using you can save 6 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjNCoJAFEDhfU8xDAQzZKabWpgGRj9CtCiphbjQ4WoXdJK5Ixj07la0OR8cRXNFOO57rdZkDera@ROxioUjhdH1RRZaN4XBuheo@6Ywu6EzQIRPTb8Fw7ddUygQ5HCxQZmVgJRzpw0j4a8WonVvRdND5uVTfynfnpxxLsdgcjdo4YQaRCV4jFY9gFgJLE7S7TE5H7iUwfgB "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: You don't need the `string.Concat`

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 53 bytes

Inputs a string, outputs an array of char codes.

```cs
s=>s.Select(c=>"beisBEIS".Contains(c)?48+17/(c%16):c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczRCoIwFADQ975iCMG9VAshKtItKhR8C@wH5mXUwCbsTqKvX2H0AecQr4hdqkdPJcfg/H3ZVH582mC63pbOR61FLVRipVm2trcUgZTOOuv4XDVtJi@Dj8Z5BsLjZr/Id2ugeb7FA2EqZtfvGcHbl/j1UMNkRbQcxTTg/zVKAz1MQIPyNpxCMG9AxCJ9AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
d`ßÈ`í8#ì)pu
```

Includes an unprintable (charcode 153) after the `#`.

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZGDfyGDtOCOZ7ClwdQ&input=IkFhQmJDY0RkRWVGZkdnSGhJaUpqS2tMbE1tTm5Pb1BwUXFSclNzVHRVdVZ2V3dYeFl5Wnoi)

```
d`ßÈ`í8#ì)pu      :Implicit input of string
d                 :For each pair of characters in the following, replace the first with the second
 `ßÈ`             :  Compressed string "bise"
     í            :  Interleave
      8#          :    8153
         ì        :    To digit array
          )       :  End interleave
           p      :  Append
            u     :    Uppercase
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
Y`B\EISbeis`8315
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs* (transliterating `Ss` to `5` due to (quote from docs): "*If the `to` list is shorter than the `from` list and the current character appears after the end of the `to` list, it gets mapped to the last character in the `to` list (alternatively, you can think of it as padding `to` to the length of `from` using the last character in `to`).*" So only a single `5` is necessary in the `to` list.)
-3 bytes thanks to *@FryAmTheEggman*, using the cyclic transliterate `Y` instead of the regular `T`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8ywSnG1TM4KTWzOMHC2ND0//@QjMxiBSBKVChJLS6xUnBKck31zAwu5nLMS1HISC1KVUjMyy8BMhRSE4szgVR@XioA)

**Explanation:**

Pretty straight-forward; transliterates the characters `BEISbeis` to `83158315`.

Two things to note:
- The `\` is to escape the `E`, because the `E` within the transliterate is a builtin for `02468`.
- The cyclic transliterate `Y` is used instead of the regular transliterate `T`. In the cyclic transliterate, the characters are repeated indefinitely. So the `BEISbeis` is actually `BEISbeisBEISbeisBEISbeis...` and the `8315` is actually `831583158315...` Only the first character in the `from`-list are relevant, though. So this will transliterate `BEISbeis` to `83158315`.

Comment: 1 byte shorter with ``T`beiB\EISs`8318315``

Comment: @ovs Thanks! I really should take some time to read through the entire docs more carefully.

Comment: Cyclic transliteration is slightly more complicated than that, but that doesn't apply in this case as your from list length is a multiple of your to list length.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
XQ"BEISbeis""8315
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyJQycnVMzgpNbNYScnC2ND0/3@lkNTiksy8dIWkSgXXisTcgpzUYiUA)

```
X                    # Translate characters in
 Q                   # the input
  "BEISbeis"         # that are in this string from this string
            "8315"   # to this string (modular indexing: "B"->"8", "b"->"8")
```

Comment: Sadly `srB"BEIS"0` doesn't save anything. If only there was one more letter!

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 76 bytes

```
@ReplaceSubstring(i;@Explode("B b E e I i S s");@Explode("8 8 3 3 1 1 5 5"))
```

Takes input as `i`. Works because `@ReplaceSubstring` can take a list of characters to replace and a list of replacement characters and match them one to one.

There is no TIO for formula so a screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
se ic
%s/b/8/g
%s/e/3/g
%s/i/1/g
%s/s/5/g
```

A Vim script taking advantage of the repeated pattern has more bytes:

## Vim, <s>82</s> 59 bytes

```
for p in ['b/8','e/3','i/1','s/5']
exe'%s/\c'.p.'/g'
endfo
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 475 bytes

```
>,[>+++++++++++[<------>-]<[>++[<+++++>-]]<[<]>>++[<----->-]<---[>+++[<++++++>-]]<[<]>>+++[<------>-]<----[>++++[<++++++>-]]<[<]>>++++[<------>-]++[<----->-]<[>+++++[<++++++>-]]<[<]>>+++++[<------>-]+++[<----->-]<[>++++++[<+++++++>-]]<[<]>>++++++[<------->-]<---[>+++++[<++++++++++>-]]<[<]>>+++++[<---------->-]<----[>+++++++[<++++++++>-]]<[<]>>+++++++[<-------->-]++[<----->-]<[>++++++[<++++++++++>-]<++>]<[<]>>++++++[<---------->-]<-->++++++++++[<+++++++++++>-]<+++++.[-],]
```

Basically, it works like this:

1. For each inputted character...

   1. Subtract the value of B
   2. If the resulting value is nonzero, add B-8
   3. Subtract B-8
   4. Subtract the value of B-E
   5. If the resulting value is nonzero, add E-3
   6. Subtract E-3
   7. So on for every letter in the order of least to greatest ASCII
   8. At the end, add the value of s (the greatest ASCII) back

Sorry it's like super duper messy.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 28 bytes

```
rplc'BEISbeis';"0'8315'$~8"1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/iwpyktWdXD2Dk1Izi9WtlQzULYwNTdVV6iyUDP9rcilwpSZn5CukKag7pebklysUlxalJSanKngWK6QkFmWrc/0HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 127 bytes

```
print replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@,'e',3),'E',3),'b',8),'B',8),'i',1),'I',1),'s',5),'S',5)
```

Assuming "@" the input. Not very efficient, though. :)

Comment: starting from SQL Server 2017 you can use the [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) function

Comment: @grabthefish Thank you, still using 2012 and 2016 versions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 52 bytes

I was looking for a way to represent the 8-digit number as a shorter expression, but only got the same length:

```
procedure f(s)
return map(s,"ESIseiBb",77^4+147)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxDsIgFEDRna94YYLIYtKE3cTBubsJhYeiFugDbOvP1yYu3v3cYFPctkzJomuE4EWRjLA2ijCaLIri5/5SMJwGrrS@dodjpyXD6P7QaEIUksHeTKGi8IL3@R7iAsnD8DL2CVMzVD8KHs3ddrHCO81c/k5f)

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 52 bytes

```
procedure f(s)
return map(s,"BEISbeis",83158315)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDsIgFAB3vuKFCRIW0zRxNnFw7hdQeOhTC/gAa/35WuPiJTfekUtxXTMnh74xQlBFC8baOMJksypGHo6nYUQq0uy7Xf9VC4z@L5osRaUFbMxMFVVQcsgXii9IAca7dTd4NMv1beDa/HkrFnimWerf6QM)

Test case taken from @Arnauld

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 20 characters

```
q"beisBEIS"8315`2*er
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v1ApKTWz2MnVM1jJwtjQNMFIK7Xo//9Ex7okp7pU17pMz7ri4LqqKAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>152</s> <s>143</s> <s>140</s> 128 bytes

```c
a[256];c=256;main(){for(;a[c]=--c;)a[66]=a[98]=56;for(a[69]=a[101]=51;c=~getchar(a[73]=a[105]=49);printf(a+~c))a[83]=a[115]=53;}
```

Requires ASCII.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCsMgDIDhV/GojMJsp2sRn0Q8hKCurGuL7aWM9dVdpKfA/yXBJiGWAq5V2hu0NMwHxpmLb1wyN@DQ26ZBI8Bp7S24ofeWlqpSGmqSd0lN0vmZwo4vqPTsLlLePgZh1jzOe@RwO1HQr/5SSao68ytlCmFn2xrgzcaN5QDTdLC0LPH4Aw)

- -8 bytes using [this](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0k1RUknPbUkOSOxSENT07r2/39TAA) to transform ASCII characters to their codes and using `c+1` rather than `c>-1` to check if EOF is reached
- -3 bytes using `toupper` rather than `tolower` and changing all characters to their ASCII codes
- -3 bytes abandoning that whole track together and using a character dictionary instead
- -12 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcdBDsIgEEDRq7AyEHGhKFIJ8SATFmRCsZFKQ@uiNO3VsYmr/z6eAmKtDprGmgWktEZxkPsIDndhzZmD2nNbddG96z4U2dKmTPVG0QQ/4ctlypgevn@WZzle1QMZK8YBHjZxsXqtNXo/kXHw7k26kWTvYpxJSKmdfw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat That seems to be borrowing a lot of ideas from my answer...

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 88 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join([('8315'*2)['beisBEIS'.find(c)] if c in 'beisBEIS' else c for c in s])
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcGxDkAwEADQX@l2dyQSRCISi8RgNmKgNE64NtrF19d77gunlTKado73@mz7qnwDkF2WBRHqMq8gKVJNE2wH@64fRsgMy46aFmNfpRWL8hTdyxLQIITDByCKPw)

Comment: The size wasn't wrong. Jo King linked to a better solution which is 60 bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 145 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var c in a[0]){var d=c%32;System.Console.Write((char)(c>64?d==5?51:d==2?65:d==9?49:d==19?53:c:c));}}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##Fce7CoMwFADQX7lLIRkq9RFBxWboXCh06CAO4ZrWQJpAbhBE/Pa0ToeDdEbClNAqInhsFFU0CIs3E9yVcYxiMO4zjIpvbx@0wpktKgCCcaCGy8i3o1OPp7LonitF/c1u3pG3OnsFEzVjOKvAGV7rSk59L6TI27@FrMVhI6vmMG@kKFtskfNu3/eU0qoJDFi/aLBaxx8)

Comment: [145 bytes (replaced `for` with `foreach`)](https://tio.run/##Fce7CoMwFADQX7lLIRkq9RFBxWboXCh06CAO4ZrWQJpAbhBE/Pa0ToeDdEbClNAqInhsFFU0CIs3E9yVcYxiMO4zjIpvbx@0wpktKgCCcaCGy8i3o1OPp7LonitF/c1u3pG3OnsFEzVjOKvAGV7rSk59L6TI27@FrMVhI6vmMG@kKFtskfNu3/eU0qoJDFi/aLBaxx8 "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online") (the original answer is actually 167 bytes, not 179).

Comment: Stupid of me that I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 101 bytes

```clj
(defn l[s](clojure.string/replace s #"[BEISbeis]"{"B""8""b""8""E""3""e""3""I""1""i""1""S""5""s""5"}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsIwFIXhV7kclxSkIiI4F4pk7lg6NMlVIqEpuXUoxWePNS7f8B84NsTXO3HOyvFjotDLoOy/1bIkPz1PiecwWiahA/qm1Z1hLwM2NMANMMUWuABc1MAZ8MUOuALy81NVWc375aIC7jE6s/KRNMnoXY19/AI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{TR/beisBEIS/8315/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OiRIPyk1s9jJ1TNY38LY0FS/9n9xYqVCmoISTFjpPwA)

Kinda annoying that the case-insensitive adverb doesn't work with transliteration. That's made up a little by the second half cycling for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 40 bytes

```
/B/b//b/8//E/e//e/3//I/i//i/1//S/s//s/5/
```

Input should be appended to the program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBBgAgEIbRI32SaB0tWneCYijazf1N//P8LT/mETQ2WqFjaIbBRRNMHC1EfA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 29 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x[&y=_x]:z}/[;"ebis";"3815"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7oiWq3SNr4i1qqqVj9ayTUnsyRVoTyxqCgzv0jJWik1KbMYSBlbGJoqxf7/DwA)

**Explanation:**

There is no `ssr` in oK, this is good enough for single character replacement.

**Explanation:**

```
{x[&y=_x]:z}/[;"ebis";"3815"] / the solution
{          }/[;      ;      ] / lambda that iterates over implicit x, y and z
                      "3815"  / our z, leet characters
               "ebis"         / our y, non-leet characters
 x[     ]:z                   / assign z to x at indices given inside []
      _x                      / lowercase x
    y=                        / equal to y?
   &                          / indices where true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 28 bytes

Translation stolen from [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6273/85052).

```
{.'beisBEIS'?'8315'2*@),+=}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v1pPPSk1s9jJ1TNY3V7dwtjQVN1Iy0FTR9u2VvX/f5AwSNrQyNgEAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Q/kdb+](https://kx.com/download/), 26 bytes

**Solution:**

```
ssr/[;"ebisEBIS";8#"3815"]
```

**Examples:**

```
q)ssr/[;"ebisEBIS";8#"3815"]"Elite!"
"3l1t3!"
q)ssr/[;"ebisEBIS";8#"3815"]"The quick brown fox..."
"Th3 qu1ck 8rown fox..."
```

**Explanation:**

Perform [search and replace](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/ss/#ssr) over the input

```
ssr/[;"ebisEBIS";8#"3815"] / the solution
ssr/[;          ;        ] / iterate (/) ssr[input;find;replace]
                 8#"3815"  / 8 take "3815" => "38153815"
      "ebisEBIS"           / the string "ebisEBIS"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>84</s> 83 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!</sup>

```c
n[]={[83]=5,[73]=1,[69]=3,[66]=8},c;f(char*s){for(;*s;c?*s=c+48:c,s++)c=n[*s&~32];}
```

Ungolfed and commented:

```c
int n[] = 
{ /* lookup table */
    ['S'] = 5,
    ['I'] = 1,
    ['E'] = 3,
    ['B'] = 8
};
int c;

void f(char *s)
{
    /* if lookup table entry is not empty,
         set *s to that entry + '0' for the ASCII representation
       else do nothing
       increment s and repeat */
    for( ; *s; c ? (*s = c + '0') : c, s++ )
        c = n[*s & ~32]; /* uppercase */
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNS8NAFEX38yseEUq@KmpqjY6jVMhCaLOo3Y2ziC8TO9BOZN7ETYh/PcYK4t2ce@Fwcf6OOI5WKtHLPFPiOpU3Ey5TubxVIpuwVCIfUuRNiPvKxRT1TetCHhPHx5gEJov8DlNKkgiFlTHNvrIrxYfxzFg8dLWGe/K1ac/3D4wZ6@FYGRt@tqaOWM9gys8tkFQgIJgE7Wx1gLeK9FFb/2qDk/QvwXO5K7blag1Pq5diU5S7gJ@cJqTot310nv6G075zFi44G8Zv)

Answer (score 0):

### Mumps (M), 32 bytes

```
R I W $TR(I,"BbEeIiSs",88331155)
```

Although... it might look a tad 'weird.' Mumps doesn't output a carriage return even if typed on input, so the input & output will be all in a single line. To aid readability, add 2 characters:

```
R I W !,$TR(I,"BbEeIiSs",88331155)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
“ʋḶ“ḲR+« ɓṂṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMiU4MCU5QyVDQSU4QiVFMSVCOCVCNiVFMiU4MCU5QyVFMSVCOCVCMlIlMkIlQzIlQUIlMjAlQzklOTMlRTElQjklODIlRTElQjklODYmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD1UaGlzJTIwaXMlMjBhJTIwdGVzdCUzQSUyMEJiRWVJaVNzJmZsYWdzPQ==)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
“ʋḶ“ḲR+« ɓṂṆ  # Implicit input
“ʋḶ“          # Compressed string "beis"
    ḲR+       # Append reversed uppercase version
       « ɓṂ   # Compressed number 83155138
           Ṇ  # Transliterate "beisSIEB" -> "83155138"
              # Implicit output
```